# Does Articles in the user profile Activity tab have some utility when you don't use teams?

Tags: bug, status-planned, activity-tab

I noticed today there's an *Articles* section in the *Activity* tab of the user profile. Apparently this is used for teams and it's only featured on Stack Overflow main that I've noticed.

Does this provide some functionality for users that don't use teams? If it doesn't provide any functionality can it be removed from view somehow?

[image: image of activity tab]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Congratulations, you found a bug! Thank you for pointing it out to us. We'll be removing this in the upcoming days. If you notice anything else that seems strange, please let us know.