# Beta release of Collectives™ on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, collectives, announcement, community

### Beta release of Collectives on Stack Overflow

Over the past year, our Reach & Relevance team (description of the team in FAQ) has been heads down working on a new initiative that will enhance the experience on Stack Overflow for both our users and organizations (open source organizations and their different projects, companies that build products and services for developers). Today, I’m happy to announce the Beta release of a new product, Collectives™ on Stack Overflow.

#### First things first: why?

We know that developers at tech organizations have a wealth of knowledge about their technologies and, while some currently participate on SO, we're interested in a way to increase and simplify that participation. An organization’s expertise, when included with the community’s knowledge, can provide a more in-depth understanding of how to use a language, leverage a service, or troubleshoot a technology.

We’ve also learned that organizations who are active on Stack Overflow have a strong appetite to add their specific knowledge. They want to have deeper interactions and provide a better experience to their current and potential users. Currently, they can’t do that with any of our products.

With that in mind, we have the following goals for this initiative:

- Allow the communities that have formed around specific technologies to engage with the people that are building and supporting those technologies.
- Increase the amount of high-quality content around tags related to a Collectives’ technology on Stack Overflow.
- Give technical employees of these organizations the tools to contribute their knowledge effectively to the Stack Overflow community.
- Provide organizations with a space on Stack Overflow where they can highlight and share relevant content.

#### Beta release

We’re launching the Beta version of Collectives™ on Stack Overflow today. It will include features that are based on our findings from research sessions with users, moderators, and organizations. Our Product Research Lead on this initiative, Mithila Fox, [posted a more in-depth post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408602/the-user-research-behind-collectives-on-stack-overflow) on this process. This is just the beginning. We will continue to listen, learn, and make improvements. We're interested in hearing your thoughts, and we have outlined the various ways we plan to gather feedback below (see: how to share feedback).

#### What is a collective?

Collectives™ on Stack Overflow is a new set of spaces on Stack Overflow where content related to certain technical languages, products, or services can be grouped together. It’s a place for users who regularly interact with this content to collaborate. In turn, the organizations that help build or maintain this technology will share their expertise. Collectives are based on a set of specific tags relating to the technologies that an organization builds, supports, and has an authority over. They aggregate all content for those interested in this technology and give some special handling of content posted in those tags.

#### Beta features

Below there’s a short description of what’s included in this initial launch. For a visual representation, see [Go Collective](http://www.stackoverflow.com/collectives/go) & [Google Cloud Collective](http://www.stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud).

#### Collectives page

Each organization that participates in Collectives on Stack Overflow will get its own page, which will act as its “home” on Stack Overflow. Questions and Answers will be posted to Stack Overflow, as usual, and the collective page will aggregate all the relevant content from selected tags. It’s where relevant Articles (more below in the Articles paragraph) can be found. Users can participate in a collective-specific leaderboard and can learn which users are Admins/Recognized Members of a collective.

When you choose to join a collective you’ll find a link to it in the left side navigation. All Collectives can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives).

#### User Roles

Collectives on Stack Overflow will add additional user roles to Stack Overflow.

*Recognized Member*

Recognized members are either employees of an organization or users from within the Stack Overflow community that are knowledgeable about their products and therefore selected to become Recognized Members. These users will have a badge on their user card when they post/edit a question, answer, or article within the collective. They are also able to post Articles and recommend answers.

[image: Recognized by collective answer]

*Admin*

The admin of a collective has all the abilities the Recognized Member has, but also has access to the data (see below) from within the collective. They are the ones who manage Recognized Members and are able to invite Stack Overflow users to become Recognized Members within the collective.

*Employee*

An Admin/Recognized member can have the employee label. This will not affect any of their permissions but would show this on any post they make. This way all Stack Overflow users will be able to see that the user is formally associated with the organization.

[image: Employee Label]

##### Articles

Collectives on Stack Overflow adds the ability to create [Articles](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/08/10/stack-overflow-for-teams-articles-content-collaboration-knowledge/), longer form content that lives on the collective page. We first introduced this feature within our Teams product last year, and we have seen strong adoption and usage. Articles give Recognized Members the opportunity to provide deeper knowledge and insights through how-to-guides, knowledge articles, or announcements. Initially, Articles can only be posted by Admins and Recognized Members of a collective, but we’re planning to release a feature (in the near term) that would allow any member of a collective to submit an Article for review.

##### Enhancing the Q&A experience through Recommended Answers

Recognized members and admins of an organization will be able to recommend answers on tags associated with their collective. This effectively adds a “seal of approval” to the most appropriate answer from their point of view. However, it does not impact or override the existing system for voting an answer up or down.

[image: Answer recommended by collective]

##### Metrics

In order to help Admins better understand the health of their collective and how they can positively contribute to it, we'll be providing them with metrics & insights on activity on the pages around the tags that are associated with their collective. More info on what data will be available can be found below in the FAQ section.

#### Feedback and next steps

We have a large backlog of feedback, feature requests, and our own ideas which will go through rounds of research with users and organizations over the coming months. And we’re curious to hear what features you might feel would be beneficial from your perspective.

##### How to share feedback

We’re excited to see how this product will be used and are eager to hear your feedback on the different features. We’ll be processing the feedback in two ways:

- You can use the regular [feature request flow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375365/how-do-i-present-a-proposal-for-change-or-write-a-feature-request-for-stack-over).
- The [user research post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408602/the-user-research-behind-collectives-on-stack-overflow) describes how you can participate in future user research.
- Later this week we’ll post a Townhall AMA Meta post (hosted by the Community Management team) where we’ll try to answer questions.

The feedback that we collect through these sources will be included in our user research process. Feedback from the community has shaped this product so far, and we want to continue that.

##### Next steps

We’ve learned a lot during our user research sessions and look forward to seeing how this new initiative can benefit the community and our customers. We want to ensure that this project continues to add value, improve the quality of content and allow our users to engage with the people that are building/supporting the technologies they use. Therefore we’ll continue identifying features that are needed from an organization and user perspective so we can build them into the roadmap in the coming months.

#### Launch customers

We are excited to announce that we’ll be launching with Go & Google Cloud. These two organizations already have a huge presence on Stack Overflow through their tags. They are well-positioned to take advantage of the collective page, recommendations, and articles in order to improve the Stack Overflow experience around their tags and engage with their communities more directly, in a central place. Both of these organizations have proven to be great partners during the process of creating this initiative, being involved in many research sessions, understanding the Stack Overflow and the Collectives project, and providing us with valuable feedback on how to make this a success.

#### Shoutouts

We’d like to give a huge shout-out to the group of users that have been participating in our research sessions. We’ve learned a lot from these conversations, and we really enjoyed them. Thank you so much, and we look forward to continuing these conversations with you.

---

#### FAQ

We know that you will have questions on Collectives on Stack Overflow. We’ve summarized several that we’ve received from community members who have participated in our research sessions, as well as a few questions we anticipate hearing from you.

##### Why didn’t you ask for feedback on Meta earlier?

Because this initiative involved potential customer organizations, we could not speak publicly about it until we were ready to launch. However, we have been running weekly research sessions with a group of 12 moderators and high-rep Meta users under NDA to gather their feedback and thoughts on different aspects of the project. We've shared a more [in-depth post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408602/the-user-research-behind-collectives-on-stack-overflow) on these research sessions and our findings on Meta.

##### Why have you been working on this, instead of this or that?

We believe this project can have a positive impact on the user experience on Stack Overflow by providing a dedicated space where people can collaborate more directly around technologies and products. While the research and development of this initiative was largely driven by the Reach and Relevance team, they coordinated closely with the Public Platform and Community teams. The Public Platform and Community teams were key stakeholders on the project to provide insight, guidance, and input.

##### Wait a second. Articles sound familiar. How is this different from the Documentation project?

Good question... We’ve done quite a bit of research on what went wrong with the [Documentation project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation). At the time, we didn't have the resources to fully support Documentation, but the research done then, and more recently around this project, has consistently validated an appetite for content beyond Q&A on Stack Overflow.

A second concern around Documentation was around the content quality. We feel that initially limiting posting of Articles to a small subset of users and expanding that later on to a bigger group through an approval process should mitigate these problems.

##### But does this mean that these organizations own the Q&A content?

No, all questions and answers will remain on Stack Overflow. Nothing changes here. Moderation rules, code of conduct, etc. will all remain the same. The license of the content will remain the same as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).

##### Does Stack Overflow become a support portal for large organizations?

No. Even though we might see more of our customers' clients coming to Stack Overflow for help, the rules around Q&A on Stack Overflow remain the same, and we'll continue to set appropriate expectations with our customers & users.

##### How will this affect the workload for moderators and curators?

We don’t want the workload for our moderators to increase significantly due to this project. However, there is no way to know for sure. This is why we are testing the concept with only two Beta Customers. We will be in very close contact with the moderator team to gather their thoughts and make adjustments - if and when necessary. Our community team is closely monitoring this and providing feedback to the project team. We have also provided clear instructions to the organizations about the best ways of engaging on Stack Overflow, making sure that their contributions are meaningful and valuable.

##### What content is part of Collectives?

We create a collective around a set of specific tags relating to the technologies that an organization builds, supports, and has an authority over.

##### What type of data will be shared with the organizations in the reporting section?

All the data will be aggregated, therefore we won’t be sharing any PII (personal) information with the organizations and will comply with all data privacy laws (GDPR, CCPA, etc.). The organizations will have access to different types of reports. These will include metrics such as page views & unique users per day/country, the total number of questions/answers in a specific timeframe, and calculated metrics such as the % of questions that got an answer within 24 hours per topic tag.

##### How does this relate to the rest of the Stack Exchange Network?

Right now we're working with Stack Overflow in mind, and our launch will be focused there. However, if other organizations show an interest outside of SO, we will keep an open mind and consider making it available more widely.

##### How will recommended answers affect the order or the answers and the rep system?

Initially, it will not affect the order at all. We are looking into one particular use case where answers that have the exact same score are currently randomly sorted. In terms of rep: it will have no effect on the reputation you get from answers. You will continue to earn rep as usual by answering and voting on responses to questions.

##### What were the criteria for selecting a launch customer?

We applied several criteria:

- We wanted to launch with one open-source and one commercial organization, as we feel those are both very relevant to Stack Overflow users. To hit the ground running, we wanted to launch with an organization that already had a good amount of activity on Stack Overflow through their potential tags. Therefore we looked at the number of tags that their technologies have and the total number of pageviews these questions get per month.
- We selected the organizations that were eager to actively work with us on the Beta launch and were willing to commit to providing resources to support their Collective and to provide us with feedback on what features would be useful for them.

##### Will recommendations affect the sorting of answers on question pages?

No, we have no plans to do so in the foreseeable future. We'll revisit this if we learn that recommendations prove to be a consistent signal to identify the most relevant answer.

##### What’s the benefit for organizations to actually participate?

We’d like to split this into two categories:

*Adoption*

We know from our research that, when evaluating platforms, engineers look for technologies that have a well-supported, thriving user community. The social proof that comes from these communities helps drive adoption and engagement for the products & services of these organizations.

*Engagement*

We know that our customers are looking for insights and engagement with their core audience to help support their own product development cycles. We feel that the features included in this Beta release will allow them to make better strategic decisions on growing and driving adoption of their products.

##### What is the Reach & Relevance Team?

The Reach & Relevance Team focuses on building and operating product features that address real user needs while enabling relevant technology providers and employers to build awareness and engage with interested users on our products such as Collectives on Stack Overflow, Advertising, and Employer Branding.

Comment: I wonder how this is gonna destabilize the rep economy in the long run

Comment: I wonder how this is gonna impact the credibility of answers from people who don't participate in the collective, or who are not Recognized Members

Comment: Innovation, like this, is very very welcome.

Comment: This seems pretty cool... so companies will pay for having a collective? And they can assign "employees" for their collectives?

Comment: One of the [very first questions will be what "collective" refers to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408592/what-does-the-invite-to-collective-functionality-do-and-what-are-collectives) (even if doesn't refer to anything in particular). Perhaps add that to the FAQ? *[Borg Collective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg#Borg_Collective)*

Comment: @aheze That's correct, this is a paid product and they can choose which of their employees will be able to be admins/recognized.

Comment: so, effectively, sponsored tags 2.0, now with more strings attached. I hope this never comes to the tags i frequent.

Comment: So private companies can essentially buy moderator rights on SO, within their "collective"? And censor uncomfortable content such as posts pointing out bugs in their products?

Comment: @Lundin erm, no? This doesn't give any diamond moderator rights. Moderation is fully under diamond mods control.

Comment: I realize that the addition of ™ to the title is recent in the edit history, and may not, therefore, reflect official position(s). I doubt that the term "Collectives" is valid, in this context, as a trademark. Typically, common words are acceptable as trademarks when the word is _not_ descriptive of the company or its product. I.e.: "Apple" for computers or school books is valid while "Apple" for a company which sells apples (fruit) would not be valid. It should also be ℠ rather than ™.

Comment: @Chindraba What you think people have called a collection of things a collective before? noooooo, I don't believe it

Comment: Can the sidebar widget be given something we can target it by? is join-leave container specific to this?

Comment: What do you charge companies to create a Collective, seeing you name them customers?

Comment: @Chindraba I think it's safe to assume this is a tongue-in-cheek addition, similar to how Stack presented [The Key™](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406398/announcing-the-key-copy-paste-like-youve-never-done-before).

Comment: @KevinB It's not clear to me what you're asking (with respect to "join-leave container"). It appears you're assuming some context which isn't included in your comment (possibly made worse by the same thing not, necessarily, being shown to all users). If you're asking about targeting something in SE's HTML with a semantically named class, then the answer has nearly always been "no". SE has been moving away from using semantic CSS classes for quite a while now.

Comment: I think this is a really cool initiative, with a lot of potential. I say potential in both directions– it has the propensity to add a lot of value and new expertise to the site, making it an even more valuable resource; but it could also possibly wreck the site balance in several key ways if botched or handled poorly. Regardless of what the future holds, it sounds like y'all have done a *ton* of research and homework to back this initiative up, and that's really exciting to me, and makes me really hopeful that it'll work out for the better. Best of luck!!

Comment: @CesarM Ok. Thanks for the clarification. Maybe use another name than "admin" then, because among programmers admin means full access to everything.

Comment: "However, it does not impact or override the existing system for voting an answer up or down" Nobody knows what the impact will be, but it's important to emphasize that voting should always be on content only. Everything else doesn't really make sense (or we could stop voting at all). I hope the impact on voting will be small and it won't affect the sorting order at all forever. Then it might even be a positive thing.

Comment: I really do not like this.

Comment: @Philippe Is "Collectives" an actual [trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark)? Have you applied to the United States Patent and Trade Mark Office to register it as a trademark?

Comment: @Chindraba That '™' title edit was made by an employee, Philippe. Perhaps it was done prematurely, but surely it wasn't done frivolously on a serious product like this...

Comment: @PM2Ring If the trademark had been through USPTO and finalized, the ™ would be replaced with ®. They could, of course, still be in the process, which I understand is rather long-tailed; probably longer than the planning and development of the features took so far.

Comment: Perhaps link to one or more of the intro videos? - *[Collectives™ on Stack Overflow - Introductory Demo for Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLVBYqn4vZ0)* (John Debrisli. 3 minutes),  *[Collectives™ on Stack Overflow - Introductory Demo for Technology & Open Source Organizations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNaZGSFVKc4)* (Jen Hindle. 5 minutes), and *[Collectives™ on Stack Overflow: Unlock the power of your community](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-Zk1CKkCY0)* (unknown narrator. 3 minutes).

Comment: _"We don’t want the workload for our moderators to increase significantly due to this project. However, there is no way to know for sure"_ - Are moderators okay with undertaking this extra (voluntary & unpaid) work when this is a paid for (by the companies, presumably for profit) service?

Comment: @Lewis As outlined [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408602/the-user-research-behind-collectives-on-stack-overflow) the moderators we spoke to don't believe this will meaningfully impact their workload. We will continue to check in with them and monitor this. Those mods we have spoken to would prefer to continue moderating the content themselves, to ensure that all SO standards are being understood and adhered to.

Comment: @mfox Given the choice between DIY and know it's done right and trusting unknown 1-rep users to do it right, basically a _Hobson's choice_, the choice is obvious, even if it does involve more work. Given a choice between shouldering even more work and not doing so, the choice would also be obvious.

Comment: There was a question about the licensing of the examples here yesterday, which resulted in the examples being rapidly pulled and the comment deleted. Then, the examples were reintroduced in revision 7. What exactly happened there, and what is the licensing status of these examples?

Comment: @tripleee The original images were cribbed from existing answers posted to Stack Overflow by completely different users. In other words, their usage here was not in compliance with the CC by-SA license because it did not provide attribution. Presumably, they copy-pasted legitimate answers from live SO into their testbed instance, from which they took the screenshots. The new images are also of actual answers posted to SO, but they're both answers by SO staff members, and the attribution (i.e., user cards) is now correct (//stackoverflow.com/a/2493719 and //stackoverflow.com/a/9684357).

Comment: @PeterMortensen one can also think of it as [collective (rep) farming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_farming)

Comment: Well this new "feature" is going down like a lead balloon.

Comment: @Jamiec, you're basing that upon what exactly?  The
751 Members of the GoLang collective?  Or the 482 members of the Google Cloud collective?  Don't forget, not everyone makes their opinion known on meta.  They just go where they find something of interest.

Comment: @PM2Ring -I’ve consulted with the appropriate legal-type folks in the office (who manage our use of things like the ™ symbol) who have told me that it is being correctly used in this instance, and that Collectives™ on Stack Overflow is the name of the product, and the correct way to refer to it.

Comment: @Philippe I'm basing it mainly on the quantity of downvotes this "announcement" has, the overwhelming quantity of upvotes answers which are critical of this feature has - not to mention the (yet again) lack of feedback loop with the SO community before this "beta" was announced.

Comment: @Jamiec The score is mildly negative, definitely not enthusiastic approval but also not a strong dislike (you have to normalize by the number of visitors). Now the Thank You feature from last year - that sunk like a stone.

Comment: I remember from the Documentation trial back then that interest in the new feature died out relatively quickly (kind of exponentially). I really wonder why there is only one very, very short article ready at the initial publication time. People will try that new feature out today and in the next days, but if they don't find much, they may ignore it. I'm not sure this is a good start for articles.

Comment: I'm deleting comments and the reason is that there are some folks trying to malign Teresa for things **unrelated to this post**. That's not the purpose of comments and any comments not related to the topic at hand are subject to deletion. If we need to hand out suspensions to make that clear, so be it. Consider this an official warning.

Comment: You're more than welcome to offer constructive criticism. I mean, multiple users have done just that in comments and answers. But there have been comments aimed at Teresa that are wanting to suggest there was this conspiracy to keep this quiet and that somehow this links back to the sale of SEI or the community mistakes of 2019/2020. Neither is correct or helpful and such comments will be deleted. As to who Teresa is, she's [basically the boss of Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/704608/teresa-dietrich).

Comment: Annoying. took several minutes to find `.subcommunity-google-cloud.s-avatar {display:none !important;}`

Comment: In case your did not RTFA, the community participants had to sign an NDA in order to provide feedback. The manner in which these participants were selected, what was their feedback and how it was implemented is completely opaque and goes against the entire spirit of the Meta community.

Comment: -1. Twenty-fourth of most downvoted question. Previously Stack Overflow only used non-free (proprietary) JavaScript codes to ruin our right to control our device, now they are trying to ruin our right to **answer**.

Comment: Is this going to be more or less doomed than the Documentation project? How will the pitfalls of that fiasco be avoided?

Comment: If software companies want to comment on answers or post answers to questions they can already do so. Judging from the quality of answers on StackOverflow, there is no need for this feature. You just need to look at Q&A forums hosted by software companies to see that they are far inferior to StackOverflow. Maybe they don't have access to the company developers, I don't know, but many answers are not helpful and just put there so they can claim they "answered" the question.

Comment: @JohnD That's always a problem. People optimize for metrics. If the metric is questions answered (absolute or relative) than a quick half-good, half-bad answer is worth more than a thoughtful, extensive (will stand the test of time) answer. Indeed the company has said it will monitor such metrics like questions answered. Let's hope that there are a lot of good metrics to meaningfully show how the quality and quantity of content evolves.

Comment: "Recommended" answers designated by technology providers **on Stack Overflow**, not on their own official websites or forums? Really? Yeah. They are free to do whatever cool things in their realm but Stack Overflow. The SE platform I know is a community workspace. Why bother giving them a gifted privilege over tens of millions of community members? I don't remember a single corporate technology, let alone Open Source projects, that managed to succeed w/o support & contribution from community members worldwide. And now, they have an elevated status to boss around here?

Comment: This feature, especially the "recognized" member feature, to me spells the end of meritocracy on this site and the final nail in the coffin of what was once one of the world's greatest open source websites.  Now, despite that I have a 400K reputation, if some mega tech company doesn't like me or recognize me, then my contributions will be rated and valued less than someone who has that badge of recognition.  This is not meritocracy, it is corptocracy.

Comment: @Mast "Is this going to be more or less doomed than the Documentation project? How will the pitfalls of that fiasco be avoided?" Usually it's very imprecise to predict the future so nobody knows, one should wait a couple of months. Also I'd say collectives are quite different from documentation. The main benefit of collectives so far seem to be user titles shifting focus from what somebody says to who somebody is. This was not the case with documentation, which was about content creation. The content creation part of collectives so far is rather throttled.

Comment: I just thought about Wikipedia and I wonder how they get anything done. They  don't have reputation or user titles or recommendations or collectives and still they handle topics that are much more controversial than programming. They don't even have votes and content disputes seem to be resolved largely by talking about it and finding compromises by users acting in good faith. This is all so un-StackOverflow, how can this work in practice? The models that Wikipedia and StackOverflow operate on differ greatly in their complexity with ours here getting more and more complex.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment @Trilarion, I do, but Wikipedia is **incredibly** complex. Contributing in a serious capacity requires understanding a lot of intricate user interfaces, a markup language unlike markdown, policies that change constantly, lengthy discussions before making final decisions, constant scrutiny, etc.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED I have much more experience with StackOverflow but I have done a few edits on Wikipedia as well and the experience was surprisingly easy: press edit, do changes, confirm changes, done. I think last time I even used a WYSIWYG editor. What interested me most is how they solve conflicts about the content and it seems they mostly hope to gain consensus and include all reasonable arguments (at least that's what they say). Notable things that are missing from here are reputation, badges and votes. Half of the activity here seems to be voting, even on comments.

Comment: Like I said I agree with you @Trilarion it's just that there's a lot more to Wikipedia than trivial edits to the page. Just being fair here - I agree StackOverflow is making the barrier to entry to be a real contributor ridiculously and needlessly complex. Wikipedia has its own problems too, though, of course.

Comment: The beta runs for two weeks now. The appetite for articles is not visible so far, people seem to stay away from the feature, maybe a restart would be necessary or some brave people going forward. A rethinking would also be possible. With ~3000 members each, the size of the collectives seem impressing. I wonder if it would be possible to estimate how many of all the users active in the collectives tags are members of the collectives? I also wonder what the success metrics of this beta is and how soon one should actually check them. I guess 6-8 weeks after the launch would be a good time.

Comment: what makes stack overflow great is how democratic it is. like wikipedia, this is its true power. and why the data quality on stack overflow is so good. adding collectives ruins this.

Comment: To all the decision-makers: look at what stackoverflow was over the years and look at it now. If you can say you're making these types of changes (without community involvement) for the better of the platform vs. making more and more $$, then go for it, but I don't think you can.

Comment: Another revenue stream for SO based off volunteer user contributions.

Comment: @DaveNewton SO was always doing that. Signup page says `GET UNSTUCK`. It's not Stack Overflow that's helping them. It's us.

Comment: So what shows you're good? Being *affiliated* with the company (and knowing nothing about a language) or getting a gold badge in a tag?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE ? I explicitly said "another", I don't understand your point.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm just saying, AGAIN?

Comment: What happen to being a site ___"By the community, for the community"?___ This finally makes it so `Stack Overflow` is no longer a community ran site, created by, and for, its own community. This forcefully Wedges companies into the paradigm of ___`"by us; for us"___.

Comment: Companies are not on the side-lines anymore where the community can feely communicate among each other in a useful way that helps the community learn to use the contemporary worlds software-technologies, but rather the big companies now have oversight over who is able to give a quality answer, and this is not a power that should ever have even been considered as giving to big tech, not unless the man behind the S.O. curtain is being puppeteered by big-tech. In a nutshell, Stack Overflow has become "By the community for Big-Tech"

Answer (score 385):

I can't say I'm excited about this. One of the basic tenets of the Q&A model is that anyone can ask and answer any question. All those status about "recommended" or "employee" or "recognized" gives an unduly authoritativeness that doesn't come naturally via contributions like tag badges do. This would veer the preferences about the content on the site from community-based, towards what an external entity dictates.

Generally, while I don't think that grouping tags around a topic is too bad (while I still believe that this should be by improving our tag corpus instead), the other characteristics that this project has given me all the wrong kind of vibes about building independent content about programming questions.

Comment: I basically had the same thought. In the end it will depend on how the "recognized member" tags are handed out.

Comment: Although "authoritativeness" *is* a word, it is rather contrived, IMHO (making a noun from an adjective itself derived from a noun). Maybe just "... an undue authority?"

Comment: @AdrianMole [Nouning weirds language](https://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1993/01/25).

Comment: Resistance to the GCP Collective™'s answer is futile.

Comment: @AdrianMole and yet it's something that I find natural, despite being a non-native speaker

Comment: Fine - it's your post (which is why I didn't edit it to *my* preference).

Comment: I also have a concern that this will distract from the tried and true practice of "the community views and votes on all content equally". We already see people's rep skyrocket after they become moderators and get a diamond by their name. While this *seems* to be about the post rather than the user (e.g. labels apply per answer rather than per user who has a label themselves) it remains to be seen what effect this will have.

Comment: @AdrianMole oh, don't  let that stop you, someone already edited a post of mine to [make a point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/324221/revisions) and ignore the meaning of it.

Comment: Dang @Tyler, getting rep because of diamond ... I wish that was true. I just get serial downvotes.

Comment: @BhargavRao It may not be *universally* true, but I have absolutely observed it on more than one occasion. It's much more pronounced for users who become mods w/ lower rep values, ofc.

Comment: I hear your concerns, and one of the key decisions we made from the early days of this initiative was to keep the focus on the content and to make sure we don’t disrupt the existing Q&A model. Features like “recommended answers” or highlighting “recognized users” are designed to build on top of the existing model, providing users with additional visual signals to find answers best suited to their needs. They don’t influence sort order, rep, or existing privileges for the exact reason you stated: those are earned from community-driven actions. (1/2)

Comment: Having organizations participating in this way allows us to tap into another benefit: companies behind these technologies have a vested interest in keeping this content up-to-date. Whether that’s reviewing old answers to ensure they’re still valid; adding a visual signal to a newer, more accurate answer that hasn’t yet gathered enough votes; or even simply answering unanswered questions. Ultimately, our goal is to make sure users can find the best answers to their problems in the easiest way possible. (2/2)

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani while the sort order is important, remember that it's not the single signal that users use. Length of the post (aka, "I'm not going to read this wall of text"), user name, authoritativeness that the post show, if there's an easily copy-n-pastable bit of code, etc. are signals that users use to determine what answer they should use. We've had users still upvoting and using posts with a warning that the code leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection. TL;dr: **not messing with the order isn't enough to not have a impact on user behavior**.

Comment: @Braiam yep, I agree with you. We're seeing this as just one additional signal that users can use to gauge whether an answer is right for their context. It doesn't replace or change the usefulness of the other signals that users consider (voting, post length, sample code, etc)

Comment: @PuneetMuylchandani I hope that metrics about the voting behavior of registered and anonymous users is taken into account after and before the change. Not only the performance of recommended by collective vs not recommended, but also if the trend of the recommended posts themselves before and after the change.

Comment: @Braiam +1, we're keeping a close eye on metrics & behavior and that'll primarily inform future work we prioritize in this area

Comment: @Puneet Thanks for your comments; they really resonate with me. I'm glad you and the other members of the team involved with this have listened to the feedback that my mod colleagues who participated in the private design/workshopping of this project provided. Specifically, that you've tried to maintain as much of the existing Q&A model as possible. From what I've seen so far, it looks like you've succeeded. (Still early to make the final call, of course.) What I'm seeing as the biggest potential problem is, what happens when there's inevitably a conflict? Consider the scenario... (1/2)

Comment: ...where normal community members reject a particular post because they think it violates the rules/standards of SO (e.g., they think it's off-topic). Say a diamond mod (a rep of the community) even agrees with them, and removes the post. But your corporate partners, the ones paying actual money for the Collectives product, come in and say no, we are paying for that post to be on SO, and we demand that you put it back. What do you, as staff, do in that very unenviable situation? Do you side with the mods/community? Or do you side with the paying customer? *That's* what I'm waiting to see.

Comment: Let me give a great example of why handing out special recognized armbands is an overall bad idea.  Let's say there are a number of questions about AWS.  And let's also say that the currently accepted answer, already there, also happens to be a low cost option.  Are we to believe, even for a moment, that a "recognized" AWS member working for Amazon might not have been instructed to offer a solution which maximizes the company's profits?  Stack Overflow was built on open source principles.  Let's try to keep it that way.

Answer (score 260):

If we're going to have a "Recognized by AudioBubble" banner under the user-card on answers posted by users *chosen* by the sponsors, then why not a "Gold Badge in AudioBubble" banner for users who have ***earned*** that accolade?

Surely, such reputation-driven, Community-awarded, qualifications are *at least* as important as those assigned by a third party.

Comment: And let them gold hammer a post against any other AudioBubble post? That's a lotta power

Comment: @Nick Who is "them"? The AudioBubble employees? I think Adrian is saying that "natural" gold-badgers should get a banner similar to collective employees, not that employees should get gold badges.

Comment: @zcoop98 Yes, indeed.

Comment: @zcoop98 Obviously I meant the regular users, imagine a Microsoft collective with C# and all their other products under it, would you want even SO community users with a "gold badge in  Microsoft" to be able to close any Microsoft question as a dupe of any other Microsoft question?

Comment: @Nick I still don't understand your concern; this proposal isn't asking for any changes to gold badge powers, nor anything resembling adding gold badges for a collective's tag pool. Just a banner for normal gold badges; users with a gold on a given tag would get a profile banner under their answers on questions tagged with their golden tag. No new close powers, nothing to even do with collectives at all.

Comment: @zcoop98 Then the banner should say "Gold badge in <some audiobubble tag>", rather than "Gold badge in audiobubble" as described, because _they mean different things_

Comment: @Nick That's a great point, I glossed over that. Maybe Adrian can clarify which they meant.

Comment: @zcoop98 Yeah, I have no problem with a banner saying gold badge in x tag where x tag is relevant to the collective (I mean, besides the existence of the banners themselves), my concern was the apparent desire for collective gold badges

Comment: @Nick I was assuming that "AudioBubble" *was* the tag name - my misunderstanding, I guess. However, maybe a moot point, as there aren't any gold-badgers in `[tag:audiobubble]`. ;-)

Comment: I hope not... posts should be judged on their quality and usefulness alone, not the badges or corporate associations the poster has.

Comment: @Kevin I agree! However, if we're going to have such 'status' indicators on posts (and I don't really think we should), then Gold Tag-Badge status should be on (at least) the same level as any corporate/cartel/sponsor -given status. Neither makes the answer better or worse: we have had a system for 'judging' answers since ... well, since the beginning.

Comment: It's bad enough some people default to casting upvotes on every post by a "new contributor"

Comment: @Kevin Hmm. The Triage queue (IIRC:  don't go there much, these days) actually *encourages* upvoting half-decent posts by new contributors.

Comment: I don’t think this would scale. I have a lot of gold tag badges; if I have multiple gold badges related to the question being answered, what would be shown?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why not? You could have "Gold tags(s) in [XXX1] [XXX2] [XXX3]" (or some such) as the banner under the user-card. After all, you can't have more than 5 gold badges for any given question. (Or just tag-badge symbols for each?)

Comment: ... I know the current "Closed by..." banner only shows one (chosen how?) gold badge for hammerers, but there's certainly scope/space for more than one (unless they all happen to be tags like "google-cloud-platform" and "huawei-mobile-services").

Comment: @AdrianMole It's the top tag (tag w/ most questions) used in the question, I think.

Comment: What is AudioBubble, BTW?

Comment: @EricDuminil At first, I though it was a German car manufacturer, but now I'm not so sure... :-)

Comment: @EricDuminil Apparently, it is the name of a certain Musical Artist.

Answer (score 224):

You mention the first collective "customers" (basically one customer, Google).

One would logically assume that a "Collective" is a paid-for product of an undisclosed price.

Wouldn't this make the feature useless for much of open-source technology, that does not have a corporate backer behind?

The "feature" as conceived seems to exclusively limited to fully "owned" tags, where ownership would be fully uncontested. Which makes it non-viable for a vast majority of the content hosted here, present and future.

As someone that spends most of his time roaming the OSS side of technology, I'm less than excited about the feature. On itself, that's perfectly fine. No product is for everyone. My only concern is the impact this has in the rest of the Q&A ecosystem.

Comment: I had a similar concern, I was trying to determine if I should move [my response](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408621) to this thread instead.

Comment: Certainly seems like open source wouldn't be the primary target of this - but is that a big deal?  Perhaps if this takes off they'll eventually have a way for not-for-profits to get a free version of this, if they're sufficiently notable, but for now it seems like it makes sense - this is a way for SO to monetize the companies that semi-outsource help to SO.

Comment: The problem seems to be a bit wider than Open Source. Take for instance C++: that's not Open Source, even though some C++ implementations are. There _are_ corporate backers, such as Microsoft, but the one single entity that represents all of C++ would be ISO's SC22 WG21 ("the C++ committee").

Comment: From the beginning, we have planned to include open source technologies.  I have been championing this use case early and often throughout our journey.  We spoke to multiple open source organizations as part of the user research.  We have a very different pricing structure for open source organizations vs commercial and will continue to evaluate them on a case by case basis.  Our goal with any open source collective is that there is enough content and dedicated individuals to support the collective to provide real value to users. (1/2)

Comment: For Beta, we are working with a limited number of organizations to ensure we can successfully support them and to learn from these Collectives.  We envision this feature becoming more widely available in the future. (2/2)

Comment: @TeresaDietrich I don't think this needs championing. It just needs defining generally: how will it be decided who owns what?

Comment: @TeresaDietrich *"I have been championing this use case early and often throughout our journey"* That's very reassuring. As I said [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow?answertab=votes#comment851254_408589), it's imperative (IMHO) that Open Source projects be able to participate in Collectives™, if they want to. I can easily imagine people saying stuff like "You should use tech X, not tech Y. Tech Y doesn't even have a Stack Overflow Collective".

Comment: There's an awful lot of implementation bugs and other bugs that have come to light since the post was made public, along with moderation concerns. That a bug-riddled feature with unclear pricing and no regard for the moderation side-effects is  received negatively is _not_ particularly surprising.

Answer (score 203):

I do *not* like this.  Not one bit.

The fundamental problem that I believe is being identified is that groups and organizations are leveraging Stack Overflow more and more as a common place of knowledge, which - to be perfectly fair - hasn't always been smooth, because of some fundamental shortcomings:

- **A misunderstanding of the place of Stack Overflow**; some projects have leveraged Stack Overflow more as a forum or help desk in the past, and we've had to request that the Community team reach out to them to provide <s>a firm smack upside the head</s> gentle guidance on how to use the site
- **A lack of moderators or users who have sufficient reputation to moderate content**, which would mean that low-quality content from a given project would still proliferate with the community-at-large having to pick up the slack
- **A very real tension between the projects and the community** in those unfortunate cases in which the community *does* have to pick up the slack; we didn't encourage this and the company only provides maybe a bonk or two, but by that point we're already in the workflow of cleaning things up

This new feature doesn't address those concerns.

- **Stack Overflow is now *officially* the place to be for project support**.  Effectively now this will trigger a landslide of projects to come onto Stack Overflow in a sanctioned and blessed capacity, allowing them to set up here.

And even though you say that the standards of Q&A aren't changing...

- **This new feature does *not* bestow any of the admins or team members any new moderation privileges**.  Heck, one of the admins in this beta has a grand total of 1 reputation.  Know what you can moderate with 1 rep?  **Nothing.**  Absolutely ***nothing***.

So you know what this means?  You probably guessed it by now, but...

- **The tensions between the projects and community will continue and become more pronounced** as this service rolls out wider and wider.  Suddenly now we - the community at large - are being relied on as the principle backbone and value of Stack Overflow to do the work that is needed to help keep these Q&As clean and sane.  We're all volunteers on this, but I don't feel that this respects that position.

More sharply, it feels like doing this would add more moderation burden on the community, and we're not getting *any* support from up above to help address this with this initial rollout.  I don't think it was considered to begin with.

One olive branch you could offer is to allow the members of these collectives become empowered to moderate that content instead of *just* giving them a super-accept check mark.

Comment: *"One olive branch you could offer is to allow the members of these collectives become empowered to moderate that content instead of just giving them a super-accept check mark."* - But that relies on those members having some basic understanding of the rules and guidelines of SO including what's POB, what's on/off-topic, etc., which is a big ask, especially when as you highlighted yourself, they may have a single reputation point.

Comment: @Nick:  Yes, you see the core issue.  **Users don't have a core understanding of the site or its rules** and yet we are handing them a lot of influence and sway on the site.  It isn't like any of the curators are benefiting from the major purchase of Stack Overflow - even though we were the ones who enabled it - and suddenly now we get to do *this*, too.  Unless I'm actually being compensated for this, I don't want Stack Overflow to make this *my* problem.

Comment: @Makoto It seems you see devils everywhere. Let's take a simple (not too) fictional example : a `[COBOL]` collective handled by the _employees_ of the US Navy _org_.     Maybe the _"employee"_ term would not describe them perfectly, anyway it's highly probable that they will be necessarily already registered SO users for a (very) long time and used to the **rules** (and i guess they're also very efficient to enforce them).  For ref., the _US Navy org_ is also a kind of collective with apparently a better welcoming reputation than us on SO.

Comment: @Makoto Joke apart, the _orgs_ behind the collectives should be _smart_ enough to entitled employees that are already long time registered SO users.

Comment: @Zilog80 I see more devils than Makoto and for the most part they stem from one concept: _Marketing_. For the "customers" (which is no longer the userbase of SO) collectives are a marketing tool. Maybe they call themselves the _Reach & Relevance_. Either way, it's going to be about the customer gaining a larger audience. Perhaps SO will get better answers, though it seems there's been no lack of that in practice.The collective's "Admins" anointed by the customer are sure to be marketing types who likely have limited expertise in the daily use of the product and probably less knowledge of SO.

Comment: Correction: at 1 rep you can suggest edits (it's moderation by suggestion).

Comment: @Zilog80: I've only ever seen one devil - profitability.  The whole network needs revenue to keep the lights on, and given the way that venture capital was raised, I don't think making this service a non-profit was ever a tenable option.  So, revenue is needed.  In the void of decisions clearly made for the good of the overall community, decisions or actions are taken that are presumed to be for the good of the company's long-term vitality.  It's not a problem that lights need to stay on; what *is* the problem is that this comes at the effective loss of what made this place worth staying for.

Comment: @Makoto I see your point. The effective problem is who the "sponsors" will grant a "recognized" token as it can undermine the moderation work. As it is, it is a hazardous/ _perilous_ path, as we have no potential lever on it.

Comment: "projects have leveraged Stack Overflow more as a forum or help desk in the past" - For sure.  My first thought here was the `[wso2]` tag, how their site linked to their tag on SO, and how that tag has basically become a dumping ground for poorly formed questions which rarely generate answers or upvotes.  And even if they start a "collective" for it, how will that improve their consistently abysmal content?

Comment: @Makoto It would be possible to run this as a non-profit open source operation. However, it is not. Profit isn't there just to keep the servers running but to make the stock holders rich. That's part of the deal of using the site - there will always be the ulterior profit motive and it will always be top priority. There will never exist any benevolent, community-friendly private companies that put the community over profit. If you want that, then use the open source, non-profit alternatives.

Answer (score 154):

> Allow the communities that have formed around specific technologies to engage with the people that are building and supporting those technologies.

I didn't know they could not. What was keeping them?

> Increase the amount of high-quality content around tags related to a Collectives’ technology on Stack Overflow.

Why did they not do it in the past? SO is free for everyone, right?

> Give technical employees of these organizations the tools to contribute their knowledge effectively to the Stack Overflow community.

They could have posted this knowledge in answers, just like the rest of us...

> Provide organizations with a space on Stack Overflow where they can highlight and share relevant content.

I wasn't aware that sharing content on Stack Overflow was such a problem. I share a tag or two with Jon Skeet, I can positively attest that sharing amazing content is absolutely possible with the current tools.

I once wrote an answer in that tag about the internals of the garbage collector and someone came along and said "Well, when I wrote that garbage collector, my reasoning was..." and I thought wow, hot damn, what an amazing answer. It won't get more in-depth than this. So apparently, people are able to come here and contribute freely, even today, without this feature.

So... what exactly is this supposed to fix?

It seems you only do this to give paying customers an opportunity to promote their own content.

If you do want to sell out this way, don't coat it in a tech bubble. Just give the opportunity to everybody so random companies can have those recommendations. "This answer was recommended by McDonald's. I'm lovin' it.".

And give me a share of that money, I think I earned it. I do this for free to help the community, but I won't be someone's ad banner space without payment.

Comment: In the spirit of transparency, I'll note that I have deleted a handful of comments here indicating agreement with this answer. I also think it is a very good answer, but there is no reason to leave a comment stating that. That is what the upvote arrow is meant to show. Please limit yourself to comments only when you are *adding something new* to the answer, and/or when you are asking clarification questions or making suggestions for improvement. (We mods are trying to be judicious and fair in what comments we remove, if any, so please try to help us out by limiting unnecessary volume.)

Comment: I regularly see comments/answers from people involved in building C#. Their answers don't need corporate endorsement, or any kind of authority claim -- they stand on their own. After all any answer can be verified by testing.

Comment: Upvoted, but-- My only problem with this answer is that I see no need to ask that they share their profits with their users. StackOverflow is a for-profit business. They made no promise to share profits with users. Every user chooses to use and contribute to the platform of their own free will because they receive value from doing so. If you aren't receiving enough value to warrant the effort you're putting into contributing, then contribute less. Asking them to send you a check is unreasonable and likely to make it harder for the company to take the rest of your recommendations seriously.

Answer (score 90):

I don't especially like this new feature. As a regular answerer and curator in the [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) tag in fact I'm concerned about how the credibility of non-affiliated content will be impacted.

The question is:

- Will I have to join the Collective for my answers to be valued the same as those of affiliated users?

In general, contributing as an answerer — and to a lesser extent as an asker — to Stack Overflow is already not easy. As reputation is the measure of the value of someone's contributions, new contributors that start at low reputation have to work hard to gain credibility.

But the good news is that so far Stack Overflow has been a place of great **democracy**, in the sense of "community governance". Crowdsourcing and the vote system as envisioned by the founders of this site is certainly not a perfect system, but it allows for a mostly **equal playing field**. Assuming that the majority of users vote fairly based on usefulness of content, by providing good informative content, one can build their reputation; their "credibility". A reputation confined to this site, but still... I'm pretty sure there're people out there who put a link to their SO profile in their resume. And anyway, this is rewarding for all parties involved.

As much as you can deny it, as much as you want to tell yourself that everyone is mature enough or trained enough to use this feature fairly, having additional gatekeeping and special ways to highlight "official" content and "official" users **will have a psychological impact** on those involved <sup>1</sup>. And this means that, if I'm not affiliated, my content—that I craft as accurately as possible—**will be worth less**.

You are shifting control away from the community, you are defying its wisdom; making the process more opaque and more subject to the will of few.

Maybe an enlightened organization will not abuse this. But there *will* be those that do. And then all of us will be sad.

I hope to be proven wrong.

Besides, the visual effect of the Go Collective logo next to the question tags is hideous.

---

<sup>1: the meaning of this sentence is clarified in the comments</sup>

Comment: Your answers will show and be voted on just like any other answer regardless if you join the collective or not, you can keep interacting and gaining reputation on the tag just as before. As you wrote *"Assuming that the majority of users vote fairly based on usefulness of content, by providing good informative content, one can build their reputation; their "credibility""* And that is true, but there are users who abuse reputation too (socks, voting rings, etc). And we deal with them. We do not want a client that abuses collectives either, and we'll talk with them if that happens too.

Comment: @CesarM If I read the OP correctly, I have similar qualms. It's not so much about the paying customer company abusing the system as it is about regular users being swayed in their voting by the "official" stamp on an answer. I.e.: "If Google says this is the best answer, it must be the best." The banner on user cards for employees and "recognized" members can have similar weight. My, and probably the OP's, fear is the subconscious psychological impact such signals will carry rather than the conscious decisions of users to respond to the same signals.

Comment: @Chindraba Yes this is exactly what I mean

Comment: @CesarM I know that *technically* the voting system won't change. You did your research and you know what the community will never tolerate. Chindraba clarified in the comment above. Placing an official stamp on someone else's profile is an instant devaluation of the contributions of all those who don't have it. They become **primi inter pares** by fiat and not by a democratic process. This has a benefit in giving cred to recognized professionals who happen to never use SO, but at the expense of those who built this website in the first place, day by day over the years.

Comment: This depreciation of traditional SO reputation will probably not affect top scorers. Very high reputation will still command respect and credibility also next to those with company seals of approvals. Under a certain threshold though, who knows... This has the potential to close off SO to new contributors even more than it is today

Comment: I was just bragging a couple weeks ago in the Meta of the community that I moderate about how "_We have no deities here._". The fact the Stack Exchange doesn't place any special emphasis on contributors on a page -- an "equal playing field" as this answer says -- is how everyone can expect fair treatment.  This new feature absolutely falsifies my statement.  This means we have biasing mechanisms in the RX (researcher experience) beyond votes and ticks.  My sympathies to non-collective users who will not have a shining beacon under their posts.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning: once SO gives this power to private, profit-seeking entities, those entities will _never_ surrender it. You may think you can close the box again, but you're mistaken.

Answer (score 75):

You mentioned you don't want to create more work for moderators but didn't mention how moderators will actually interact with Collectives. Will moderators have the ability to make changes/review who has what powers within a Collective? E.g. if they need to edit/manage an article that has profanity or some sensitive information, can they do that? If they need to suspend a user who is the sole admin for a Collective, can they assign a new admin?

For posts, can moderators revoke any labels assigned by Collectives? Can they assign labels for Collectives to posts? (meaning, will they have the power to, not necessarily the authority)

Comment: I'd suppose that these kinds of things are handled by Stack Overflow's sales team.

Comment: All moderator privileges for questions within a collective remain the same. Only the collective’s Recognized Members/Admins/Employees can add/remove the “Answer Recommend by” label to answers within their collective. Only Admins can change permission levels for members (ie. adding/removing the Recognized Member badge on a user card). (1/2)

Comment: For articles, all Admins of the collective have editing rights on all articles. The author of the article has the ability to edit their article. Additionally, the author can add any user (Recognized Members only for now) to the article who would get editing privileges. We’ve worked with customers to provide them with guidelines and help docs to ensure their expectations about community norms and rules are set. We plan to monitor this closely and revisit if any issues arise. (2/2)

Comment: @Carog can admins add users to get editing privileges?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica Currently, Admins can only add users that are labeled as an Admin or Recognized Member. We're looking at expanding the editing permissions on articles with the upcoming tool (mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412005/lets-draft-some-guidelines-for-articles-in-collectives)) that will allow Members to draft and submit articles for inclusion in a collective. We plan to share more details about that tool and other changes included soon.

Answer (score 69):

Are there any plans to ensure that the *Recognized Member* titles are given out in a fair manner? Or is this totally up to the Collective owner?

I can easily see that answers from someone without a title will be considered less valuable in tags controlled by a collective. If a collective can deny membership just so, they could make it way harder to participate in a certain tag just because they don't like a certain user. Or because they are from some specific country/gender/religion.

In case of companies, I can also see that they deny membership to employees of competing companies. This would shift the focus from quality to political/commercial reasons.

Comment: While ultimately it is up to the admins, we onboard all clients and admin users to ensure they have proper guidance and training around the identification of Recognized Members and Recommended Answers. We intend to work closely with them as they use these and other features. That said, answer sorting does not factor in recognized members or recommended answers. Voting and accepted answers will continue to set the priority.

Comment: *Recognized Member* titles have been given out in a fair manner. Anyone who paid SE 1.8 billion dollars got one.

Answer (score 61):

From [collectives page](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives#homepage), I've got an impression you are solving *totally different* issues compared to what you tell us here:

> Find trusted answers, fast

Since when are answers from regular users, upvoted and accepted, not "trusted"? Should new visitors ignore other "non-trusted" answers from now on?

> Stop testing multiple solutions to your questions

How is that possible to achieve? Will collectives buyers sign a contract with SO to ensure they maintain all their answers? How you can guarantee this statement?

> Get product information in one place

> There’s no need to review multiple tag pages

Really? Articles are going to replace all websites and SO will replace hotlines and everything? So naive, so not true.

> Earn a Recognized Member designation from your favorite technology companies. See your answers recommended and check where you rank on the Collectives leaderboard.

Isn't a gold badge in tag enough? Doesn't high reputation mean a better experience with on-site tools? Will I get paid for answers once I am recognized? No?

I must say I am very negative about this. When you design ads you probably should think about other "users", whom you already have here...

Comment: meh, seems like most of the page is marketspeak - not sure there is any real meaning behind those claims

Comment: "*How is that possible to achieve?*" to me, this reads as "ignore answers from non-recommended from non-trusted users. So, anybody who isn't an employee is to be ignored. Unless they get the recommendation blessing.

Comment: Thank you for posting these points.  It saves me having to post an answer that references https://stackoverflow.com/collectives#:~:text=Stop%20testing%20multiple%20solutions%20to%20your%20questions. This is a frank admission that **the goal of these feature is to bias researchers away from non-collective / non-collective-approved answers and toward collective or collective-approved answers**.

Comment: I think it's fair that SO need revenues. Instead of selling more ad space, they sell "trusted answers", like google search. I personally prefer collectives over 3 additional ads on the side bar.

Answer (score 60):

1. What will be the legal requirements for organizations that want to "own" a collective? Is this only possible for registered companies or also for more loose groups like a group of developers working on an open source project?
2. How is SO going to verify if the person who requests a Collective is really authorized to do so?

Comment: And will the "employee" nomenclature change for non-traditional Collectives, e.g. an open-source project or an informal group of users who are all experts in some tag or tag family?

Comment: Will the loose group of developers working on an open source project even have the funds to pay for a Collective?

Comment: @PM2Ring Depends on the pricing :D

Comment: There are no "legal" requirements, but the immediate use case for Collectives is for companies and not-for-profit organizations with multiple tags to be the sponsors of a collective, not to exceed one technology (e.g., Google Cloud vs Google). Our evaluation criteria are that the organization builds, supports, and has some level of authority over the technology. There is currently ongoing research on how we can utilize Collectives outside of this use case. If you are interested in participating in any future research, please [sign up](https://stackoverflow.com/company/research). (1/2)

Comment: Signing up for Collectives isn't a quick process and involves many checks to ensure we are partnering with the correct people. (2/2)

Comment: In connection with my previous comment, Teresa says [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow?answertab=votes#comment851070_408593) that *"We have a very different pricing structure for open source organizations vs commercial and will continue to evaluate them on a case by case basis".*

Comment: If this Collectives thing is successful, it's imperative (IMHO) that Open Source projects be able to participate in it, if they want to. I can easily imagine people saying stuff like "You should use tech X, not tech Y. Tech Y doesn't even have a Stack Overflow Collective".

Answer (score 53):

I was expecting an answer to the [`How`](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives) part of this question upon clicking the `i` icon:

[image]

Not an instruction to simply check back.

Is this placeholder text? A mistake? Should this link to an actual answer to the question?

Comment: I just noticed the same thing, looks like you beat me to it, this sentiment (and lack of actual answer to the question on the landing page) mimics other concerns around costs and other elements and how it might be more difficult for open source communities to utilize the feature

Comment: We’ve removed for now, as it’s a bit confusing given that currently all Collectives are being added by the team manually, we will update when we’ve got more to say about this part.

Comment: @DavidLongworth: Why you didn't change the text you said in the comment that a Collective is added by the team manually. Is it a secret? Or else I find no reason of taking this banner down.

Answer (score 51):

I hold a bronze badge in Go,<sup>1</sup> and I have to say I don't like this at all. It's
just spam on my questions page, as it's on every single question:

> [image: spam]

and all of them are just links to the same page.<sup>2</sup> For now, it's just yet
another thing that I need to add to uBlock Origin filters. If anyone wants to
*really* see what Stack Overflow has become, here is my current list:

```
stackoverflow.com###announcement-banner
stackoverflow.com##.js-consent-banner
stackoverflow.com##.js-sidebar-zone
stackoverflow.com##.ps-fixed
stackoverflow.com##[href^="/collectives/"]
stackoverflow.com##[href^="https://stackoverflow.blog/"]
stackoverflow.com##[role="banner"]
```

---

1. https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/928/go?userid=1002260
2. https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go

Comment: To be fair, the [tag:go] tag is on every single question, too. I agree though that seeing *double* is not a good thing.

Comment: And if the question is tagged both [go] and [google-cloud], it looks [like this](https://i.imgur.com/o7eM8op.png). This is concerning. What if a question has 5 "Collective tags"?

Comment: Seems like an easy solution to this is to hide the [tag:go] tag when there is also a collective with the same name?  Then it's at least not *more* spammy...

Comment: or just, not attach fake collective tags to posts

Comment: @Joe The tag link is important to go to the explanation page, to see the "Learn more ..." link, to get the Tags Description on hover etc. I do not like it to vanish

Comment: Thanks for the rules for uBlock Origin. How can I remove the Collectives' widget from SO's home page as well?

Answer (score 49):

If I am not a member of a Collective, will I still see the banners applied by that Collective to answers and questions if I come across them organically?

Before we relied on the Stack Overflow community to tell us which answer is optimal through voting, but now there might be an explicit or unconscious bias towards what (for example) the GCP team thinks is "best".

Comment: Yes, the "Recommended answer" label and additional badges on user cards will be visible to all users, regardless of membership. However, this will not change the order of answers (still using votes and accepted answers).

Comment: @Carog Thanks for the clarification. I still worry about the powerful effect that such labels will have on the perceived usefulness of a question or answer.

Comment: I think it should only appear if you have joined/opted into a collective.

Comment: @EkadhSingh Please join me [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234131/room-for-discussion-between-tylerh-and-ekadh-singh)

Comment: I second the motion of @TylerH, it _should_ be "opt-in" for registered users not in the "Collective". It's possible a random user might be interested in the collective, and its opinions about content. It's also likely, more  so, that the average user actively does not want to be bothered with such crud. A good answer _is_ good, regardless of some organizational support, or lack thereof. For unregistered users, search engine leads, keep it "on" so that the money spent by the sponsors gets them some ROI.

Comment: @Carog You say that now but SO has already started down the road of pay-to-play so why should we assume the Collective-recommended answer won't find its way to the top? To be fair, the userbase is mainly technical so I expect they'll verify whatever is posted as a response, but you have to understand that we're not overly trusting of the intentions behind this feature.

Comment: @Woody1193  I can't predict the future — unfortunately — so I cannot 100% guarantee that we would never do anything. I can however, tell you that we have no current plans for Collective-recommended answers to affect the sort order. Most (if not all) users we met with during the initial [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408602/the-user-research-behind-collectives-on-stack-overflow) agreed that we should **not** affect sort. Unless that opinion changes drastically with users (which would be researched and tested heavily), it won't be changing the sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 44):

Will the "employee" flag appear on all posts by the user or just those on the relevant tag(s)?

I can see that having it on all posts might get confusing.

Comment: The employee flag and the recognized member flag will appear only under relevant tags

Comment: @PiperLawson thanks. I thought they probably would, but just wanted clarification.

Comment: I can see this [both employees and recognised members] having massive repercussions for situations like FGITW, it's essentially endorsing a post when there can be equally good or better other posts.

Comment: @Nick the idea is to endorse the post by indicating it's by someone who knows what they're talking about. That's why I wanted the clarification over when the label would appear.

Comment: @ChrisF Respectfully... gold badges are endorsements that people know what they're talking about, and they're regularly abused by some individuals, just hoping that this doesn't have a similar effect

Comment: @Nick Well I for one will be on the lookout for things like that. I was one of the mods they consulted over this feature and I was definitely looking at it with an eye to see how it would affect moderation etc.

Comment: @ChrisF Then it sounds like we're in safe hands :p

Comment: Yes, but a lot of people are simple creatures - they see it's endorsed, therefore it must be correct and good, regardless of whether it is or not. I have a feeling  this is gonna make it substantially harder for people to get into answering (read: making answer engagements harder), for both new users and old ones, at least on tags covered by collectives.

Comment: It's a good idea on paper, but it could have a fairly negative effect on individual answerers. We all know it's not exactly easy to get started as it is - whether that becomes harder with collectives is something we'll have to wait and see, but I personally consider it likely that it'll become harder for everyone who doesn't someone end up as an endorsed answerer fast. Being outcompeted by other answers of varying quality because of a semi-official endorsement is potentially bad, in my opinion. At least if it happens, which only time will tell.

Answer (score 39):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Was the character Question Hound (aka "This Is Fine Dog") included in the image on the [Collectives landing page](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives) with the permission of creator [KC Green?](http://kcgreendotcom.com/index.html)

[image: Screenshot of Collectives landing page with Question Hound highlighted by a freehand red circle]

Comment: Even if it *wasn't*, wouldn't that be KC Green's problem to deal with and not necessarily ours?

Comment: From a legal standpoint, sure, though we're more than free to express displeasure with the company's ethics.

Comment: Interestingly, the binary sequence `01110100 01101111 00101101 01100100 01101111` is 'to-do' in ASCII.

Comment: Very good spot - we've removed the ok canine now.

Answer (score 38):

There is really only one thing I want companies to do on Stack Overflow, and that is to have their experts answer questions here, especially those that wouldn't get an answer otherwise. The people that wrote the code and worked on a particular feature are often the ultimate experts on that topic. They can write answers that explain more about the general design and concepts beyond just the specific question. And for more specialized and narrow questions sometimes they're the only ones that actually know enough about how stuff works behind the scenes to answer at all.

Getting more of these experts on Stack Overflow would be a good thing. I'm not convinced this feature will do anything like that. And the commercial nature of this feature and the way it provides certain capabilities to employees of companies that pay for it sets up new potential conflicts with the community.

I think that going beyond Q&A and into something like articles is important for Stack Exchange sites, but I'm not hopeful this iteration of the idea will work well. It avoids the most difficult parts on how to curate them, how to organize collaboration and how to encourage and reward users that provide good content in that format. It's entirely up to the company whether to post good in-depth technical content or sales pitches.

I don't think the name is good, but I'm not good at naming things so don't take this feedback too seriously. It has strong associations to socialism or the political left to me, which creates a lot of dissonance when I know it's a commercial feature. My most cynical interpretation would be that it's a fitting name for a feature that is designed to let the masses work for big corporations for free.

Comment: _"a feature that is designed to let the masses work for big corporations for free_" I couldn't have said it better. What concerns me more than the name is that newly created Collectives sort of "hijacked" the existing questions and answers. The [stats of a Collective](https://i.imgur.com/YadLqXm.png), for one, is **very misleading**. This makes it sound like hundreds of thousands of questions were posted _to that Collective_ (they were not!) and that the Collective itself has reached hundreds of millions of people in its (short) lifetime (it did not!).

Comment: Organization would probably have been a better name, I guess. It's more generic. Collective has connotations that do not go together with the other labels like admin or employee.

Comment: Yes, agreed on the associations. They really ought to have preempted it by revealing the thinking behind the name. It is close to the word *[collectivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectivism#Marxism%E2%80%93Leninism)*, though they may have meant a [hive mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg#Borg_Collective).

Answer (score 36):

I'm struggling to understand how collectives is going to help me as a user searching for answers.

The recommendation/recognition system, if working as intended, is going to be effectively serve as another accept. Now suppose I came here to solve a problem, and I'm faced with

- the most upvoted answer
- the accepted answer
- the recommended answer
- the answer by the recognized member

What do I do?

If they are the same answer, then the system added nothing. If they aren't, they serve to confuse. How does this improve upon the voting system?

Comment: That's a good point, and it's part of the reason why I think this Collectives thing should be something that's is completely separated from the regular questions (which, of course, will never happen).

Comment: You could probably use a combined measure of trust. For example count accepted and recommended answers as 10 extra upvotes each.

Comment: @Trilarion How is the user supposed to know how much each is supposed to mean for every different question? Why doesn't the UI reflect that trust?

Comment: What do you want, a percentage that tells you how much you can trust an answer? Or a factor that tells you how much better one answer is than another. Or something else? Already now there is a problem how to interpret scores. With the new features it becomes even harder and may just lead to confusion but it's also possible that a combined measure would be statistically more precise and accurate as a measure of quality. Doesn't have to be though.

Comment: ...and when one answer has all four of these metrics then we have excessive/unnecessary confirmation -- https://www.snopes.com/tachyon/2016/05/nkextramedals.jpg?resize=600%2C338&crop_strategy=smart

Answer (score 35):

The "Collective" indicator seems to show up as an additional tag in the tags section:

[image: a [go] question with two [go] tags]

1. Will this affect how we tag questions or the number of tags we can apply?
2. Will we be able to choose *not* to affiliate our question with a collective that is associated with those tags? E.g. if I want to ask a "Go" question but am not interested in the "Go Collective"'s input.

   Maybe there is a Collective (or just some active individuals in that Collective) that have garnered a reputation for being wrong, or pushing low-quality/harmful work.

   To be clear, I don't mean a way to turn off Collective features for *me*, I mean a way to *block* Collective interaction with my post, on a per-post basis.

Comment: 1. The number of tags remains the same (up to 5). How a question is tagged has not changed. If a tag is part of a collective, the collective’s logo will also be displayed with the question. That question would also appear within the list of questions on the collective page. Similar to how that same question would also appear in the list of questions on tag's page.

Comment: 2. No, any question that has a tag associated to a collective will automatically be associated to that collective. Anyone on Stack Overflow can answer a question, that includes members of a collective and non-members. Contributions to a post will not be restricted based on their role type in the collective. Any user with the minimum amount of rep needed can also add comments and edits to a post.

Answer (score 35):

I am 100% in favor of attracting and motivating more professionals to engage as SMEs on Stack Overflow, **but**...

We already have thousands of users who are generating redundant content to farm rep points and boost their presence in this community.

Let's see these collective SMEs behave with real purpose and make optimal contributions.

Instead of having collective leaderboards which focus on number of answers posted and number of unicorn points earned, let's have smarter leaderboards.  Show us positive curation metrics such as: flagged/voted/hammered duplicates, recommended answer stamps on non-collective users' answers, necro-edits, necro-answers, etc.  These things help to improve/curate EXISTING content instead of feverishly generating new content.

---

I have another concern on collective user behaviors -- being that so many askers deem question closure as a punishment / not welcoming, how likely are these company representatives going to be to flag/vote to close and downvote questions that *should* be closed/downvoted? I have a feeling that they will be "too soft" about upholding quality standards.

By not being part of the solution, they risk being part of a pre-existing problem.

Answer (score 34):

I'm concerned about the "paywall" aspect of this, presumably Google is forking over money for Collectives. I'm hoping that doesn't change any expectations involving SO standards; for example if a recognized user is posting answers that border on advertisements and/or spam we won't see SO coddle those answers at the expense of the communities expectations of what should happen to that kind of content.

In all other cases I'd expect community driven moderation to manage this just fine, but now there's some cash perhaps tipping the scales in ways we can't see.

This just feels like the "News" equivalent of sponsored content

Comment: There's no change in our standards, the community can vote to close/delete and make edits as usual - this is not a way to bypass community moderation or force advertisement/spam onto the platform.

Comment: I don't see any paywall aspect mentioned in the announcement. Are you imagining the company will start hiding Collective-labeled content behind a paywall?

Comment: @TylerH no, bad wording I suppose, more that they'll value the input/votes of companies that pay for Collectives over the community itself.

Comment: @Culyx a core tenet throughout this initiative was to make sure we don't disrupt the existing Q&A model, including the content standards we have in place. We set very clear expectations with organizations around what's allowed vs. off-topic, and we've had training sessions and shared guidelines with their teams prior to launch. +1'ing what Cesar said, this isn't a way to force advertising or bypass our standards.

Answer (score 33):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Unlike on question and answers, it's not possible to click on the score of an article to view the upvotes and downvotes. Was this intentional or will such a feature be added to articles in the future?

[image]

Comment: This was not intentional and likely a symptom of porting over from teams, which does not include downvoting in their articles. I have logged the bug with the team. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @PiperLawson Thanks for replying. I've marked the answer with the relevant tags. Feel free to edit if/when needed.

Comment: Interesting that the buttons are so different from normal up- and downvotes, as if they signify something different. And the size of the buttons seems to indicate they are much more important than the score itself.

Comment: @Scratte I don't know if it's the same in Teams (never used it) but based on Piper's comment above, it could be the case. I do agree though that the font size of the score is too small compared to the size of the buttons. I think it's even smaller than the body's font size. Maybe this should be posted as a separate bug/feature-request.

Comment: @Scratte: That bothers me as well. And there are a number of other variations in the design that set these apart from normal Q&A. I can see arguments for and against that—they are, after all, not Q&A, so distinguishing them in _some_ way seems useful. As is, however, a lot of those changes (such as the location of metadata) seems arbitrary, while other changes (such as the voting buttons) fall into an uncanny valley of being just off enough that it feels like a mistake. If there are going to be design differences, I'd rather them be more deliberate and pronounced.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I've heard that it's been under development for a year. But despite the long time used for this, it seems there are more than a few bugs. I expect the reason is that some elements are built from the ground up (along with someone forgetting to test it).. which strikes me as an odd choice, since the entire "feature" intermingles with regular posts, as in banners, tags and user acknowledgements.

Answer (score 32):

I am very skeptical of this initiative. To me, it sounds like it is turning SO into a combination of a promotion platform and a support platform for companies. Worse, the work is—to a large extent—done for free by SO users. This really has a bad smell.

Today, we have a close reason that says:

> Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more
> This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

But now, SO is to become a platform for promotion of specific tools. That's bad.

I hope the fate of this initiative will be the same as the long gone "Documentation" initiative.

Comment: You have a point here but _"now, SO is to become a platform for promotion of specific tools"_ in and of itself is not really a bad thing. I mean it's not like SO didn't have ads before or things like sponsored tags. The problem is the potential for those companies to be more involved in the content creation/curation process that ends up affecting the quality. Not _merely_ the fact that they're paying to be promoted.

Answer (score 27):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On the profile page (both when seeing other user's profile and my own) there is a prominent "Invite to Collective" button.

[image]

No idea what's supposed to do, but it doesn't do a thing.

<sup>if this is not the place to report bugs regarding the beta launch, I'll just delete this quietly</sup>

Comment: Thanks for letting us know! That shouldn't be there. We're fixing it.

Comment: That is not a button for you. it is meant for those that want you to be part of their collective. If no-one clicks that button you're not of enough value to any collective. I feel we need a collectables collective where those without a collective can find support.

Comment: But I want to be part of my collective, @rene. My collective is the for the ones outside other collectives, and that have trouble understanding the usefulness of the feature.

Comment: Kewl. I can be in your collective then! Where we can be both annoying ;)

Comment: @rene  [but can we have a collective for all users not part of a collective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox)?

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, we can call it [the Collective Front of Judea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WboggjN_G-4)

Answer (score 27):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

What is an "endorsed edit"? This seems like just too much, both in terms of what value this new feature has and in terms of noise for viewers/readers. What value could endorsing an *edit* provide? Take this example:

[image]

The user added *a tag*. Is the edit so valuable/high quality that it deserves an "endorsement"?

Comment: Do you have a link to that rev. page?

Comment: @zcoop98 https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68106939/revisions It showed the "google employee" Collective flair under the user's name under the post where "last edited by" exists. Check out another one of their revisions from their profile to see it still live somewhere.

Comment: Found one; that's really funky. The "Notice added" event is in both the revisions list and the timeline, but doesn't appear to actually show up as a visible post notice. My guess is that it was simply a way for SE to indicate that a given edit was performed by a recognized collective member/ employee using the current revision and timeline system (regardless of whether the edit is substantial). It's definitely weird to me to use "Notice added/ removed" events even though no actual post notice seems to exist.

Comment: Maybe the endorsement was initiated by the editor himself? Kind of: "trust my edit, behind me is the might of the collective".

Comment: Do *all* of the edits that Frank makes to posts with the tags corresponding to the Google Cloud Collective carry this "Endorsed Edit" annotation? (I.e., is the system adding it automatically to everything he does because he's an "official" representative of the collective?) Or is it something that he has to manually indicate each time? UPDATE: There seems to be a bug in the implementation of this feature, already reported: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408778

Comment: @CodyGray I would assume yes: e.g. if the question has a collective tag, then any post in the thread last edited by Frank is going to show that label...

Answer (score 26):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When doing a search for a collective's posts, please don't list all of the tags that they own, searching for: [`collective:"Google Cloud"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=collective%3A%22Google+Cloud%22) gives:

> Results tagged with google-cloud-python or google-cloud-pubsub or google-cloud-dlp or google-app-engine-launch or google-app-engine-python or google-cloud-cpp or google-cloud-recommendation or google-cloud-vision or google-app-engine-go or google-cloud-data-transfer or google-cloud-automl or google-cloud-datastore or google-cloud-endpoints-v2 or google-cloud-sdk or google-data-studio or google-cloud-storage or google-cloud-asset-inventory or google-cloud-url-maps or google-container-registry or google-cloud-monitoring or google-cloud-filestore or google-cloud-memorystore or google-cloud-data-fusion or google-bigquery or google-cloud-tools or google-cloud-healthcare or google-cloud-talent-solution or google-cloud-profiler or google-cloud-dataflow or google-cloud-identity or google-cloud-print or google-cloud-console or apigee or google-cloud-pubsublite or google-cloud-language or google-cloud-load-balancer or google-migrate-for-compute-engine or google-cloud-network-load-balancer or dialogflow-es-fulfillment or google-cloud-composer or google-cloud-test-lab or google-app-engine-patch or google-cloud-api-gateway or google-cloud-http-load-balancer or google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy or google-cloud-armor or google-cloud-visualstudio or google-prediction or dialogflow-es or google-container-optimized-os or google-cloud-vpn or google-cloud-repository or google-cloud-nl or google-cloud-internal-load-balancer or google-cloud-ai or firebase-realtime-database or google-cloud-tasks or google-cloud-debugger or google-cloud-ml or google-cloud-search or dialogflow-cx or google-cloud-marketplace or google-cloud-ml-engine or google-cloud-tpu or google-cloud-intellij or google-cloud-powershell or google-cloud-datalab or google-cloud-sql or bigtable or apigee-baas or google-cloud-firestore or google-cloud-stackdriver or google-app-engine-golang or google-cloud-iot or google-cloud-dns or google-cloud-automl-nl or google-cloud-spanner or google-cloud-dataproc or google-cloud-node or gcloud or google-app-engine-deploy or google-container-os or google-cloud-error-reporting or google-cloud-php-client or google-cloud-iam or google-cloud-source-repos or google-cloud-translate or google-app-engine or google-cloud-scheduler or google-dataflow or google-cloud-functions or google-cloud-code or google-cloud-logging or google-cloud-speech or google-cloud-launcher or google-cloud-spanner-emulator or google-kubernetes-engine or google-cloud-robotics or google-analytics-firebase or google-compute-engine or google-cloud-bigtable or google-cloud-trace or google-cloud-messaging or google-anthos or google-cloud-print-privet or google-container-builder or google-cloud-networking or google-fusion-tables or google-cloud-billing or google-cloud-metrics or google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines or google-cloud-proxy or google-cloud-resource-manager or google-cloud-platform or google-cloud-shell-editor or google-cloud-kms or google-cloud-interconnect or google-cloud-router or google-cloud-build or google-cloud-run or google-cloud-shell or google-cloud-endpoints or google-cloud-save or google-cloud-registry or google-cloud-pubsub-emulator or google-cloud-instance-template or google-cloud-speech-boost or google-cloud-webrisk or google-cloud-storage-r or google-cloud-cdn or google-app-engine-php or google-cloud-dataprep

Comment: That's a *big* tag list. The tags on that page [fill my entire screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHiVY.png) and then some. I do like being able to see all tags that are part of a collective, but there's gotta be a better way than this.

Comment: Wildcards. Use 'em: [google-cloud-*]

Comment: @CodyGray I mean sure but then why be able to search by collectives at all? Your wild card ain't inclusive enough anyway, what about Google container? Or Google app? Or Google fusion? Or Google dataflow? Or Google migrate? Or apigee? Google Kubernetes?.... ;)

Comment: _"google cloud cdn app engine netflix samsung kubernets apigee dataflow"_ should be on there... :p.

Comment: You can then search by wildcards yourself...

Comment: so... it is actually possible to make long queries? :) How about them also working on removing the query length limit (if URL length limit is a concern, then the query could be send in the payload instead)

Comment: I appreciate you tagging this as a [feature-request] cause that assumes a deliberate choice ;). It is a bug though. It shouldn't show all the tags. We're working on fixing it :)

Comment: [This has been fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTq1V.png) in the meantime!

Comment: @zcoop98 Yep, now the only problem is it doesn't show _additional_ tags: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TjWg.png, but i can live with that

Comment: @AlizaBerger Perfect, the results for that are exactly what i'd expect them to be now, thanks!

Answer (score 26):

My reaction to the *feature* is somewhere between "meh" and "yeah nah". My main reaction to the *rollout* however is "lol". You're telling me that SE worked together with Google, created the collectives **6 weeks ago**, and all these two paragons of computer technology managed to prepare in these 6 weeks was 10 "recommended" answers and a handful of selected members in each collective? Not even a single article written ahead of time? Not even taking the time to go over the top 1k (or just top 200) questions of the tags and recommending everything of value? This doesn't exactly inspire confidence that Google will be a good steward for these collectives, which in return does not inspire confidence in the feature.

At the time of writing this, there's now a single article in the cloud collective (from a Google employee), which reads like an answer to an unstated question. It consists of a two-sentence introduction followed by code, and doesn't exactly feel like an "article" - for that, I'd expect a decent introduction that explains what kinds of real-world situations this code applies to or what problems it solves. To call this high-quality content would be quite a stretch, thus the goal of being better than SO.docs by restricting the articles to a selected group of users seems to have failed already...

Comment: Let's wait and collect a larger sample of articles before it should be declared a success or a failure. On the other hand, quality of the content of the articles will be a key factor in the decision.

Comment: @Trilarion well, a big part of this answer is me saying _you had at least 6 weeks to prepare and have literally nothing to show for it_. Followed by the fact that the first thing they actually have to show is... not garbage, but far from high quality. I don't need to wait to say that this is a very bad rollout. It might get improved, but if the day-1 reaction to a new feature is "well let's wait if it gets better", that's pretty bad in my book.

Comment: I agree. I just looked at the one currently existing article and it was quite short, even shorter than a good typical answer in Q&A. I commented on it.

Answer (score 25):

Are the "12 moderators and high-rep Meta users" still bound by the NDA?

Or is it possible that they post candid answers here about their experience participating in this product discovery, and what are their thoughts on the result that was launched today?

Comment: Undo [commented on the other post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408602/the-user-research-behind-collectives-on-stack-overflow#comment850721_408602) with their experience. So I think they aren't bound by the NDA anymore.

Comment: We're not going to say who these users were to respect their privacy - however, if they want to talk about their experiences, they can (like Undo did). I'm working on getting an official answer regarding the NDA.

Answer (score 25):

> How will recommended answers affect .... and the rep system? ...
> In terms of rep: it will have no effect on the reputation you get from answers.

For sure it will. A "recommended answer" tag will be a big sign drawing attention to that specific answer. Consequently, it will gain more upvotes than other answers. The "Recognized Member" badge will do the same.

I have no doubt that these two concepts will impact the rep system.

Answer (score 24):

Not sure if it has been addressed already, can there be more than one collective for any given tag? Could there be competing collectives? Could multiple collectives recommend the same or different answers to a single question?

Comment: If the first is no, how is it decided which competing collective would get a given tag? Highest bidder?

Comment: For example: GitHub (Microsoft) and GitLab could be their own collective/org. They have specific tags (for instance: github-action vs. gitlab-ci for pipelines). Would they share the "git" tag? (the common version control tool they both use)

Comment: @yivi Just want to know. But even if there is only 1 collective per tag, it might still be more than one collective per question if a question has tags from more than one collective.

Comment: @Trilarion The scenario of more than one collective per question already happens. Having Google as customer with Google Cloud and Golang as "collectives", [it's not particularly difficult for it to happen](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-*%5D+and+%5Bgo%5D+is%3Aquestion). I guess the maximum is 5 collectives per question.

Comment: Technically a tag could be associated with two Collectives, but this would be extremely rare (random example: [google-maps-sdk-ios]). Which tags will and will not be associate with a Collective is defined by whether the organization builds, supports, and has authority over a particular subject. So in the example of Git, I don't think this applies to any organization (like @yivi describes).  Multiple collectives can recommend the same (and different) answers, this would be a more likely situation when a question has tags that are associated with different Collectives.

Answer (score 20):

Will the revision history or timeline of a post include information about *which user* applied *which label* to a post that is contained within a Collective? Will rollbacks revert those label applications?

Comment: The “Answer recommended by'' label is meant to be seen as a recommendation from the organization, not just a single user. At this time, we do not plan to add additional information within the revision history to show which specific user added the label. If future research suggests a need for it, we will revisit. Rollbacks do not revert a label being added to an answer. Only the collective’s Recognized Members/Admins/Employees can add/remove the “Answer Recommend by” label to answers within their collective.

Answer (score 20):

You know, I *kind of* like the "recommended answer" part, but I can see it going wrong, fast.

The reason I like it, is that I've been fantasizing about a way to highlight quality answers for a while. I have thought about proposing a review system, in the sense of established users properly reviewing a post on points like readability, applicability, compatibility, security, correctness, maintainability and so on. Something more than just up- and downvotes.

This "seal of approval" does that in a very basic way: it gives a visible "trusted +1", so to say. But just as with votes, you'll have to look out for the abrupt devaluation of this seal.

Or: [who trusts the trusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quis_custodiet_ipsos_custodes%3F)?

If, for example, a given collective mass-employs recognized members who in turn approve any answer that even remotely seems to answer the question, then it's borked by design. It'll become equivalent to the decades-old Microsoft forums joke (there's a tautology in there somewhere):

- User posts a question
- Moderator / independent contractor / power user posts their default boilerplate canned answer they post to every frigging question that hits a certain keyword (*"Try running system restore, don't forget to like and subscribe"*)
- User has seen this before and gives up, sometimes tries responding which is usually ignored
- Moderator returns after a few days, marks thread as inactive, marks their own answer as best

You don't want that seal to hold *that* little value, now do you?

So how can a company manage all questions in a tag as large as Go, let alone Java or C# or JavaScript (and who can manage the latter)? Is the UI efficient to filter and sort through new and existing questions and answers? Is someone (Stack Overflow staff, moderators, users) watching what those collectives and their members do, now and in the near *and* far future? What about duplicate questions that are still open, and duplicate answers where some or all of them receive a seal? Can users flag a marked post to tell a moderator, or the collective's users (or both) that the answer shouldn't be sealed, as it's promoting a bad practice or incorrect?

Comment: Also how do recommended answers play with outdated answers?, e.g. Your "recommended" modern JS answer isn't worth anything to me when I'm running IE11, what's the recommended old answer? Or what when the recommended answer is too old to be recommended? Do the recommendations decay or get reviewed periodically? The recommendations appears to just be an additional checkmark, and the potential to be equally useless.

Comment: @Nick my thoughts exactly, hence the questions. :)

Comment: I kinda don't like this, because recommended answers can age just like anything else and if not constantly watched and moderated, after a while we will have huge problem on our hands, even worse than accepted answers because now those answers will have "quality" seal attached. Not to mention, that quality seal can be misused by company employees. So, I wouldn't exactly start answer with "like", but I pretty much agree with the rest.

Comment: @Dalija yes, that's why I start my answer with why I like it, followed by way more text explaining why I could see this going entirely the wrong way.

Comment: I figured as much... but people tend to read "like" too literally, so I felt the need to emphasize the dislike ;)

Answer (score 18):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The "Read the post on Meta" button at the bottom of the [/collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives) page links to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ instead of where I would assume, which would be this post.

For reference, I'm talking about this button:

[image: Picture of the Read the post on Meta button towards the bottom of the Collectives page]

Could you update this link to link to here?

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani In addition, the text says "feeback" in stead of "feedback" (missing a **d**).

Comment: @g00glen00b ‍♂️  thanks for catching that. On it!

Comment: link is updated! looking around the office for a spare 'd' now...

Comment: @DavidLongworth Sorry I can't help, all I've got are "Ctrl", "C", and "V" keys.

Answer (score 17):

I like the idea about clusters of tags that are somehow relevant together and I like the idea of having additional content in form of articles but I'm not sure if collectives will be a good influence. It's somehow a social network features where people and connections between people count more than actual content. I feel that there is a great risk of bias and lower quality in the end (a rigged system).

I could imagine that users would actually like to opt out of this feature, i.e. do not see recommendations, badges, labels, invitations and other spaces related to collectives, as this may enhance the focus on the content.

What are the ways to opt out? If there are none, could you consider adding some?

Comment: user-script in your browser?

Answer (score 17):

**Why corp-only?**

Entry barrier could be as low as knowing you *can* promote chatroom members to write&tag for the room. Nothing Google-specific or requiring corp structure about:

- managing watched tags together
- using that to focus on a group of tags more easily
- live & more accessible metrics
- flagging where vote rank is unexpected for like-minded
- long-form writing that would not qualify as a great Q&A
- and any sort of easily (un)subscribable notifications for all of those

All welcome building blocks to increase quality across topic/technology groups not necessarily aligning with our current network boundaries. **Only some sub-features need be gated** to paying customers:

- customize one contributor role to publicly say spell "employee"
- adblockable public icons/text on flagged posts

Everything else about Collectives<sup>BETA</sup>, both implemented or only hinted at features, **sounds useful to everyone - with matching moderation cost**.

Comment: because this feature is a combination of some teams features, and sponsored tags. the sponsored tags bit doesn't really jive with it being free. If you want the teams features, you can already have them, at least in a private scenario.

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

Downvoting an article results in an inbox notification with a URL that doesn't work.

> [image: -1 on an article]

Which links to `https://stackoverflow.com/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android` instead of `https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android`.

There's also [no record of the vote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6296561/zoe?tab=votes&sort=downvote) (mod/CM-only link) under "votes" on my profile

Comment: For me, it links to the second (working) link. I'm not sure what the `-1` means though, since it doesn't affect the rep or anything.

Comment: @41686d6564 it [does affect rep](https://i.imgur.com/NHokkma.png) for me and the poster. Upvoting or downvoting articles behaves just an equivalent vote on a normal post in terms of rep for the poster and voter. See also https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen?tab=reputation

Comment: Yes, I can see the rep change now. Not sure why it didn't work before. So, it works exactly like downvoting _answers_.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/ - and yes, just like downvoting an answer. My bad

Comment: Paying with reputation on regular answers makes sense, to prevent abuse from other answerers. Paying with reputation on Articles does not since there are no competing answers. We need to be able to judge the quality of Articles, without being punished for it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but let me know if you're still seeing issues!

Comment: This is arguably more likely to be [status-complete] than [status-norepro]. The URL seems to have been corrected now at least

Comment: @AlizaBerger I've been able to repro it again by clicking the notification on meta rather than on main. Redirects correctly if I click on main SO, not if I click it on meta

Comment: I can repro it on any site that isn't SO

Answer (score 14):

**Is the widget on the (right) sidebar temporary?**

I just noticed that there's a widget on the (right) sidebar listing existing Collectives and pushing down Hot Network Questions:

[image: Widget on the sidebar with 3 collectives]

Considering that there's already a "Collectives" item on the left navbar with a link that says "Explore Collectives", *and* that when I join Collectives, they get listed there, what's the point of that widget to the right? Is it just temporary to get people to notice the launch Collectives? Or is it permanent and will list more Collectives as they're added?

Comment: Even if this were intended to show only for the Collectives a user is in, I can't see how it would scale well at all. Certainly they don't foresee a scroll bar?

Answer (score 13):

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)

Particular Articles don't have a direct link for opening. I can only access it by clicking on the comments link.

[image]

Comment: See [Articles don't have titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408776/articles-dont-have-titles).

Answer (score 13):

Will moderators/the community have any way to fix/flag these

> Answer recommended by (company name)

suggestions if they are clearly incorrect/out of date?

If not, this feels like the sort of system that will work well for a while, but eventually become unmanageable. It seems quite comparable to the problem with [outdated accepted answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project), if you only have a small number of people capable of fixing something, having a way to bring it to their attention seems vital.

Clarification: By "flag", I mean bring it to the attention of the company endorsing the answer, rather than the traditional flagging to close.

Comment: This seems covered by the explanation that user moderation capabilities on Q&A will not be affected, so if you see an incorrect/out-of-date answer you can edit or downvote it or leave a comment explaining how it is incorrect/out-of-date.

Comment: @TylerH That's true, but assuming the answerer and the person who marked it as "recommended" aren't the same person, the company who endorsed that answer have no way to know about the downvote/comments assigned to it?

Comment: If a company is that concerned, hopefully they're continually monitoring their own recommended content to make sure it is always up to snuff. Nothing so far indicates users can't delete negatively-scored answers even if they are recommended by some Collective...

Comment: I just think it's highly unlikely that most companies will check back in on old recommendations once there are a significant number of them, unless it's pointed out that something needs updating. To be clear, this is not relating to standard moderation, downvotes/deletions are fine for "bad" answers, but a "good" but outdated answer that is recommended could easily convince people not to use a new "better" method.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Apparently, when the Recognized Member is also an employee, the label/badge is not shown on their user card. For example, this is how Jon Skeet's user card looks under a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40762475/8967612) that is tagged [google-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform):

[image]

Compare that to the user card of a non-employee Recognized Member in the Go Collective:

[image]

The post above mentions that the employee label should be displayed:

> An Admin/Recognized member can have the employee label. This will not affect any of their permissions but **would show this on any post they make**

So, it should probably show the same badge but with the Employee label rather than Recognized Member.

---

Note: This could end up being a different problem specific to the Google Cloud Collective. I couldn't verify because:

- The only non-employee Recognized Member in that Collective doesn't have any related posts.
- The Go Collective does not have any employees.

Comment: The Recognized Member badge only appears on posts that were written while they were a Recognized Member. The badge won't be added to posts previously written by the same user. The badge is tied to the post.

Employee labels behave similarly with a slight difference: if the Employee label is removed from the user (no longer an employee), any previous engagement/posts by that user will now show the Recognized Member badge instead. We didn't want to label a user as an Employee unless it's current.

Comment: @Carog Yeah, I think you're right. But in that case, [their older answers should not be highlighted as top contribution in the Collective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct8Ib.png). That's what confused me in the first place.

Comment: Additionally, the [leaderboard label](https://i.imgur.com/AgSyyru.png) is displayed on all posts for Recognized Members, but not for employees as shown above.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! Looking into this now.

Comment: Ok I see what's going on @41686d6564, in the leaderboard we highlight all contributions from any Member of the collective. In the screenshot you provided, the answer displayed is the top contribution that user made (before they were labelled as an Employee) but still considered the 'top' within the 'Last 12 months' (filter).

Comment: The trophy icon is attached to the user card (instead of the post). Those icons are given to the top 3 users of the leaderboard while actively in those positions.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

I'm a member of the Stack Overflow community.

I'm not a member of any new (or any to-come) communities like:

[image]

I suppose (aka strongly hope) that this should read "More from the Google Cloud Collective".

Please fix.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, You're right, this is a bug. We'll be fixing it.

Answer (score 10):

> Articles
>
> Collectives on Stack Overflow adds the ability to create , longer form content that lives on the collective page. We first introduced this feature within our Teams product last year, and we have seen strong adoption and usage. Articles give Recognized Members the opportunity to provide deeper knowledge and insights through how-to-guides, knowledge articles, or announcements. Initially, Articles can only be posted by Admins and Recognized Members of a collective, but we’re planning to release a feature (in the near term) that would allow any member of a collective to submit an Article for review.

Articles seem to be different from normal Q&A (even self-answered Q&A) although they also seem to give reputation and allow voting on. What exactly is the relation between the two kinds of content? Where are the differences?

For example, can articles be duplicate targets of Q&A and vice versa? Can articles be edited and if so by whom? Can I close or delete vote on articles? Do articles need to be focused or clear or not primarily opinionated? Or are they more like random blog posts? If I disagree with an article, can I add to it, provide an alternative version? Do articles provide shared authorship and shared reputation maybe? Are articles completely separate or how do they integrate with Q&A?

Comment: _Initially, Articles can only be posted by Admins and Recognized Members of a collective, but we’re planning to release a feature (in the near term) that would allow any member of a collective to submit an Article for review_

Comment: There is no "edit" button on articles, so presumably only the author or someone Up In The Collective can edit them. And they cannot be used (at least currently) as dupe targets. (And I hope it remains that way).

Comment: There are UI elements to vote, comment, and [provide author feedback to articles](https://cln.sh/S9dNTB). So "disagreement" can already be provided. In theory in the "future" you could submit an article disagreeing with another existing article, but it would be up to the Collective admins to accept it and publish it.

Answer (score 10):

> Questions and Answers will be posted to Stack Overflow, as usual, and the collective page will aggregate all the **relevant** content from selected tags.

At first I expected that the collective-question page was build using a simple OR of all tags registered by the collective but the word "relevant" tells me there are more to this than the tag-system, right?

Please share information about how **relevant** information is found.

Comment: Collectives are based on tags indeed. From OP: Collectives are based on a set of specific tags relating to the technologies that an organization builds, supports, and has an authority over. So that's the way we define relevancy here.

Comment: @JD-Stack So you define **relevancy** as everything that has a specific tag!? So why put the word "relevant" into that sentence if it's really everything?

Comment: @4386427 Why would a question tagged with [go] *not* be relevant to the [go] Collective? What else is required for relevance?

Comment: @TylerH All tags I follow get irrelevant questions. For instance homework dump with no effort. Typos preventing compilation, spam, etc.. all kinds of crap. I assume the GO tag gets the same. Also I assumed that "relevant" indicated a filter to remove such post. Now a know that there is no filter. They just used the word "relevant" to make it sound good but there is nothing to it...

Comment: @4386427 Preventing people from mistagging their questions (or asking off-topic questions) is an issue, sure, but it's one that is way outside the scope of things Collectives is trying to do.

Answer (score 10):

Is [Google cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/groups/-1002) a bot or script like Roomba or something?

Its URL is `https://stackoverflow.com/users/groups/-1002`... The last time I saw a user with a negative UserId it was a bot:

[Processed Meat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-589/processed-meat) with `https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-589/processed-meat`

and

[Feeds](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-2) with `https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-2`

If it is a bot then what does it do? Does it add "Endorsed edits by ..." if an employee tries to add some specific tags to a question?

Also, why is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68105180/revisions) happening? Is it a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

[image: Google cloud doesn't seem to able to decide]

Comment: Reported here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408608

Comment: The "Endorsed edit" thing is also mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408686/8967612) (but not the repeated addition and removal).

Answer (score 10):

You mention having a different "pricing structure" for open-source projects, but I'm struggling to see why an open-source project (which typically have limited to no budget) would pay money for this feature.  It seems relatively straightforward to duplicate the "User Roles" functionality by writing up a browser plugin or a Greasemonkey script that decorates answers by project members when they post on questions that have specific tags.  The metrics seem to be things you can already figure out by using the Stack Overflow API or SEDE, just with a pretty UI on top of it.  You wouldn't have the landing page, but that doesn't appear much different than a normal tag page.  You also wouldn't have the 'Articles' feature, but most open-source projects already have something to meet that need (project webpage, blog, GitHub wiki, etc.).

It doesn't seem to me that there's much here to justify an open-source project spending their limited funds on.  "Collectives" simply wraps this functionality up in a nice ready-made package.  That's a viable product strategy for a lot of markets, but we're talking about experienced software developers who are members of a movement that has a history of taking proprietary solutions and rebuilding them in a nonproprietary format.  These seem like the exact people that would be more inclined to put this functionality together on their own than to try and fundraise to pay for it.  In its current state, "Collectives" seems to lack the sort of "killer feature" that would make open-source projects want to subscribe.

Comment: The browser plugin likely wouldn't be that widely distributed and in case for example that recommendations influence sorting order it could become quite complex. If anything you would have to reprogram the whole of SO, I think. But I share your concerns about pricing. Most open source projects I know are so poor they can't even pay their programmers, they won't pay for collectives either. But then, maybe that is the pricing structure. After all more activity directly translates into more income by making the content even better and more valuable.

Comment: "*I'm struggling to see why an open-source project (which typically have limited to no budget) would pay money for this feature.*" Moreover, we already have software authors here who monitor the tags related to their product and answer questions. They typically do a disclosure when answering questions "Author of X here...". So, for some tags, we informally already know who the "recognised users" would be. I don't know if those people would find value in *paying* SO to get that label officially.

Comment: @Trilarion That sounds like yet *another* reason why the nametag decorations shouldn't alter the sort order in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

#### What about questions with tags across multiple collectives?

If I were to ask a question about [using Go to interact with Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=collective%3A%22Google+Cloud%22+%5Bgo%5D), does this mean those from either collective can mark answers as recommended?

- Does the latest recommendation overwrite the earlier one?
- Do both get displayed?
- Would one collective get priority over the other in some way in choosing the recommended answer?
- What if one collective thinks an answer the other recommends is a bad solution?
- What if 2 recognized users from different collectives both try to post their own recommended answers?

For now it's probably not a huge issue (both owned by Google), but once this expands to multiple organisations (e.g. asking about [using Google Cloud with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=collective%3A%22Google+Cloud%22+%5Bjava%5D)), this will probably quickly become a problem.

Comment: Similarly to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow/408638#408638 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408734/town-hall-collectives-on-stack-overflow/408763#408763.

Comment: Was there anywhere written that only one answer per question can be recommended by a collective? I thought you could have multiple recommended answers anyway, from the same or from different collectives.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I might've assumed it's one per question (because usually there'd only be one "best" solution to a problem, allowing multiple recommendations would likely just add more noise in most cases and they refer to the singular "most appropriate answer" when mentioning recommendations). But either way that's something to clarify.

Answer (score 9):

Allowing a company, say Google, to mark an answer with "Recommended Answer" is a great idea.  Until it's not.

Marking certain users as employees or with certain recognition isn't earned because it wasn't assigned by the community.

Answer (score 8):

I have doubts the big firms, like Microsoft, or established companies, like [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Home/Mission.xml), will run here to give you their money.

Why? 
Because they already have all the necessary tools for support and documentation. And accessing those tools is a kind of filter to reduce the load on the support department.

Does anyone sane want to have *more* help requests from thousands of SO "hamsters"? Does anyone want to spend *more* money on support (because more requests require more request handlers)? I don't think so. This department doesn't earn money by itself. Will SO collectives become a sign of high-quality support so that everybody will have to get it to compete with the others? I doubt it.

There are dozens of products to create documentations and to offer support already. Why would someone want to create articles instead?

I believe established firms aren't going to shift it here. I believe successful companies aren't going to benefit even a tiny bit from collectives. You'll get a lot of random startups here (unless it's too expensive) and I have a strong feeling if they ever succeed, they will likely move away to establish their "base" elsewhere, similar to Microsoft [MSDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network)/support.

Perhaps I am too pessimistic.

Comment: I do agree that (big and successful) companies should run their own support and marketing/promotion. It's not what SO is for. But... hmmm... apparently Google is interested and isn't it fair to say that Google is pretty  big and successful ?

Comment: agreed with 4386427 here - Google has been interested in SO for a long time, and they seem to be on board with this. Although that brings a question: if big companies are interested the value proposition should've been substantial. Which makes me a little paranoid.

Comment: @OlegValter Things don't have to have value for Google to invest money in them. That's the downside of having more money than god; even a low level manager is authorized to spend millions of dollars with no checks/balances.

Comment: @TylerH I only referred to the "I have doubts the big firms ... will run here to give you their money."  - apparently they do. And that's what a bit worries me - checks and balances or not, one has to convince another that the money they spend brings them value - which makes me a little worried because if the feature's going to play out as promised, there is little value I see (and that's what makes me a little paranoid)

Comment: Even if big firms are willing to finance this collective adventure of StackOverflow, does it imply that employees are more clever than the community? Somehow I doubt this, because that the reason why StackOverflow became successful in the first place. And if you like to do it right, because the current is it not, then open Collectives to Open Source initiatives and, e.g., make each Open Source Community a Collective. Here we would have at least the certainty that the Open Source-driven answers have a value. However, I fear that this will invite, e.g., the company marketing person "answers."

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Currently user profiles have an Articles section (shown below in the screenshot).

I think the Articles section shouldn't currently be in user profiles because the majority of users haven't authored any Articles yet. I also think the Articles section should only be shown if a user has in fact authored an Article. In its current state it doesn't add any relevant information (using a programming term we could say it's polluting the user profile visually.)

[image: image of Articles in user profile]

P.S. This had previously been reported [in this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404976) and solved when Articles first launched for Teams.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The members page doesn't support time span filter values in the pagination controls navigation links.

For example, starting from [Page one with a time span filter of a one year](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go/?tab=members&TimeSpanFilter=Year&Page=1), the *Page #* and *Next Page* links are missing the TimeSpanFilter parameter and will show data with the default seven-day interval.

[image: Screenshot showing page 2 link missing the TimeSpanFilter=Year paramemter]

https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go/?tab=members&TimeSpanFilter=Year&Page=1

Comment: Thank you for reporting this bug, it has been reported to the developers and prioritized.

Answer (score 7):

**Why is there no Admin label/indicator?**

Currently, there are labels for Recognized Members and Employees. However, unless I visit their profile or check the Collective's admins, I have no way of knowing that this user, for example, is an Admin:

[image]

Even in the Members tab of the Collective, they're listed just like any other Recognized Members:

[image]

I think the user card of an Admin should say something like "Admin in the Go Collective" instead.

Comment: I guess it depends on whether there's a useful distinction, in terms of answer quality or "authoritativeness", between a "recognized" user and an "admin" user in a collective. I would imagine that there *isn't* such a distinction, but maybe that's incorrect. (Unless I'm misunderstanding you proposal)

Comment: I think the answer is more or less already given by @zcoop98. We feel that whether somebody has some additional permissions within the Collective (downloading reports, user management) doesn't affect their association with the content. Therefore we've introduced the labels. (Recognized by & Employee of) which both give some additional context. Feel free to tag me if this needs more clarification :) I'll try to provide it

Answer (score 7):

On the collective page there is this segment "Top answer scores":
[image]

This indicates something plural (because of scores), but there is only a single user here, is it possible for multiple users to show up here?

Also the text states:

> "[user] scored 80 answering questions this week"

What did this user score, unicorns, waffles, reputation, post score? Please clarify.

Comment: [It is possible for multiple users to show up](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go?tab=members).

Answer (score 7):

Will there be an API to interact with the collectives?

Currently, the [user resource](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) on the API does not contain any information about the collectives a user is a member of.

Also, [there does not seem to be a method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs#:%7E:text=type-,Per-Site,Methods,-Each) to list a collective, its members, its tags, etc...

There is a use case to be able to manage collectives through the API. Any company (i.e. the existing "Google Cloud" collective) could use the API to set and remove "employee" status to members through an internal client that verifies they are indeed an employee, rather than have admins manually manage the status of hundreds of members.

Comment: hehe, this sounds as a question we've gotten from (potential) customers.. A lot :). The answer is: yes, there will be an API for customers to manage this stuff through their internal systems

Comment: @JD-Stack What about non-customers? Will regular users be able to get information programatically about collectives? i.e. Just listing members of a collective seems like something that should be public (it is already accessible through the web interface). Also, joining/leaving collectives through the API seems like something a regular user might want to do (not sure in which situation, but who knows...). I'd like to be able to do everything I can do through the web interface to be doable through the API, since scraping the web does not seem like a sustainable solution.

Comment: @JD-Stack Indeed, will this be exposed to SEDE, at least?

Answer (score 6):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

You can see that the [7-days members list](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go?tab=members) and the [30-days members list](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go?tab=members&TimeSpanFilter=Month&Page=1) are not perfectly consistent with each other.

For example, some users who:

- do appear in the 30-days members list
- and do have positively scored posts in the last 7 days

still don't appear in the 7-days members list. (Even after a couple list updates). Is this intended?

Also I would expect the 30-days members list to be somewhat consistent with the [30 days top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/topusers) list. Excluding question askers and top users who didn't join the collective, the rankings are still bit different.

Please can you clarify how this works?

Comment: We've looked into this, and found that this is due to the fact that lists get cached separately(which is a deliberate choice). Even though there are options to make these lists match, this is not something we feel is worth prioritizing, for now, therefore we've changed it to [meta-tag:status-declined].

Answer (score 6):

So... I just finished reading this. I won't go over some of the weird results of this idea, like giving some users a "more equal than the others" status that could either be good or go horribly wrong. For that, there are already many other answers.

I will only point out another aspect of this resource dispersion.

I used to be pretty active on SharePoint questions. SharePoint has its own site, but SharePoint questions are plenty on SO too. So, right off the bat, I got *two* sites with *separate* privileges I would have to earn. Since SO is oversaturated by fast answerers (often using the "post quick fix later" technique someone mentioned in another post), I decided to just focus on SharePoint.SE. But then I got a different problem - a dead site with low traffic, low voting activity ([a site with ***three*** great questions in its whole history is *not* a healthy site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/great-question))...

I lost hope to make my contributions relevant in any way that could give some actual gratification from posting. The few questions I posted had no answers or even "I know this doesn't reply to you, but is similar so I post either way - please upvote" ones.

Why is this relevant? Because if a SharePoint Collective gets made on SO, that is the final nail in the coffin of SharePoint.SE. A big "know what? This site outlived its purpose - start farming again on SO" hand-wave.

But I suspect this is not just for SharePoint. Where would a Blender collective be built at? And a bitcoin one?

For years SO told us that smaller sites for a single product/tech were great, even if that dispersed your rep gain and made you struggle in low traffic zones. This new product now feels like a 180° turn in the opposite direction. Pull in the smaller communities to SO and give them "private" prestige ***while still on SO***.

I ask a rhetoric question...

*Is there any plan to let us/me migrate my work to SO if a SharePoint collective was really made or do you expect me to start from zero again?*

Comment: You should really be posting all SharePoint questions to SharePoint.SE, not here. We should at some point do a tag cleanup for SharePoint tags on SO and edit the tags to say 'go ask on SP.SE'... questions about programming for SharePoint sites might be OK here if they're applicable elsewhere (e.g. they're not unique to SharePoint)... and in those cases it shouldn't be necessary to mention SharePoint at all.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, you *should*. And that was what I did before getting burnt out from the experience. Dead site, no one votes, has 33 over 10k users, last moderation election was in 2017... all the problems I mentioned above. And tell me, if you where Microsoft, where would you go to open a Collective? on the well-known site or the second hand child no one cares about?

Comment: @TylerH to be clear, I agree with you on paper, but this feature seems to go in the opposite direction.

Comment: the critical part that is missing from this description is that interested parties *open a dialogue with the company* to create a Collective; it requires input and consent from both parties... *hopefully* the company will take steps to avoid fragmenting communities like this. Or maybe this is a good idea that version 2.0 of Collectives should get a roadmap started already and the first feature should be "cross-site Collectives" for this very reason.

Comment: meh, if a dead site goes away, that community coming back to SO would be a benefit to them, not a curse.

Comment: @TylerH I really wish that SO would develop better cross-site features for us normal folks before doing so for Collectives (eg: [Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with "crossover questions" between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989)), but we'll see what comes I suppose.

Comment: It's possible to move content between SE sites manually, so if SharePoint.SE closes you could at least save the valuable Q&A from there (with attribution) if it's ontopic here and not yet existing. But crossover questions or even crossover tags or cross-over searches would be very much welcome.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

## Push the search option more!

Companies will probably link to their collective pages as a type of help center. Other users have expressed a general concern that this might lead to even more duplicates. Right now the search option is even more hidden than on normal pages as it says `collective:"Google Cloud"` instead.

My recommendations:

- At the very least remove the `collective:"Google Cloud"` text and return it to just "Search..."
- Redesign the Collective page for users that are *not* logged in (similar to how stackoverflow.com looks different). For not logged in users highlight the search functionality and present yourself as a repository of knowledge rather than a forum.
- (Research whether there is a way to get users to search on Google Search as it's significantly better than StackOverflow search)

Comment: This should probably be posted as a separate feature request based on how the post asks for feedback.

Comment: Putting the current context into the search bar is consistent with the rest of the site (for better or worse). If you go to [a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), it will put that tag in the search bar. If you go to [someone's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266242), it will put their user ID in the search bar.

Comment: @BernhardBarker Neither of those are landing points within the site though. And in contrast to what you're saying this does not apply when you open a question which is the most likely 'entry point' aside of collectives (assuming collectives become popular).

Answer (score 4):

Why does the 'Badges' column show different counts than the profile page? If it's collective badges, there there is no information about such badges in the question.

[image]

Member's profile:

[image]

Comment: I'm going to guess it's how much they earned in the past 7 days. So izca got an additional 5 silver and 4 bronze badge, but no gold in the last week.

Comment: I would've guessed it was how many tag badges that user earned within the collective's domain of tags, but even after poking around a bit, I'm still not sure what it means.

Comment: @Scratte It shows same in all 3 date filters.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to be retroactive. I'd expect it to be the same until 7 days have passed. Then the "Last 7 days" will differ from the "Last 30 days". Not until 30 days have passed will the "Last 30 days" differ from "Last 12 months".

Answer (score 4):

So, effectively SO created a bunch of new features for the Q&A community, but isn't going to allow us to benefit from them without some 3rd party company paying to unlock it and us deciding to let that company live on our profiles/questions/answers.

Am I missing something?

Comment: "Am I missing something?" It's all for the best of the site and keeping the lights on and making money (or a subset of these). I'm personally not sure yet what I should think if I know that a user is for example a Google employee. I'm rather confused by it. I wish I could go back to a state of ignorance, which allowed me to judge content just by itself.

Comment: the "something" i might be missing is that no actual features other than articles were introduced. O.o just opportunities to display the collective name and the company's logo.

Comment: That's it, I think. And a bit of recognition of answers and people and further gameplay (you get a trophy if you answered lots of question within a certain time). And there are tags and collective tags now, which are a bit redundant unless it's actually possible to find a "Go" question that doesn't belong to the "Go" collective (an independent, underground Go question maybe).

Answer (score 4):

I really don't like how collectives/companies are ***choosing*** "recommended answers" and "recognized users" (biased), instead of the Q&A software ***recognizing*** them by score (proof of worthiness).

It makes sense to highlight good answers and people who are proficient in the technology the question is about.

But why should the collectives award those labels?

There *is* a system to highlight good answers - the score. If the collective thinks a particular answer is really great, they should upvote, like everybody else.

And there *is* a system to highlight experts - again the score, now in combination with the question's tags. Award any account a "recognized expert" label for all tags where their average score of best answer per question exceeds some number X. If we want to highlight people who are expected to give great answers, we should highlight those who have proven to do that in the past, not those who someone else said they allegedly will.

Comment: This answer is a little unclear in terms of how it refers to 'badges'. There is a first-class object on the site called a 'badge' and it is broken down into gold, silver, and bronze badges. You _appear_ to be talking about the graphical indication of a user being identified as a 'recognized expert' by a collective... while that graphic might look like a real-life badge, it's not a "badge" in terms of what Stack Overflow defines a badge to be... I'd recommend rephrasing the post to fix that issue.

Comment: Yeah, you understood it correctly; so what could be an unambiguous single-word term for that "recognized expert" thingy?

Comment: Maybe something like "the 'top user' label" or something?

Answer (score 3):

I've been noticing an increasing amount of "collective" results that are specific and often only applicable to a single product which my query does not even mention or remotely relates to.

The prevalence of these inapplicable "collective" results on any broader type of search makes for a very frustrating experience. My problems with `zsh` and its `readline` command idiosyncrasies is not going to be solved by Google Firebase or Twilio Sendgrid, and none of those "collective" results even contained any mention of the other words in that query.

This initiative is being presented as something of great benefit to your end-users whilst it's really just a revenue stream for StackOverflow and a marketing channel for BigCorp. This lack of honesty is very off-putting and wearisome.

Bottom-line: Sponsored content is getting in the way of finding relevant results, the possibility of corporate influence having been exerted over the content this website serves me has irreparably damaged its credibility, and I've lost all interest in community engagement now that my behaviour has been turned into a product.

Comment: "*I've been noticing an increasing amount of "collective" results that are specific and often only applicable to a single product which my query does not even mention or remotely relates to.*" Without sharing your query and a sample of your results it's impossible to read this as an anything other than an anecdote. The issue may be with your query or your understanding of the search results, not with the system.

Answer (score -3):

Good for recognizing our unspoken [Conflicts of Interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict_of_interest) (law), a resounding problem here.

If we were [academically-backed by/like say Harvard University](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359915/is-stackexchange-a-school-educator-should-se-be-qualified-as-and-graded-like-an) then we would have earlier had to profess that is how to solve part of the problem.

Answer (score -13):

Slowly I decoded, what does it mean:

> Collectives™ on Stack Overflow is a new set of spaces on Stack Overflow where content related to certain technical languages, products, or services can be grouped together. It’s a place for users who regularly interact with this content to collaborate. In turn, the organizations that help build or maintain this technology will share their expertise. Collectives are based on a set of specific tags relating to the technologies that an organization builds, supports, and has an authority over. They aggregate all content for those interested in this technology and give some special handling of content posted in those tags.

My opinion is not so bad, as the other answerers'. Imagine any technology which has a company behind it. Imagine the most infamous ones, like Apple or Microsoft. What if next year they invent yet another way to misuse and cheat their developers and users? Then they need to get a PR disaster. And community participation in the collective could serve very well that goal.

Another thing. Some technologies have notoroiusly crap documentation. I think we all know some technology, where the doc talks about everything - except what you want to know. We all know softwares where some trivial, very annoying bugs simply are not fixed and there is no reaction from the company.

Remember what happened on the MSE after the Monica firing. Now we could do the same to the m$ and the Apple!

Comment: Attention delete-voters: the "delete" button is for posts that are irrelevant, not for those with which you disagree, no matter how strongly. Delete votes are not super-downvotes. Granted this is...somewhat incoherent, but only somewhat. It's clear enough what is being said.

Answer (score -18):

> Collectives are based on a set of specific tags relating to the technologies that an organization builds, supports and has an authority over. They aggregate all content for those interested in this technology **and give some special handling of content posted in those tags**.

(emphasis mine).

Are there plans about giving any of these new "types" of users (*Admin*, *Recognized Member*, *Employee*) additional privileges within the collective's tag questions?

Ideally, so they can become more involved in regular curation activities (editing, closure, deletion, tag management, etc).

Generally, getting answers is not something that the community needs much help with (particularly in the high-volume tags that were picked as beta-launch communities). Conversely, curation is always in need of more hands.

Comment: I would expect an employee to have the knowledge/experience to answer questions related to their product. But to be given the ability to close/delete questions without actually earning the related privileges? No, thanks!!

Comment: @41686d6564 Not that I'm really looking forward to the idea. But trying to look for a possible use for this for the community. Again, getting answers from employees does not seem like a great feature (we already have that covered very much, thanks). So... not really sure what the communities bring to the table. Labels? If they would at least shoulder a bit of the curation work, it _could_ be of some use.

Comment: @yivi Articles seem to be a nice addition. Hope we can close questions against an article in the future. Allowing companies to control which questions may be asked on SO sounds terrible.

Comment: Admins, Recognized Members and Employees have an additional ability to add the Answer recommended by” label to any answer within the collective. We see the value that you’re mentioning but we did not want to interfere with the regular dynamics on Q&A. All privileges around curation remain the same and users will need to earn rep to get there.[1/2]

Comment: We’re strongly encouraging them to participate in any way that would improve the quality of current questions within their rep capabilities. Additional tools and resources have been created for these types of users to encourage their participation. If from our user research sessions (ongoing) we find that this is desired by our users, we will consider it. [2/2]

Comment: There may be insufficient curation, but giving those privileges to users who may not understand the rules and guidelines on the site, and may only be committed/attached to their organisation instead of Stack Overflow, may not be the best idea. Of course you also get enough reputation to unlock those privileges without knowing the rules, and that's far from a perfect system, but at least in that case you should've engaged with sufficient posts to at least have some idea of what's expected here.