# Your article is in another castle: should link-only articles be allowed?

Tags: discussion, support, external-links, collectives, articles

I noticed [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68912517/google-cloud-application-default-credentials-php) <sup>(now deleted)</sup> that was posted recently to the Google Cloud collective. It's essentially a link-only article:

[image: Screenshot of the deleted article]

Seeing that articles (at least technical ones) are similar to answers (they have been [compared to self-answered questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408943/8967612)) and since we have already established that link-only answers are not allowed (as per [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/348196)), **do you think articles should be the exception?**

In other words, is an article consisting of an external link and a couple of sentences to describe what the actual (i.e., external) article is about allowed?

**Update:** The article has since been deleted by a staff member. So, I'm guessing the answer is "it's not allowed". The following question still stands though:

If not, what's the proper action to take when encountering similar cases (considering that articles cannot be flagged or closed and they can only be deleted by <s>mods</s> community managers)?

#### Update #2

[Another article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68928239/6-days-left-in-google-cloud-communitys-learning-challenge) was dropped yesterday. This time, not only is it a link-only article, it's not even a technical one (it merely announces some kind of a learning challenge/game hosted by the company) and yet it's tagged as a "Knowledge article" <sup>(rather than, maybe, "Announcement"?)</sup>. Here's a screenshot in case it (hopefully) gets deleted:

[image: Screenshot of an article about a Learning Challenge hosted in the Google Cloud Community with a link to the challenge]

Can we please make sure that companies are on the same page with what articles should be used for? [We've been told](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408945/8967612) that guidance was provided to the companies but that doesn't seem to be taking into consideration with these off-topic articles.

Comment: It seems to have been removed already.

Comment: Yea, this is basically a link-only answer, and serves no function other than to draw traffic away from the page, on a wild goose chase...

Comment: to a personal blog at that

Comment: @JeanneDark Yeah, apparently it was deleted (by a mod/staff) while I was writing the question. The second question still stands though: "what can/should we do in such cases?"

Comment: Articles can not be deleted by moderators. Deleting an article requires a Community Manager.

Comment: Cesar M♦ [deleted it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68912517/timeline)

Comment: It's mildly annoying that we need staff intervention to delete articles. Can we please have moderation systems for when collective owners drop the ball? Including this, (at least?) two Google Cloud articles have made it to meta for being, well, bad or in violation of normal rules

Comment: @Zoe Yes, we need to, at least, be able to _flag_ articles _and_ moderators should have the ability to delete them. I didn't know that even mods cannot delete articles until now!!!

Comment: @Zoe I don't think you'll find anyone here who will disagree with you, but that kind of ask is certainly better as a standalone question/request rather than a comment...

Comment: @Zoe I agree it's frustrating that moderating articles requires the intervention of staff. I think the most important thing to implement would be to allow flagging articles. If articles could be flagged, then moderators could at least be informed there was an issue and could escalate such issues to CMs. Right now, there's no easy way to report issues with articles. I do find it frustrating that we wouldn't really be able to *resolve* such issues, but I understand (but not like) the company wanting to be an intermediary between moderation actions and paying customers.

Comment: @Zoe oh, but then the company wouldn't be able to market Collectives as a controlled space for companies :) Remember the times we were "assured" the companies received proper training in that the articles should follow the same quality standards we have on main? This is the second public slipup in a row, and it just shows what's it going to be once the feature goes out of beta by the end of the year. P.s. But yeah, thumbs up to the request - we *must* have an option to flag articles for serious problems. Will you make a feature request as TylerH implies above?

Comment: @OlegValter I'll get around to writing one later, but I've had a lot to do today and just haven't gotten around to it yet.

Comment: @OlegValter I think it's worth remembering that this article was posted by a SO community member who's not a cloud employee and who has more than 20k rep on SO, so I don't think it's really fair to blame the "company" here. I do also want to say that the fact that we've been deleting/dealing with problems when they show up is, hopefully, a sign that we're taking the commitment that they need to follow the same quality standards seriously?

Comment: @Zoe you can obviously still write the feature request if you want, but know that this (giving the community more ways to interact with articles and surface/deal with problems) is already something we're planning on doing. The current state is simply not good enough for larger scale use.

Comment: @CesarM - it is worth noting, though, that last time I checked, the articles are posted by "recognized members" only (apart from employees) that I would expect to lead by example given the controversial nature of the feature, not just handed the badge and the privilege and sent sail. I doubt the fact that it was posted not by an employee should have any bearing on the assessment of the situation in the current state of the feature.

Comment: On the bright side, number of posted articles so far, is so low, we can bring every single one to the meta ;)

Comment: @CesarM I think reputation is irrelevant when it comes to knowing the rules of the site. How many flags did they raise? Do they review? Or do they just collect reputation points? I'm pretty sure there are some users around with.. say 101 reputation points, that just may know the rules better.

Comment: @Scratte you're completely right and I agree, but that was not my point. All I tried to say is this wasn't a google cloud employee. Probably conveyed it badly.

Comment: @CesarM the problem is not the poor wording but an attempt to shift the blame. If these slip ups happen on a scale of about half a dozen articles, imagine what an <insert expletive here>-show this is going to be once the feature goes out of beta (not to mention that calling its current state "beta" is a bit of a stretch) next year. And this keeps coming despite significant concerns that gate-keeping is going to make things worse - if that's not what we should blame "the company" for, I do not know what should - bad or underthought decisions should be called out for what they are in my book.

Comment: @OlegValter See, it is a problem of wording because now I understand the disconnect and where I was unclear. By "company" I meant google cloud, not stack overflow. You interpreted it as Stack Overflow (which is a fair interpretation). I'm not saying SO carries no blame, I'm saying in this instance it wasn't the fault of google cloud - some comments were pointing as if they had submitted two bad articles, when this one wasn't from them.

Comment: The length of this article was very short (four lines), while articles are supposed to be longer than normal Q&A. The Google cloud members should know that in principle.

Comment: @Trilarion Well, the actual article (if you follow the link) is much longer. But _that_ is what should've been posted rather than an external link. Putting aside the fact the link-only articles are off-topic, this makes the "1 min read" label very misleading (when you need at least 30 minutes to read the actual article).

Comment: @CesarM well, of course - I do not have any brawl (heck, practically all my work is done for their products) with Google as a *customer* of a service. It would be really unwise to place the blame on them as controlled spaces is the value proposition of collectives. These quality concerns have been there from the start, and it just starts to show what it is going to be once the feature goes live unless something is not done *urgently*. Articles could go through peer review, for example (at least by other recognized members).

Answer (score 54):

No, this should not be allowed. They're bad for a lot of the same reasons that link-only answers are bad.

The specific article you mention is little more than an ad for another article. It itself contains no useful information whatsoever; if the link "goes dead," the article would be completely pointless.

This is another argument for collective owners [needing to have SO experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408900/should-administrators-of-collectives-be-encouraged-or-required-to-have-experienc).

A bigger issue here is that article quality standards aren't nearly as well-defined as question quality standards. There seems to be a consensus that they should meet similar standards for Q&A, but there's not really an agreed-upon standard for articles. Apart from this question, there are only two other posts with the articles tag that address quality standards:

[Is it acceptable to have 'thanks' in an article?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409281/is-it-acceptable-to-have-thanks-in-an-article)

[Are articles allowed to be off-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408912/are-articles-allowed-to-be-off-topic)

As far as I know, there's not a single, unified standard anywhere that actually spells this out - only questions asking about specific quality issues.

Answer (score 29):

Right now the community is not able to moderate articles, and we know this is a problem. As part of the evolution of the feature we do want to expand how you all (and mods) can interact with it, however, we don't know exactly how it'll look yet. It's something we'll have to work with yall on.

On launch, even CMs couldn't interact with it, we now can, so progress is being made :)

As for the question itself: yes, link-only answers (or articles) are not okay and we removed it once we saw it. For now, what you can do when you see these is continue to post on meta. Hopefully, we'll see before you need to do it (like this case), but if not, we should be accountable here and be able to act on it/explain if we're not acting on it.

Comment: Articles were always alien to the concept of public Q&A, though.  Given that this still feels like we're building the airplane as it's in flight, maybe a proper discussion about what an article means in the context of Q&A is more appropriate rather than tweaks.

Comment: @Makoto I agree. We've been discussing this internally and we'll have more to share soon - both on [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411010/what-are-the-quality-standards-for-articles) as well as more in the future.

Comment: Did the discussion include, "Do we even want articles in public Q&A?"  Because I really think it should.

Comment: @Makoto not at the moment, no. Not that I am aware, at least. Though I do see value for Articles in public Q&A and I think it's too early to say it's completely useless and/or doesn't add any value. I'd like to at least try to get it right, to a place that it can contribute to public Q&A, before declaring it worthless/should be removed.

Comment: This is why I think you should include that question in the discussion.  This was always an enterprise feature meant to serve a niche for enterprise Teams that only really had demonstrable value for those enterprise customers.  Now you want to bring it here without really talking about ***why*** you're even bothering.  Before you can get something like this right, you have to establish what "right" is, and the only people who can help you with that are the community.  Not just the cherry-picked customers, either - the ones who've been using this platform for *decades*.

Comment: @Makoto The platform hasn't been around for decades yet, FWIW, but if you mean all 12 years, that would not only exclude me but also you! Please reconsider how restrictive the group of people is that you just recommended Cesar consult :-)

Comment: "On launch, even CMs couldn't interact with it..." The articles part of collectives was launched clearly too early. It seems like there wasn't much internal testing (create real content and try to interact with it) been done before. And there also wasn't any example content available at the beginning. Consequently the feature has been largely ignored so far. Trying to improve it will be difficult, because the novelty effect is gone and interest might remain very low.

Comment: Thanks for the assurance and for considering providing curation tools. Please note that [another article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68928239/6-days-left-in-google-cloud-communitys-learning-challenge) was dropped a couple of hours after I posted this question. I've updated the question to refer to it to but I'm pinging you here because I can't flag the article.

Comment: @41686d6564 We've removed that one too, thanks. That one is a little baffling, but I'll need more context before I can say anything informed :)

Answer (score -2):

As a bystander I have seen nothing positive come from articles.

They're usually just shameless plugs and redirects for external content.

I think articles should be burninated as a whole.

Even the okay ones seem to be nothing more than a canonical answer.

I doubt that Google has even a sliver of interest in making SO their main knowledge base when they already have such an extensive and well-oiled KB. Unless you start attracting the "little guys" with sub-par infrastructure compared to what SO offers then this is likely dead in the water.