# Is it acceptable to have 'thanks' in an article?

Tags: discussion, collectives, articles

[This Stack Exchange Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) asks the question whether we should remove 'hi', 'thanks' and other salutations from posts.

The general view of the community has always been to remove greetings and salutations as unnecessary noise.

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68475140/faster-cloud-storage-transfers-using-the-gcloud-command-line) contains an acknowledgements line:

> Acknowledgements: Special thanks to the Google Cloud engineering team that made all this possible: Nick Hartunian, Tech Lead Dilip Pednekar, and Ross Rauber.

I'm unable to edit this out myself, as it's an article.

Comment: I don't follow. What you've quoted is an "acknowledgement", which is perfectly fine. It's giving credit, which is neither a greeting nor a salutation. You don't have to (and shouldn't) remove sentences from a post *just* because they contain the word "thanks". I assume the guidance for articles is the same in this regard.

Comment: It's not attribution for the content of the article, but for the software being presented. The reason we edit out 'hi' and 'thanks' is because it's extraneous content which doesn't add to the post. It's equally extraneous here.

Comment: As far as I can see, the promotion of a software product *is* the entire content of the article. If that article is on-topic, then I don't really see a problem with the acknowledgement. The article itself would be off-topic by the standards of the main site, but whether such articles should be allowed is a different issue I feel.

Comment: @cigien Isn't the promotion opportunity exactly what SE is trying to sell via Collectives?

Comment: This article is a just an ad coming from unexperienced in using SO people and should be removed. And I strongly disagree with position, which allow aknowledges. Shall I put aknowledge to my mom in each of my posts then? She did a great job once, I was born.

Comment: Hmm, smells like spam. Interestingly, a downvote doesn't seem to move the score below zero (and as a bonus you get to close a dialog you didn't ask for) and there's absolutely no way to close vote or even flag.

Comment: "I'm unable to edit this out myself, as it's an article." You can comment.

Comment: The strange thing about that article is actually "That’s why we’re excited to announce...". Maybe the content has been copied from somewhere else. In a typical Q&A on SO almost [nobody is ever excited](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22excited+to%22).

Comment: @Trilarion it has. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/new-gcloud-storage-enables-super-fast-data-transfers

Comment: I see Sinatr claiming "This article is a just an ad coming from unexperienced in using SO people and should be removed" - yeah? I don't pretend to be so sure of that, articles are not answers. And they are definitely outside of the scope of "the community", collectives are something outside of it all and beyond our influence. Stack Overflow Plus, if you will. So yeah, what the community thinks really isn't all that relevant for collectives specifically, what matters there is what the Googles and the Amazons among us think.

Comment: The more promotional articles become the less valuable and should they lose their reputation for containing lots of knowledge it might become difficult. I guess there is a thin line to thread for articles to become successful.

Comment: I had been confused about what the purpose of articles was. I see they are a convoluted way to post ads on the site and make them look like real SO content. That explains it.

Comment: @khelwood I think so too now. At least there is an ad part to it that I don't like.  If only it would have been explained better at the introduction. But still, the fun part is that we can vote on them.

Comment: @Trilarion I don't know, I feel like voting on an ad is telling them you read their ad, which is what they want. It would be better if they got no views or reactions at all and decided this wasn't worth pursuing. But I guess downvotes are as close as we can get to the illusion of countering the upvotes.

Answer (score 72):

I think you are incorrectly focusing on the words rather than what they mean.

The typical use of "thanks" is to thank (unspecified) people in advance for the help that the poster thinks/hopes they will provide. That is viewed as not necessary (noise) for reasons that have been aired [elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/11407695).

The use of "thanks" in *this article* is to acknowledge and give due credit to other people who have contributed to the article and/or the product that the article is talking about. That is not noise. Rather, it is akin to putting an acknowledgment or citation *in an answer*.

Comment: I would edit an acknowledgement like "Thanks to the Laravel team for producing X feature/product" out of an answer, but I wouldn't edit out an acknowledgement like "This answer is based on Y's answer to a similar question". I think the acknowledgements in the article are more like the former than the latter.

Comment: Well, I don't think you should do that.  A "Thanks to the Laravel team" note is a genuine acknowledgement of the people who worked on the product that the article is talking about.  It is not noise, and it is not gratuitous cross-promotion.

Comment: On the other hand ... if the article itself is off-topic, then it should be removed.  (I am making no judgement on the specific article as a whole.  Such a judgement is off-topic for >this< Q&A.)

Comment: I'm not sure what the acknowledgement is actually acknowledging. What is "all this" exactly?

Comment: @Trilarion - One could argue the merits of this specific example.  But I am trying to draw out a (possible) principle for deciding between noise and appropriate use of "thanks" and the like in an Article (or Answer).  I would leave the word-smithing of the acknowledgement to the people who are writing / curating that article.  (Put your peanuts away :-) )

Comment: @StephenCI agree and these are only the very first articles and one shouldn't put too much scrutiny on them or people will get scared away (which is not the intention), but then I also don't want Oscar speech long acknowledgements below every bit of information because it also dilutes the content. There is a balance somewhere and being specific and concentrate on the important influences is one way of achieving the balance. Just saying. It was just a comment.

Comment: Not entirely sure I agree with this.  I think a distinction should be drawn for acknowledgement for contributors to the *article* and acknowledgement for contributors to the *technology being described*. The former is not just OK but is required as per [referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).  But the latter isn't.  In this case the people being thanked didn't contribute to the article (unless they wrote some documentation that was quoted) so "thanks" in such a situation seems more promotional than referential, and so does seem noisy (or even spammy).

Answer (score 17):

Articles were never a public feature of the main site's Q&A, so realistically speaking, we have no way to say whether or not this use of articles is consistent with anything else on the site.

But the article reads like a blog post.  [Oh wait.](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/new-gcloud-storage-enables-super-fast-data-transfers)

I cannot comprehend the value of reposting something from a blog that people who are in the know on this technology would have found in the first place, but this is due to my limited exposure with the feature itself.

My sentiment:  we could probably dislike the fact that the article reads like a blog post, but that may be the reason why articles exist to begin with.

This doesn't sit all that well with me, but I get to be the grumpy old man shouting at kids on his lawn instead of bothering to turn on the sprinklers this time.

Comment: "I cannot comprehend the value" - [rep farming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408738/6296561). Two collectives in and it's already happening

Comment: @Zoe:  Unicorn points aren't *valuable*, though.

Comment: Not to those of us who have all (or virtually all) the privileges, but there's a long list of people who'd call it valuable without blinking

Comment: I found [the on switch for the sprinklers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHtPk.png). Works on my lawn.

Comment: @CodyGray:  I'm not sold that a downvote on an article means anything.  The very likely scenario is that after this beta trial run, and the feature is torn down, all of the votes would remain kinda like what they did with Documentation.

Answer (score 11):

The acknowledgement section would have smarter wording if it said:

> **Acknowledgements to** the Google Cloud engineering team that made all this possible: Nick Hartunian, Tech Lead Dilip Pednekar, and Ross Rauber.

or

> **Credit to** the Google Cloud engineering team that made all this possible: Nick Hartunian, Tech Lead Dilip Pednekar, and Ross Rauber.

One reason *thanks* is a problematic keyword is also because it results in False Positives (using [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer?tab=Votes) or [search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=)) for editors who are seeking to clean up posts.

So yes, even if there is a use case it will still cause extra work.

---

---

*thanks* - [3,429,775 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thanks)

*thanks to* - [178,878 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks+to%22)

**by comparison**

*acknowledgements to* - [51 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22acknowledgements+to%22)

*credit to* - [8,218 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22credit+to%22)

Comment: I tried to look at results of "aknowledgements to" and those results don't have such a word. SO search bug?

Comment: Soon we will see "credit to everyone that answers my post" and "credit in advance to everyone that answers my post" and the short version "credit in advance". Not to mention the lazy one: CIA.. ;)

Comment: @Scratte lol, perfect. But before that we'd have the pleasure of seeing the entire user base change a habit, and it would still distinguish the completely new user from those with some site experience.

Comment: Also breaks some regex I use for editing. Articles aren't targeted by that tool, but still. Definitely agree with the sentiment here

Comment: Completely disagree. Human should not adapt to software. Software should adapt to humans.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward Except thanks always has been widely discouraged on this site - and that's a case of humans needing to adapt to a set of rules, but who refuse to. Tools that use regex to do the heavy lifting of an edit, or use SQL to search cannot detect whether that sentence is something worth removing or not, because neither tools are capable of that type of detection.

Comment: @Zoe Could you link the "set of rules" in SO which forbids using thanks in the way described in this question? Neither are them discouraged, please link citation. Only thanks which are noise like *Please help, thanks* are discouraged or forbidden.

Comment: You're saying we should not only take care to follow SO's (sometimes crazy) rules on what we say and how we say it (e.g. we're required to be friendly to newcomers but not if it involves using friendly words of greeting); we're now expected to choose phraseology that makes it easier for the moderation army to enforce these rules? Spare a thought for those of us who just want to be helpful.

Comment: Since I asked for citation it is only fair that I apply the same to myself. Citation for my claims : [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) "**Do not use signature, taglines, greetings, thanks and other chit chat.** (...) Thanks and other statements of appreciation are unnecessary, and like other chit chat should not be included." . Those are the unnecessary thanks, the ones which are statements of appreciation. No mention of thanks as acknowledgements as being discouraged. Indeed the site **requires** acknowledgments/attribution.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward "Indeed the site requires acknowledgments/attribution." To be completely precise, the license requires attribution, but only if you reproduce the content elsewhere, not if you create content, then nothing is required.

Comment: @Trilarion [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) *You should be aware that all Public Content you contribute is available for public copy and redistribution, and all such Public Content must have appropriate attribution.* So, yes, the **site** requires attribution. Other entities may also require attribution but there is no lack of precision in the statement "Indeed the site requires acknowledgments/attribution."

Comment: @AnonymousCoward That's exactly what I meant with if you create the content, then nothing is required. Most of the Q&A on SO have no attribution/acknowledgement because none is required in these cases.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward Sourcing only applies if you've copied text from other people. OP is crediting the work people did to make the thing the article is talking about possible, not because they contributed to the article itself. That falls outside the requirement for referencing, meaning it's still noise and has no place in the post.

Comment: @Zoe "That falls outside the requirement for referencing, meaning it's still noise and has no place in the post." Non sequitur. Your comment also falls outside the requirement of referencing but of course it is not noise. Please quote the "set of rules" that humans need to adapt to.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it and a few others that you with 3k rep should be more than capable of finding on your own. If you're looking for a definition of noise, it's any bit of text that has no value to the post itself. That includes thanks, and thanks for work done to make something happen. Neither of those add value, nor is the latter a reference. Again, see the first link. That's how referencing works and I'm genuinely shocked if you're not aware of how they work and when they're used

Comment: Referencing copied content and not plagiarizing is academia 101

Comment: @Zoe Your link supports that not all thanks need to be removed. The question is about "Thanks in advance", "Thanks in advanced" and similar kind of thanks. Most upvoted answer states in bold **Adding "thank you" to a post that doesn't adhere to site's standards is false courtesy.** Which leaves the door open for thanks which adhere to the sites rules, as the one in this discussion, which is not "thanks in advanced".

Comment: Also in that answer *In case of the minuscule number of well-written posts, adding "thank you" is of course nothing wrong, but I still tend to remove it, explaining politely why, if needed.* So there is nothing wrong with well written thanks, that person still deletes them, but I wonder why if there is nothing wrong. Probably because there are so many and has not enough time to consider each individual one. Which is fine, manage your limited moderator time as you see fit. But don't delete a well written thanks if you are aware it is well written.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward "...why if there is nothing wrong." They dilute the content. A possible reader gains no insight from it and has to spent more time on it. It makes the whole thing less valuable.

Comment: @Trilarion If they dilute the content then, yes, there is something wrong with such thanks. Delete away. But we are talking about thanking the authors of a technology in an article about such technology. Is it not useful to know the authors of such technology in such article? Also, do you or Zoe claim that "all thanks are to be removed"? If so I can stop discussion and agreed to disagree. Otherwise, if you also think that "some thanks are worth being kept" then our disagreement is about whether the specific thanks in OP are useful or not.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward In general, I remove all thanks unless it really seems particularly needed (very seldom it does to me, for example not really in this case), but you know, everyone has a different curation style. I cannot exclude that others do not remove all thanks or even rollback my edits. Obviously meta is the place to reach some kind of consensus. To answer directly: It's not useful to know the names of the authors of such technology. Every day I use hundreds of such technologies and if I would apply the same standard and try to know every name, I would lose too much time.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward As a compromise we could for example talk about a dedicated acknowledgements sections (something that is preferably folded by default but can be unfolded). That way we would have the advantages of both camps.

Comment: @Anonymous Coward: The canonical is *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950)* (posted 11 days after the meta site opened back in 2009)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for the link. It reinforces my position since the top answer to such linked question is *I've always been against the greetings and salutations (along with other extraneous clutter)* . But here we are dealing with an acknowledgement. Not with greeting, salutation or extraneous clutter. Acknowledgements may not be required (unlike attribution which is required) but neither are them forbidden (unlike greetings and salutations which are). Since they are acceptable per (lack of) site rules, let's stop trying to control what people write.

Comment: That being said, if acknowledgements are undesired it is fine to add a new site rule about them if there is consensus. But let's not pretend that they are forbidden by current site rules about greetings and salutations.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward you could say that thanking someone who helped you in the comments isn't necessarily attribution because there aren't any clear attributions rules surrounding comments. It's not forbidden but it's also not required, and so you can consider that attribution a form of salutation in the current format where comments aren't considered maintainable or practically attributable. (The mods themselves have always said this is a murky region.) But in any case this post was meant as an observation for proficient copy-editors over what may be a preferable phrasing.

Comment: @bad_coder This Q&A is not about tanking someone who helped you in the comments.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward for an attribution you don't have to say *thanks* that is a form of salutation. An attribution only requires *"taken from here"*, or *"reference"*.