# What are the quality standards for articles?

Tags: discussion, articles

Currently, there are three Q&As regarding articles:

[Your article is in another castle: should link-only articles be allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411008/your-article-is-in-another-castle-should-this-be-allowed)

[Is it acceptable to have 'thanks' in an article?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409281/is-it-acceptable-to-have-thanks-in-an-article)

[Are articles allowed to be off-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408912/are-articles-allowed-to-be-off-topic)

There is not, however, a unified standard for article quality. Most of the discussion has seemed to be "reactive" in response to specific quality problems, and they tend to center around whether the same standards for questions and answers (e.g. no link-only articles, articles must be on-topic) apply to articles too.

Can we create an actual standard for this? (One possible idea I had would be to create answers with proposals for this, either on this Q&A or on another Q&A, so that the community can vote on them and we can reach a consensus).

Comment: nerver read one, but would a peer review notsuffice

Comment: @nbk A peer review really couldn't be a replacement for an agreed-upon standard, because otherwise reviewers wouldn't know whether to approve or not.

Comment: A peer review is a normal procedure in academic paper and proposals, so it could be a good thing for other experts like i am, to give my 2 cents to  artivcle. I don't know if voting is allowed,. so that could replace a peer review

Comment: @nbk comment gave me an interesting idea, what if an article is not viewable outside the collective unless it has x vote, that would mean at least the collective has agreed the article has some merit before it is released to the "masses". not sure if that just ends up meaning small collectives never would get enough steam to break out, but just a half baked idea.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After seeing how things have been going since launch, we agree that we need defined guidelines for Articles. We also agree that the community needs to be involved in defining and helping us craft those guidelines so that Articles can provide value for everyone.

We will be coming to Meta soon with ideas and opportunities for input and collaboration on building these guidelines. While it looks like you're already coming up with some great ones, we're not quite ready to begin it yet. We don't have a hard timeline, but will be sharing more information in the upcoming weeks as soon as we do. We're also looking to communicate why we believe Articles can add value to public Q&A and more around the research we've done on that subject.

Answer (score 23):

I will post some proposed rules here (separately from the question so that people can vote on it separately):

- Articles must back up their claims with facts and references
- Articles should contain sufficient context for the problem that they are intending to address. They should focus on a practical problem that programmers actually face.

  - Articles must fully address the problem they are intending to discuss. Readers should be able to get a clear understanding of how to solve their problem from reading the article.
  - Topics that would require extremely lengthy articles to address in full should ideally be split into multiple articles. If there is other context required, the articles should clearly indicate what context is needed.
- Articles may be about any of the following topics, provided that they are clearly related to the topic of the collective:

  - Algorithms
  - Tools or software libraries used primarily by programmers
  - Specific programming problems
- Articles cannot be about any of the following:

  - General computing
  - Network or server administration
  - Legal advice
  - Opinion-based topics
  - Hypothetical or speculative articles, rants, etc.
  - Anything not directly related to programming
  - Programming topics not directly related to the topic of the collective
- Articles must be more than just links. If they contain links, they must have sufficient context.
- The title must summarize the content
- Articles must be in the primary language of the target site that they accompany (currently English, since collectives "accompany" the main SO site; if there's ever a collective for another site, like the Russian SO site, it must be in the primary language of that site). Articles should use good grammar, spelling, and punctuation to the best of the writer's ability.
- Articles must follow the Code of Conduct - abusive or insulting language will not be tolerated.
- Articles may not engage in excessive or undisclosed self-promotion
- Articles should not be exact duplicates of existing Q&As or articles. (We need to decide whether we want "canonical articles" or "canonical Q&A" for commonly-asked questions).

We need to make a decision about product announcements, news, app store policies, etc.

Comment: The decision about "canonical articles" will depend greatly on whether we can close questions as duplicates of articles. Personally, I don't think we should, because there's (currently) no way of posting a better answer to an article, and (currently) no way for non-collective members of editing articles to make them better (to include an edge case, for example, allowing people to close more questions against it).

Comment: Product announcements, news, app store policies, are all off-topic on Stack Overflow. No need to "make a decision" :).

Comment: "The title must summarize the content." In principle that should go without saying, and many other things here too, but to write it down at least once is good, I think. I kind of agree with all, but still think that articles aren't integrated well with Q&A, even if they would follow all these rules. The question is still how to collaborate on articles, who can and can't write articles and how and when they should replace some Q&A or not?

Comment: I just checked what types of articles can be (from Teams though, not Collectives, but I believe they're the same): [1) Knowledge sharing, 2) Announcement, 3) How-to guide, 4) Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAp5m.png), if this helps in expanding/claryfing these proposed rules.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Where's the line between a "product announcement" and a "what's new in <library> <version>"?

Comment: I would take the "*Articles cannot be about opinion-based topics*" off the list. Such articles would still be very valuable and could offer insights that Q&A might not be able to do, as long as they reflect the mainstream opinion of the collective. An example might be "*Recommended coding conventions for working with XY*".

Comment: @Bergi *what's new in <library> <version>* **is** product announcement and shouldn't be allowed here. A separate article for each new feature documenting it in detail would, as long as it is kept up-to-date with new releases, be useful and align with the content created before collectives.

Comment: And I think *recommended coding conventions* is a terrible example. I don't think articles about code aesthetics should be allowed on StackOverflow.

Comment: @HereticMonkey One reason that many of those question types were banned is that we're not customer support for the company, and we often can't know the answer. If an article is written by someone who's verified to be affiliated with the company, though, that argument doesn't really apply. That being said, the fact that those questions work poorly on the main Q&A site doesn't necessarily mean that they would work equally poorly as Collectives article's.

Comment: @Bergi You bring up a good point. I guess that articles like that wouldn't necessarily suffer from the problem that Q&A has of tending to descend into pointless blathering.

Comment: Well, I was told that bringing Collectives on wasn't going to change our policies at all. Apparently, the employee who told us that misspoke.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Articles aren't Q&A, though. A lot of site rules don't apply the exact same way to articles that they do to Q&A, and some of them may not apply at all. For example, recommendation questions are banned because they tend to attract opinion-based answers and spam, but an article doesn't attract answers at all, so it's not clear if that standard still applies. As another example, how does the on-topic guide's rule about including a MRE apply to an article? The closest I could come up with for that is that they need to include enough context for the problem that they're addressing.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Another example is the point about opinion-based articles that Bergi mentioned. One of the [problems](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/) with opinion-based questions is that they can quickly descend into pointless blathering. However, that's obviously not the case with articles (since there are no answers), so it's a little less clear that opinion-based articles are harmful in the same way that opinion-based Q&A is. "Real articles have answers, not items or ideas or opinions" doesn't make sense, given that articles don't have answers at all.

Comment: "Articles aren't Q&A" And that right there explains the problem I have with them. This site is a Q&A site. We've always prided ourselves on "just Q&A; no jibber jabber, no frou frou, just questions and answers". Now, it's "just Q&A... and Articles". Soon it will be "just Q&A... and Articles... and blogs... and whatever else we can sell". And it won't really cost the company much, because the burden will always lie on unpaid curators and moderators to identify the bad actors. We had a set of standards that we were more or less comfortable with. Now we have to do it all over again.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree - it is very important that we set clear quality standards for articles before things get too out of hand. I don't agree that the standards are necessarily exactly the same as they are with the main Q&A site, though. If anything, SE has an incentive to participate in that because I suspect that people would use the feature more if there was clear guidance on how to do so (and the feature would be much more likely to benefit future readers). They can't make money on the feature if no one writes (or reads) articles.