# Intel collective owns [x86] and [x86-64]

Tags: discussion, tags, collectives

It is odd that [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86) is now part of the [Intel Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel?tab=tags), even though some Q&A in this tag [specifically mention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69814823/2945027)/[discuss](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65049724/2945027) AMD. Even more funny for [x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86-64) that was actually invented by AMD.

Is there a specific reason for this? Can we remove those tags from the collective?

---

Reviewed all Intel Collective tags:

- [jasmin-x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmin-x86) is non-Intel x86 implementation, as @Bergi pointed out
- [rdtsc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdtsc) is an x86 instruction, so the same issue as with [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86)
- [i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i386) has a lot of Q&A not related to Intel, but it is the result of misuse: wiki states clearly that it is Intel product

Comment: I wonder what would have happened had StackOverflow decided to go with `[amd64]` (currently synonym of `[x86-64]`) :P

Comment: Collectives are just a group of tags related to a subject. The fact that the tag is relevant to Intel doesn't mean it can't be relevant elsewhere, a tag can be associated with multiple collectives, we just need to wait for AMD to make theirs.

Comment: Collectives are just sponsorships

Comment: Just another example of why collectives need to go away.

Comment: Earlier I asked if collectives can have [tags in common](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408763/1536976) and jd-stack answered at that time that it's possible. So anything goes. If AMD becomes a collective they could probably have these tags too.

Comment: Also [[tag:jasmin-x86]] appears to be a non-intel x86 implementation, I have no idea how that got into the collective.

Comment: @Trilarion - I wonder if Intel were aware of that ahead of agreeing their sponsorship (and if that still holds true)

Comment: @Bergi My guess: $$$$$

Comment: @Alejandro I doubt Intel would pay a cent to put their label on the two (sic!) questions about a hobby emulator used in education.

Comment: "Can we remove those tags from the collective?" Yes in the sense of I wouldn't mind, but also no in the sense of there is no technical way for us to do that.

Comment: This looks very inconsistent. Neither [tag:x86-64] nor [tag:arm] were designed by Intel. Both x86-64 and ARM CPUs are or were being built by Intel. But only one of the two tags is part of the collective. That makes no sense. Either both of them should be or neither of them should. I cannot think of a coherent set of objective criteria that would differentiate between the two.

Comment: Also, I just realized that the tag synonyms for [tag:x86-64] and [tag:amd64] seem to be the wrong way round. The name of the architecture is AMD64, x86-64 was used in some early documents before AMD had settled on a name, and thus ended up being used in some early ports (e.g. GNU autoconf and GCC, I believe), but it is not the name the architecture is known by.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The architecture is absolutely known by "x86-64". It is used all over the place. Just see [this Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=x86-64&btnG=) search result, for example. I rarely ever hear someone say AMD64 but hear people say x86-64 (or even just x86) all the time. It may be technically incorrect, but it is used that way.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Technically, Intel's CPUs don't implement "AMD64", they implement a 99%-compatible architecture called "Intel 64", so "x86-64" is sometimes used as a neutral name covering all implementations. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Industry_naming_conventions) (which itself has "x86-64" as the primary name) gives examples using both terms, as well as the slightly confusing "x64".

Comment: @IMSoP this whole discussion of AMD vs Intel 64 reminds me that at one point "Intel 64" meant the ill fated IA-64 (Itanium) that thankfully did not stick around.

Comment: @IMSoP: Indeed. [What EXACTLY is the difference between intel's and amd's ISA, if any?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38516823)  Related: [The most correct way to refer to 32-bit and 64-bit versions of programs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53364320) my answer catalogues most of the official and actually-used names.

Comment: @jrh: Are you sure you're not thinking of IA-64?  That is and always has been Itanium.  Or did Intel ever officially use "Intel 64" to talk about Itanium?  They officially use "Intel 64" and "IA-32e" to name their implementation of x86-64 in their current manuals, but it's remotely possible they could have changed the meaning of "Intel 64" at some point.

Comment: It's a bit of trivia now, but Intel did use the "Intel 64 Fund" to refer to their effort to fund development of products for IA-64.  I swear I saw some mention of it in the press as "Intel 64", but a quick search suggests if it did happen, it was rare.

Comment: @PeterCordes unfortunately I don't remember exactly where, but I think I remember seeing "Intel 64" on some Linux (or freebsd?) distro downloads.

Comment: @jrh: Ah, I see.  That could easily be the result of some Linux devs choosing that name, though, even if Intel never officially used it.  Linux / GNU has a history of making up names like "i686" (x86 with PPro extension like cmov) that Intel has never used.  Anyway, yeah, just historical trivia at this point.  And fortunately, as I said in my answer here, whether [x86] and [x86-64] should be part of the Intel collective or not doesn't hinge on naming, semantics, or who architected the ISA in the first place.

Comment: Communicating with SO the company is like speaking to a wall. So maybe the way to go is to scare away these companies from using Collectives by posting a lot of questions shaming their products? I can _easily_ come up with some 100+ questions regarding why the icc compiler is non-compliant or does a poor job optimizing code for the Intel x86 target. In fact I'm very tempted to start a crusade against this compiler now. Pretty much any Godbolt adventure I'm having goes like "aha gcc did that, hmm clang did that... hmm icc ran off into the woods", so this is like penalty shots without a goalie.

Comment: Btw the [tag:intel] tag is a perfect burnination candidate that needs to be removed, like all other company name tags. It is ambiguous and fills no purpose - see the burnination of Apple, Microsoft etc tags.

Comment: @Lundin, you are not using `icc` compiler except seeing it in Compiler Explorer, are you? I think those who need to use `icc` use it regardless of issues, like I know areas where MSVC is sub-optimal or non-conforming, but I'm not using other compilers much anyway. I mean I think the crusade against `icc` is useless, we all already know where we are with the compilers.

Comment: My concern is that curation of Intel on `[x86]` may be harmful for the possibility for other vendors discussion. If the concern comes true I'd rather [follow perf folks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412812/intel-collective-owns-x86-and-x86-64?noredirect=1#comment877810_412844) than try to run a war. I'm rather asking why `[x86]` is in Intel Collective, isn't this an oversight, and if it isn't, where are we going further with this.

Comment: If this sticks, then to be consistent, they should also own [tag:x86-16], which incidentally is an ISA that they *did* actually design. Not that Intel engineers are probably that interested in the questions from people writing retro DOS code or real-mode boot sectors, but hey, they gotta take the bad with the good. For that matter, they should take [tag:intel-8080] and [tag:8051] too.  And [tag:itanium].

Comment: (Oh, they do have [tag:intel-8080].  But the others stand.)

Comment: @NateEldredge, and they took [intel-tsx], which also isn't a brilliant success now. Think it was mostly as simple as taking anything that has "Intel" in it.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: Yeah, I thought [tag:intel-syntax] was kind of funny...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86) and [x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86-64) (and [i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i386)) tags should be removed from the Intel collective, but not because of who designed the ISA, or that other x86-64 vendors exist.

TL;DR: **The real problem is that Intel is a big company that does lots of quite different things, and has software products that are of little interest to people that know about details of their CPU hardware (and vice versa).**

---

The fact that AMD (and VIA) also make x86-64 CPUs is not really critical, nor is the fact that AMD architects designed the 64-bit extensions to x86. (See also: [The most correct way to refer to 32-bit and 64-bit versions of programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53364320/the-most-correct-way-to-refer-to-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-programs.)) We do already have the ability to tag [amd-processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amd-processor) [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86) for performance questions specific to AMD microarchitectures (or their SIMD extensions like XOP).  As discussed in comments, it's fine if a collective includes a tag that isn't *exclusively* relevant to that collective.  Besides, most people using Intel tools to develop software don't want to stop it from running on AMD CPUs, and many actively do want it to be portable.

What's more relevant is that this collective currently includes [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86) and [x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86-64), which are most often tagged with [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly), **but the collective describes itself as being about Intel software and tools**.  e.g. their compilers, [icc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/icc) and [intel-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-fortran), libraries like [openvino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openvino) and [intel-mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-mkl), and even Intel builds/distributions of existing software like [intel-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-python) and [intel-tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-tensorflow)<sup>1</sup>.

The current description for the [Intel Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel) is:

> A space for developers to collaborate on Intel software tools, libraries, and resources. Share knowledge and connect with Intel product experts. Find the information you need to drive innovation and simplify development from edge to cloud with Intel.

If "resources" include Intel's optimization manual, and "Intel Product Experts" include [micro-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/micro-optimization) experts who know about Intel microarchitectures, then, yes, there's some overlap between that description and questions like [Deoptimizing a program for the pipeline in Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361145/deoptimizing-a-program-for-the-pipeline-in-intel-sandybridge-family-cpus) and [Why does my Intel Skylake / Kaby Lake CPU incur a mysterious factor 3 slowdown in a simple hash table implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69664733/why-does-my-intel-skylake-kaby-lake-cpu-incur-a-mysterious-factor-3-slowdown-i/69685404#69685404) (Pipeline nukes because of the mechanism Intel CPUs use to provide TLB coherency, going beyond the on-paper specs).

But, if so, that's too broad.  It makes little sense to lump that together with software stuff like [openvino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openvino) and [realsense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/realsense) (computer-vision libraries and hardware) and [intel-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-python)  (https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel?tab=tags).

Especially since many [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86) questions are actually about debugging and writing assembly programs, i.e. correctness problems and system call / library ABIs, and assembler syntax, not really relevant to performance or anything other than assembly-language hobbyists / beginners learning their way around.  And about tools like assemblers, compilers, and disassemblers.  So fully not relevant to people using Intel's performance libraries.

Assembly language / machine-code details are almost never relevant to higher-level stuff, so including them in the same collective as computer-vision, quicksync video tools, and so on, makes no sense.  (So that definition of "resources" shouldn't include Intel's ISA manuals, either.  That's basically its own thing, already well-covered by [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86).  And for hobby OS kernels, tags like [osdev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osdev) and [bootloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootloader) combined with [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86) or [x86-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86-16).)

*If* the collective wanted to include stuff that low-level, it should include [sse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sse), [avx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avx), and especially [avx-512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avx-512), since Intel is currently the only vendor selling CPUs with AVX-512 SIMD support.  (But I don't think it should.)  And Intel has an [intrinsics guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html), which is a pretty important "resource" for people writing code using them.

---

#### We should narrow the scope of the collective to match what was probably intended

*Just* Intel software / tools, not hardware (although that does still lump together computer-vision stuff with [intel-fpga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-fpga), and Intel profiling tools like [intel-vtune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-vtune)).  I guess Collectives are supposed to be broader than tags—that's the whole point—but it seems too disparate.

There are some gray-area tags like [intel-pmu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-pmu) which are clearly Intel-specific, but are generally about low-level details, even moreso than VTune.

The Collective is also missing [sgx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sgx) (Software Guard Extensions) which is an Intel technology for running code in a protected "enclave", with some special toolchain support for building code to run in, and other code to communicate with it.  That might actually be appropriate, especially if we're going to keep super-low-level stuff like [intel-tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-tsx) (transactional memory) as part of the Intel Collective.

The fact that I'm currently at the top of the Intel Collective leaderboard since I joined it yesterday is basically a joke.  I know of the existence of many of their libraries and things, but I've never used the TBB or MKL libraries, let alone their computer-vision stuff.  If the leaderboard is dominated by people answering assembly / cpu-architecture / performance questions, it seems to make a mockery of what the whole thing was supposed to be about.  (Especially assembly homework-debugging questions, although those don't get a lot of upvotes since they usually have near zero future value because the reason assembly beginners are having problems is that they don't know how to put pieces together in the first place, and thus can't break their problem down to a [mcve].)

**Footnote 1**: I don't know how many *programming* questions there can be about tags like  [intel-tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-tensorflow) or python; unless they extend the language / API with new functions. Questions are probably just about installing them, or get tagged because that's the version they happened to be using...  But the existence of tags like that is off-topic for this meta Q&A.

---

#### Compared to other Collectives like Go

Unlike, for example, the Go Collective, where everything is in one programming language that all members of the Collective at least have in common, the current set of tags in the Intel Collective can easily include questions that have no relevance or interest to people interested in other questions in tags that are part of the same Collective.

Fortunately, the "Intel Collective" is just extra visual noise in the tag field, and at the top right of question pages.  It doesn't actually result in showing you questions you don't want to see if you don't visit [the Collective page](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel).  Therefore, its existence doesn't make anything substantially worse, and in that sense it doesn't matter what tags it includes.

If its existence can save us from people tagging [intel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel) on questions about things that already have more-specific tags like [intel-fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-fortran) or [intel-tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-tensorflow), that's great.  (In my opinion, the [intel] tag should be used for things like CPU microarchitecture questions that are about Intel CPUs specifically, e.g. with [cpu-architecture] and [x86].  Definitely not where another tag already has *intel* in the name)

Comment: *"…most people using Intel tools to develop software don't want to stop it from running on AMD CPUs…"* I see what you did there. :-)

Comment: I agree with your point that Intel Collective tag set is too broad, and current intention doesn't match `[x86]` tag. Probably it is more important that my initial  concern. But to me, the ownership concern, which you stated as _"don't want to stop it from running on AMD"_, still holds. I don't want that `[x86]` acquisition by Intel stopped from discussing AMD. Like imagine that an answer uses `pdep` and contains the usual Zen 1/2 warning, and then this Zen 1/2 part is removed as off-topic.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: If I ever saw an edit like that, I'd roll it back.  And raise a mod flag if the edit message was really something like "off topic for Intel x86".  Collectives aren't more important than tags and don't change the meaning of tags, they're just a way to group existing tags together.  (And if that ever changes in a bad way, I and probably other x86 performance folks would leave SO if SO policy became to remove AMD info from [x86] answers.  I really can't see that happening, that's just so obviously terrible that nobody sane would ever go along with it, regardless of collectives.)

Comment: @PeterCordes "I really can't see that happening, that's just so obviously terrible that nobody sane would ever go along with it, regardless of collectives" - you've obviously never worked for a company that loves money, then...

Comment: @IanKemp: SO has pulled a lot of bullshit, but I think even they would realize that directly selling companies the ability to have people edit random existing answers to slant in their direction would be *way* past anything they've ever tried to push on the community in the past, to the point where the geese that lay golden eggs would leave.  Maybe you're picturing this as the tail end of a very long slippery slope which you see SO going down, but I still say implausible, or lost cause in that case and not worth worrying about for the purpose of this meta Q&A: we'd all be gone.

Comment: @PeterCordes You don't seem to understand that having us "golden geese" leave **is the intention of SE Inc.** Because we aren't golden to them, we're annoying rabble who question their questionable decisions and hold them accountable. What we *aren't* are the things that *do* make them money: new users and corporate sponsorships (which is what Collectives are). The most important thing about SO to SE Inc. today is showing constant "growth" (via new user signups) and milking the Stack Overflow brand name for all it's worth - *not* the quality of the site's content.

Comment: @PeterCordes Essentially, the slippery slope is just going to keep getting more and more slippery until SO is a revolving door of help vampires who create an account to post 1 gimme-teh-codez question, and a new account every time they need another "question" answered; and rep hunters who exist to do nothing but answer those "questions" because imaginary internet points are more important to them than personal integrity. That is the ultimate end-stage goal for SE Inc., to dumb the site down to a point where it is literally nothing but the stupid and the useless yelling at each other.

Comment: @IanKemp: I don't think SO management is dumb enough to not realize that without people to write good answers, it won't be an attractive site to ask questions on in the first place.  Regardless, whether SO eventually destroys itself or not isn't relevant to this meta question; if things get as bad as Alex is worried about ([x86] answers being edited to remove mention of AMD considerations), it won't matter because we'll already have left, and copied the useful CC-BY-SA content to somewhere else.

Answer (score 5):

Nick summed this up beautifully in their comment [on the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412812/intel-collective-owns-x86-and-x86-64/412854#comment877433_412812). A collective does not “own” a tag; they have a significant association with the tag (legally, and technically). They fit our criteria for what we think justifies association. This does not exclude other collectives from using the tag. Other brands, such as AMD, that create a collective, would be able to have equal association.

This shouldn’t discourage any discussions around the tag that don’t directly include AMD or any other chips that utilize the architecture. Bergi also brought up a good point which is the [jasmin-x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmin-x86) tag doesn’t fit into this collective and we have removed it.

Comment: This does address my initial concern that arise when I first noticed this association; however, now I also join Peter's answer, do you have something to address it?

Comment: Thanks for handling the [[tag:jasmin-x86]] issue!