# Does earning reputation from a contribution to Collectives affect the global Stack Overflow reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, collectives

While exploring [the Beta release of Collectives](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow), I saw that Articles can be created there, and that such articles can be voted on. Presumably, votes on articles will result in reputation changes, just like votes on questions and answers on the main site.

Does the reputation that one nets from votes on articles on Collectives get added to their global Stack Overflow reputation? Or does Collectives use a different reputation system?

Comment: i hope, as only the admin can recognize peolple as "recognized" this would be an unfair advantage.

Comment: There is no reputation for Collectives. It's all the same reputation.

Comment: But if only recognized users (which can be approved only by admins) can write articles, that means that only them can gain reputation, which sounds a little unfair, right?

Comment: Normal answers also count towards it, it's not only articles. But yeah, this restriction's been discussed - it's exploitable

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic You can still earn reputation through other avenues across the site (questions, answers, edits), why would not being able to write articles be unfair from a rep. standpoint?

Answer (score 6):

Collectives does *not* maintain its own, separate reputation system.

> "...we settled on handling Article rep in just the same way as Q&A rep." from [The user research behind Collectives™ on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408602/the-user-research-behind-collectives-on-stack-overflow)

That means that any reputation that a user earns from contributing to a Collective (e.g., from upvotes to an Article) will be added to their global Stack Overflow reputation, just as any reputation that they earn from votes on questions and answers.