# How has activity, participation and quality developed in the collectives tag sets since their introduction?

Tags: discussion, statistics, quality-improvement, collectives

Collectives were presented ([Beta release of Collectives](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow) and [The user research behind collectives](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408602/the-user-research-behind-collectives-on-stack-overflow/408661#408661)) as a way to increase participation, for example by reducing barriers to entry or by forming communities or by calculating and displaying leaderboards. And the number of members in the respective collectives (4-5k) looks impressive.

Is there already such an effect visible? Has the activity, participation or quality of recently generated content significantly improved in the tag sets defining the two existing collectives?

Quantity of created content could have improved or quality or both or maybe no change is visible yet.

It may depend on how quality of content or activity is measured. Some possibilities would be:

- number of (positively scoring) questions asked
- number of answers given (and upvoted)
- fraction of questions answered
- number of answers per question
- number of unique answerers
- number of votes given

See for example [How is question quality measured in A/B tests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests) for a possible definition of question quality.

To see if a change is significant one could take one month after the introduction and compare to a couple of months before possibly with a seasonal adjustment.

What makes gathering the statistics a bit difficult is that the tag sets are quite large and I'm not sure how to efficiently search within them.

Comment: I think with some SEDE quieres one should be able to come up with some numbers. Currently I do not have time to try myself on it.

Comment: Unless the company provides those numbers, we'd have to wait at least another 30 days to make sure that all questions asked in that timeframe had time to be roombad.

Comment: looks like not enough people downvote on collectives tag

Comment: @BDL You're right, it's better to wait 30 days more, otherwise statistics will be distorted.

Comment: @nbk Now or before? You probably mean that fewer downvotes not necessarily mean higher quality.

Comment: no i doubt you will find any difference, eitehr in the question or answer independent of collectives. It will not influence any of the quality. Company members answer often question of their product, only some like oracle doesn't do that, but i thing they take a look here.

Comment: I'm interested in _more important_ curation metrics: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408770/2943403

Comment: Isn't it a bit too early to call for an evaluation.

Comment: @4386427 Yes, we need to wait at least 30 days more to grow out of the roomba deletion period, but otherwise I think that period should be enough to get statistical certainty and be able to reliable detect even small changes should they have happened. If the positive effects need longer to manifest themselves, we could easily redo the analysis later on.

Comment: @mickmackusa Feel free to gather and display important curation statistics. Curation is part of the activity, participation and quality.

Comment: eh, simply looking at the one month after introduction would give you participation during the launch period, which is useful information, but isn't necessarily a good measure of how it will work when the spotlight isn't aimed at it.

Comment: @KevinB Sure, there might be a novelty effect, that wears off over time or it could be a slow build up effect that is not yet visible. If more times become available, it's not a big problem to redo the analysis to get a more complete picture.