# Link to Collective in post revisions is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, revision-history, broken-link, collectives

I noticed the new "Answer Recommended by" in an answer:

[image: Answer recommended by in a post]

The link to Google Cloud collective works fine in the post.

Then I went to the [post revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35107250/revisions), and in there the link is broken, pointing to https://stackoverflow.com/users/groups/-1002 which returns Page Not Found error.

[image: Link broken in revisions]

Can the link in the revisions please be fixed?

Comment: Not only does it return a "Page Not Found" error, but then (at least for me) it weirdly redirects to the user profile of a specific account: the *user* with the ID 1002. That seems like a completely separate bug mixed in.

Comment: Ah, bugception. Be sure not to go 3 levels deep, or you might lose a dev

Comment: At least that should help to reduce the number of future bugs, right, @ErikA? ;-)

Comment: @Cody lol that's a nice one!

Comment: @Cody Thanks for pointing this out, fix coming soon.

Comment: @Carog you mean only fixing the mod redirection? Or also fixing the bug reported in the question? Thanks!

Comment: Oops! Typing too fast, yes a fix is coming for the bug reported.

Comment: I would add the 'status-planned' tag but didn't want to delete one of the other tags.

Comment: Presumably this should have the [status-planned] tag, instead of the [status-review] tag that was edited in...?

Answer (score 8):

**Update Nov 25th 2021**
This bug has been fixed

Thanks for pointing this out, the bug has been reported and prioritized.