# What is the new badge UI on the Profile page?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page

Observe, from my [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7742131/caird-coinheringaahing?tab=profile):

[image]

This appears when you navigate to the Profile of any user on Stack Overflow. Every other site in the network (including MSO) shows the older UI (again from my profile, this time on MSO):

[image]

Why was this change made? Is it going to be applied to Meta Stack Overflow as well? What about other sites on the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: Looks to be on MSO now, too.

Comment: @CodyGray Looks the same as always for me. Caching perhaps?

Comment: Oh wow. Now I'm not seeing it on Meta, either. Definitely caching, or a roll-out in progress. Either that or I'm going crazy.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com? :þ

Comment: Hope it's a roll-out in progress, because that looks guuuud.  Especially with Dark Mode.

Comment: similar MSE post [When will the new Stack Overflow badge design come to other sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366800/571958)

Comment: I like it, but  wish I saw it on meta as well. It seems to be a caching problem on the other sites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was a part of the Collectives launch earlier today. We added a "badge" (sorry, no better term here) to the profiles if a user was a part of a Collective. In order for this to fit better visually, design felt that something else on the page should be modernized as well. Based on research, we also decided to move badges up within the profile as well.

Comment: So, does this updated badges/tags UI in the profile page roll out to all other sites for consistency? Or will it remain SO-only because only SO has Collectives?

Comment: What is a Collective(s)?

Comment: @Luuklag https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @CodyGray the Public Platform team will get this scheduled for an upcoming sprint

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't look like it's using the real estate on the profile page in a way that's interesting. The big images do not convey any information at all. It may look fancy, but it just forces me to scroll more to get the information that I'm interested in. Badges are the least interesting part of a user's profile.

Comment: They look much, much better than the old ones.

Comment: Re *"...to the profiles if a user was a part of a Collective"*: I must have been absorbed into a Collective, then...

Comment: *["Your Collectives"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/my-collectives/63550)* appears empty and says *"We couldn’t find any collectives. Have you joined a collective yet?"*

Comment: @PeterMortensen When I go to that link on your profile, I can see the "Other collective invitations" toggle and turn it off :O

Comment: it is  terrible decision, and terrible design. I don't care what badges a user has. why would I? I sometimes check what tags they participate in the most, and this new thing  totally gets in the way. just terrible. do remove it ASAP.

Answer (score 4):

[This is now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366832/798831) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) network-wide.  Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: I had hoped the roll-out would have been to put it back to the bottom of the page. But no.. :'(

Answer (score 3):

Here is a rough (pre-coffee) first pass from this morning at reverting the styles for anyone who wants that in their user script. It's not pretty, but it works. If I get some free time or people bug me I may clean it up or replace it with a JS version, which I'm sure would be much cleaner. As usual add it in a user style add-on to sites on the domain of `stackoverflow.com` or `meta.stackoverflow.com`.

One arguably more important change made in combination with this is the reordering of badges to be above tags and posts... this is a mistake, in my opinion, because badges another user has earned are the least important of the three, and should be at the bottom of the page.

This new order means we have to scroll past the badge section space to get to a user's more relevant content, even if the user hasn't earned any badges (or only a few 'beginner' badges)...

```css
body.user-page #badges svg {
    display: none;
}

body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell > .grid > .grid--cell:not(.mb12):last-child ul > li > div a, body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell > .grid > .grid--cell:not(.mb12):last-child ul > li > div > div {
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid > .grid--cell.fl1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid > .grid--cell.fl1 > div {
    text-align: center;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid > .grid--cell.fl1 > div:first-child {
    order: 2;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid > .grid--cell.fl1 > div:last-child {
    order: 1;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell:first-child > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid {
    border: 1px solid #f1b600;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fff4d1;
    color: #3c4146 !important;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell:first-child > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid > .grid--cell.fl1 > .fs-caption {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell:first-child > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid > .grid--cell.fl1 > .fs-caption::after {
    content: "GOLD";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #6a737c;
    font-size: 11px;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell:first-child > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid > .grid--cell.fl1 > .fw-bold {
    color: #3c4146 !important;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell:nth-child(2) > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid {
    border: 1px solid #9a9c9f;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    color: #3c4146 !important;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell:nth-child(2) > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid > .grid--cell.fl1 > .fs-caption {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell:nth-child(2) > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid > .grid--cell.fl1 > .fs-caption::after {
    content: "SILVER";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #6a737c;
    font-size: 11px;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell:nth-child(2) > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid > .grid--cell.fl1 > .fw-bold {
    color: #3c4146 !important;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell:last-child > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid {
    border: 1px solid #ab825f;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #f2e9e1;
    color: #3c4146 !important;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell:last-child > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid > .grid--cell.fl1 > .fs-caption {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell:last-child > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid > .grid--cell.fl1 > .fs-caption::after {
    content: "BRONZE";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #6a737c;
    font-size: 11px;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
}
body.user-page #badges > .grid > .grid--cell:last-child > .grid > .grid--cell.mb12 > .grid > .grid--cell.fl1 > .fw-bold {
    color: #3c4146 !important;
}

body.user-page #user-card + div > div.grid--cell.fl1:nth-child(2) {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#top-tags {
    order: 1;
}
#top-posts {
    order: 2;
}
#badges {
    order: 3;
}
```

Here's what it'll look like back at the bottom of the profile page:

[image]

I've noticed extra-long badge titles will overflow the badge 'background'... a consequence of adding flex properties, borders to things that previously didn't have borders, and restricting the width of the column. I'll work on that later, if I have time.

Comment: It's nice that you've done the CSS work. However, your point about the vertical position of the badges on that page is something that's worth a complete feature request question on its own, *not* just stuck as a brief side mention in what is primarily sharing the CSS work you've done.

Comment: @Makyen I agree, but I think given all the changes going on today it is something that should wait a few days or maybe even weeks, otherwise it will just get lost.

Comment: Given that they've said they're actively working on this area *now* to bring it to all SE sites, I disagree that it's a good idea to delay.

Comment: @Makyen By all means feel free to take the issue and run w/ it with your own FR; I am a bit busy currently :-)

Comment: Yeah, I know that feeling.

Comment: Are you aware that "grid" and "grid--cell" is being deprecated?

Comment: @Scratte No, since I'm not part of the Stack Overflow developer team I don't know what changes they plan to make to their code base.

Comment: I think one doesn't need to be part of the developer team for this. It can be seen [On Stack Design](https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/flex/) and on [StackExchange/Stacks on GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/releases/tag/v0.66.0)

Comment: @Scratte Which are places not really visited except by the developers...

Comment: I visit those places because I make user scripts and custom CSS changes. But by your response, I reckon you'd prefer to not be informed.

Comment: @Scratte No, I'd rather they just not make certain changes, honestly. Barring that, I am not interested in the changes to be *pro*active, e.g. anticipating them. Currently I'm still content with *re*acting to bad changes. It is what I've grown used to.