# Who can see deleted articles?

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives, articles

The new feature of articles seems to be functioning similarly to normal posts. Yet, when I visit [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68213441/welcome-google-cloud-community) I cannot see it. All I see is the 404 page. I have the privilege of a trusted user, so why can I not see deleted content? Are articles hard-deleted?

Comment: Even Mods cannot see deleted articles: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408912/are-articles-allowed-to-be-off-topic#comment852873_408912 so it might be hard deleted. Pretty sure this is a bug though.

Comment: ... even I can't see it...

Comment: I don't think they're hard-deleted (that would be bad design). I wonder if the original author or other employees in the collective can see it though.

Comment: I'm guessing the author can see it. They shouldn't be hard deleted. We don't hard delete anything.

Comment: The boat programming question was hard-deleted, but it [lives on](http://web.archive.org/web/20100426125115/http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/) (referenced at 1 h 02 min 43 secs in [episode 50 of the Stack Overflow podcast](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-28), classic series (2009-04-21)).

Comment: Moderators can still find deleted articles using the site search engine (with `deleted:yes`) and we can see metadata about it with some URL fiddling. It is not hard-deleted. What’s missing is the “deleted article” view for those with access rights.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: There are exceptions. [The boat programming question was hard deleted (removed) from the database](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131733/why-was-the-original-boat-programming-question-deleted#comment363617_131733) [by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about/14493#14493).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I am well aware of that one exception. It does not apply here. My point is that we can't view soft-deleted articles even though we know they are soft and not hard-deleted.

Comment: @Catija *We don't hard delete anything.* Really? Some GDPR wouldn't be happy with that `:)`

Comment: @iBug content, not user info. This question is about content.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed at some point. I just now noticed that I can see [this deleted article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68213441/welcome-google-cloud-community):

[image]

Apparently, when an article is deleted, the word `[deleted]` is appended to the title of the post, which is not consistent with deleted questions.