# Collectives Update: Introducing Bulletins

Tags: discussion, collectives, announcement

Hi Stack Overflow community, I’m Bert. I received a short [intro post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376784/please-welcome-valued-associate-1065-bert) when I joined the Community Team, but I’ve been quiet since then, learning more about the SO community and how things work here.

One big area of focus for me is Collectives, and it’s been fun and fascinating to see how things have evolved since the first Collectives debuted. I’m glad that Stack has assigned a dedicated Community Manager to help shepherd this beta product and ensure that it has utility to the SO community without seeming like a shift in our core values and workflows.

#### So what’s new with Collectives these days?

We're continuing to add new partners, with [Twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/twilio)’s Collective [launching in April](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/03/02/twilio-launches-collective-on-stack-overflow/) and another one coming in the next few weeks.

As I was getting up to speed and reviewing the launch of Articles, I understood the concerns that the community had about that new content type and how it was rolled out. [I was also impressed with how the community came together to craft guidelines for Articles.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413357/community-input-needed-the-guidelines-for-collectives-articles)

Today I’m introducing you to **Bulletins**. Bulletins are a way for Collective organizations to update the SO community about notable releases, changes and events.

Examples of what a Bulletin might communicate:

- Upcoming changes to a product or service
- Release notes and other timely information helpful to developers
- Information about new trainings or courses
- Information about conferences and other developer-focused events

A few more notes about Bulletins:

- Since Bulletins are not knowledge content like questions, answers, and Articles, Bulletins will not appear in search results.
- For the same reason, they are disconnected from reputation.
- Bulletins may be tagged by the author, for the purpose of determining relevance to specific subjects, but they will not appear on tag pages. At least one of the Bulletin's tags must be associated with the Collective, and the author cannot create a new tag when crafting a Bulletin.
- Bulletins have an expiration date, after which they will change to an “archived” state.
- Bulletins can not be voted on, and there is currently no other option to comment or provide feedback on them. **Would you be interested in a feedback mechanism for Bulletins?** Why or why not?

[image: Bulletin creation screen]
[image: Published Bulletin]

Bulletins will become available for Collective admins this week. Any new type of content needs to have specific guidelines, and we have crafted some initial guidelines for Collective admins, which you can see below. These initial guidelines are intended to make sure that Bulletins are relevant, useful, and timely to the community:

> Like Q&A and Articles, there are guidelines that Bulletins must adhere to. Bulletins that do not adhere to these guidelines may be perceived as mass marketing.
>
> **Relevant**
>
> The subject should be of interest to at least some Collective members, though it will be visible to the general public as well. Collective members are highly engaged users (or future highly engaged users), not a general audience.
>
> **Useful**
>
> The information should be new or updated information that impacts member’s work. It should be able to exist on its own, it is not a teaser to “find out more”. The intent should primarily be to create awareness of something, not to drive traffic elsewhere.
>
> **Timely**
>
> A bulletin is not “evergreen”, it is meant to expire when it is no longer relevant or useful. If your intent is to create something evergreen, it may be better as a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/article-guidelines) (please refer to those guidelines for more information).

Since this is a new content type, we also thought it would be useful for Collective admins to have a clear understanding of each content type available to them. These definitions below are provided accordingly:

> **Questions**
>
> The primary type of content on Stack Overflow. It’s absolutely fine to [ask a question and then post an answer yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)! If you are conveying a short set of specific how-to instructions, or if the information would fit well into an FAQ list, a question is probably the best format. [Guidelines for posting a question can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
>
> **Articles**
>
> Articles exist specifically within the Collective, and should be:
>
> - longer-form content that discusses a broader technical topic
> - a set of how-to instructions that covers multiple scenarios and possibilities
>
> Articles are collaborative after the initial publication, with community members able to add comments/suggestions and, in some cases, make edits.
>
> [The full set of guidelines for Articles can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/article-guidelines)
>
> **Bulletins**
>
> Bulletins are updates posted by admins of the Collective, for members and readers of the Collective. Information conveyed in a bulletin should be relevant to the community and the topics covered by the Collective. The information should be focused on a timely subject or a recent change. External links can be included, but the Bulletin should contain a summary of what members can find by following the link.
>
> Bulletins do not have comments, and are set to expire on a specific date.
>
> The full set of guidelines for Bulletin creation can be found here *(will be linked to the guidelines shown above)*.

Are these guidelines and definitions clear and accurate? Is anything missing? We’re interested in your feedback on these initial versions. As Collectives begin to create Bulletins, let us know your thoughts on those as well.

Comment: In the Articles definition, is that an either/or for the bullets points?

Comment: On the bulletin, maybe add an option to make the bulletin to be not public anymore after a set amount of time and that time can't be more than 30 days/1 month and minimum 3 days. That will make sure that the author is aware that the content isn't evergreen.

Comment: @Braiam That's a great question (re: Article definition). I don't think the items are mutually exclusive, so I'd say "either" (or perhaps "should be at least one of these").

Comment: The lack of Comments doesn't look very "handy" to me..., if this current Post was a *Bulletin*, I wouldn't have been able to mention that you have a Typo in "*Information **about about** conferences*"... // Same also if stg is not clear and Readers have Questions...

Comment: @chivracq I expect that those posts are freely editable by collective members, but maybe Berthold knows something else.

Comment: Since Bulletins are messages specifically from the organization associated with the Collective, only admins can publish and edit them.

Comment: I'm sure there's some justification being made here for making non-knowledge content a first class citizen of a knowledge repository, but I don't know if it's worth inquiring about.

Comment: @Makoto it's a company blog post, without being the company blog post. Companies already wanted a venue to share news, I say let them, but also remove them once it is not "news" anymore.

Comment: @Braiam: But they have their *own* sites to do this from, which is kind of what I'd expect some company like Intel to do when announcing this.  They'd likely cross-post between here and their own blog which would mean that Stack Overflow still has non-knowledge content on their site.  Like I said, there's a justification hidden somewhere, but I can't be bothered to dig around for it.

Comment: @Makoto I do want to point out that Bulletins "will not appear in search results", "are disconnected from reputation" and "will not appear on tag pages", so it sounds like second-class citizenry at best (no offense meant to any Bulletins who may read this).
We've crafted the guidelines to help admins avoid simply cross-posting from standard marketing channels and company blogs; that's the "relevant" part.

Comment: @Braiam Re: expiration/evergreeness, archived posts will still be public, but are hidden behind the “archived” filter. The Bulletins tab in Collectives is filtered to "active" by default. A viewer needs to choose the “archived” filter in order to view archived Bulletins. Archived Bulletins also have a specific icon displayed next to them, and cannot be pinned.

Comment: So, effectively this is a place for marketing content that will only exist within the collective area, nowhere else?

Comment: @Berthold:  So it's something that's less useful (from a content perspective) than comments are on Stack Overflow, yet it's being put into a feature that companies pay for.  I admit to having an overflowing bias on this, but that honestly feels pretty first-class to me; someone is requesting that you develop this with those limitations, so you...are.

Comment: @Berthold when will they be achieved? When someone decides to push a button or automagically?

Comment: @Braiam The archive date is set during the creation of the Bulletin. If no specific date is selected, the default is 60 days.

Answer (score 39):

> Bulletins can not be voted on, and there is currently no other option to comment or provide feedback on them. Would you be interested in a feedback mechanism for Bulletins? Why or why not?

At least some form of flagging is needed as a feedback. The guidelines laid out are well and good but it can happen that a Bulletin does not adhere to them. In which case there needs to be some way to notify *somebody* that the content is inappropriate.

Which then brings up the next point - who would that somebody be? Are diamond moderators supposed to monitor and handle Collectives content? Or would it be staff?

This is for Stack Exchange to decide. I am only posing it as I do not see any indication of this being planned. As presented, it makes it seem like Collectives admins are given free reign and no oversight.

Comment: We'll be incorporating flagging and the diamond moderation tools into Collective Articles and Bulletins. Any user-generated content needs to be able to be flagged and moderated. At the moment, CMs have the ability to delete Bulletins (and Articles) if needed.

Comment: When did moderation become so insignificant that elementary tools became second-class citizens themselves?

Answer (score 22):

> Since Bulletins are not knowledge content like questions, answers, and Articles, Bulletins will not appear in search results.

Where exactly *will* they appear though? You haven't told us that. If I don't join any collective and don't visit a collective's page, will I be bothered with those bulletins somewhere while navigating the site?

Please tell us where you're planning to display those bulletins, preferably with examples (e.g., screenshots) of how they will look like.

I noticed that the question contains [4 image links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0DbU.png) that don't appear in the post because they all lead to 404 pages. Were they supposed to be demonstrative images or what exactly do they represent?

Comment: Bulletins will only be display within the Collective's pages.  There's a new "Bulletins" tab within a Collective to see all the entries, and a Collective can "pin" up to 2 bulletins to display on the Overview tab of the Collective.  There's also a side-bar widget that shows recent bulletins and is displayed within the Collective pages.

Comment: Apologies about the non-displaying images! That was my error (they displayed for me but no one else). As you'll see, they are images of the creation interface and published state for a Bulletin. Thank you for remarking on it.

Answer (score 6):

I like the idea of having a designated place for Collectives to post useful, temporary, "update"-style content, and I think this feature goes a good distance to address Collectives' total lack of internal/ member-facing communication features that's [come up before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408917).

I understand that Bulletins are designed to be temporary content, so it makes sense to sequester them away from more traditional posts that are written to be useful long-term. Given that, I find myself wondering how you plan to balance making the content usefully locatable while still keeping this needed separation.

Will the posting of a Bulletin trigger a notification of some sort for members? Or is this designed to be more of an RSS feed-style feature, where users only see Bulletins if they go looking on a Collective's page?

Put another way, inundating users who are uninterested with Bulletins is  undesirable, which you clearly understand– but if they're *too* hidden, then they're not very useful to anyone at all, even the people who *would* otherwise be interested, which more or less defeats their purpose altogether.

Comment: As your very well-stated remarks detail, if we're going to surface Bulletins to those who are most likely to be interested, it's going to be about finding the right balance. As we learn more about how Bulletins will be used and move forward with the Collectives beta, we may surface Bulletins in other Collective-focused ways, but we are still in the ideation stages. [John's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418333/collectives-update-introducing-bulletins?noredirect=1#comment912273_418335) details where they appear at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Where will the link to bulletins be placed? Will it be a tab on the top of the collective page?

**Edit:** Found it

[image]

Comment: Yes, next to the Articles tab, as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/gitlab

Comment: @Berthold thanks for pointing it out, I couldn't see it.