# Articles don't have vote breakdown

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, collectives

Articles (Collectives feature) support upvoting and downvoting, but they don't show vote breakdown.

Vote breakdown can be crucial when determining the value of some post. There is a huge difference between a post being upvoted twice without having any downvotes, and between a post being upvoted 30 times and downvoted 28.

Please add support for showing the vote breakdown for users that can see vote breakdown on the rest of the site.

Comment: Reported here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408657/11573842

Comment: Honestly, the upvotes and downvotes in the articles section shouldn't affect reputation.. It should only be used to order the articles in the article page nothing more than that. This can easily be abused by Recognized Members or Employees

Comment: kinda like how SO Docs was abused

Comment: @PeterHaddad Reputation is separate concern. Even without reputation, knowing whether something is downvoted or not can be significant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks again for pointing this out, the vote breakdown on Articles is viewable now.