# What is the difference between articles and self-answering?

Tags: discussion, collectives, articles

From a visual and functional point of view, articles appear to be virtually the same as regular posts (questions and answers). What can you accomplish with an article that you can't by just posting your own question and self-answering?

Here is what users see when asking a question:

[image: Answer your own question - share your knowledge, Q&A-style]

Isn't that the purpose of an article, to share your knowledge? The articles section has the appearance of being a separate area where "special users" can post, and garner higher attention due to the lower proportion of posts. If you are going to self-answer your question, but you have the privilege to post articles, surely you'd gain more attention (and rep) by posting it as an "article" rather than a "question".

Combine that with the fact that the privilege to post articles is not unlocked through rep, but rather must be granted by the "collective" (a.k.a., a private entity which pays Stack Overflow an unknown amount for these privileges). It all seems rather distasteful.

Comment: An advantage/difference of an article is that you are not forced to split the knowledge into a question part and an answer part, which can be a bit artificial sometimes.

Comment: I would love to know the idea behind articles too. I don't think I can close a question as a duplicate of an article. Most of the knowledge is already covered by Q&As, and writing an article for a new topic seems like a waste of time.

Comment: I've wondered the same thing and reached the same conclusion: basically the entire difference that nobody but the anointed few can post an alternative article competing with your article, in the way that they can compete with an answer. Articles don't grant collective members any new ability to write and share content that they didn't have before, nor even attempt or purport to do so; they simply shield collective members from competition, and that's it.

Comment: @MarkAmery Do you mean that for money, I can gain an advantage over other users of this site?

Comment: @Marijn that's true, but is the artificiality of posing a problem as a concrete question, then answering it so bad that we need collectives (tm)? Seems like grilling a zucchini with a space shuttle to me.

Comment: @ggorlen it is part of the more general idea that articles are not Q&A, it also allows for longer content that would "need more focus" as a question, things like tutorials, best practise-type comparisons between approaches, new feature announcements etc. SE did some [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408602/the-user-research-behind-collectives-on-stack-overflow) and they found out that people want this kind of functionality. I personally don't know if it is a good idea to integrate that kind of content into SO, but let's see how it goes.

Comment: @Marijn "..which can be a bit artificial sometimes." Many question in Q&A aren't questions either "How to..." are more like titles instead of questions. Clearly establishing the topic that is being answered is rather an advantage if you ask me. Articles may just leave the reader unclear about what they are dealing with.

Comment: Articles may indeed by too close to self-answered Q&A. I would envision articles being a bit more different, for example having a reference list of Q&As and being more like a wrapper around different Q&As with a single common topic/purpose because even if articles have a broader scope, they will still duplicate content of Q&A, which is bad (or at least not that good). Better would be to invent some kind of Uber Q&A, i.e. a connection of several Q&As together without duplicating content. The existing articles (yesterday there were two ontopic articles) could all be Q&A without any problems.

Comment: "...appearance of being a separate area.." That's definitely the case and it feels like there is currently a fence between articles and Q&A, even if only by how they appear. It's probably because articles were implemented and envisioned as a separate feature and not much attention was spent on a possible integration of both.

Comment: I see self-answering as a way to share with others how you fixed your specific issue. Or at least, I do it with that spirit. Self-answering for broadly sharing knowledge — i.e. without having a specific need — looks, in fact, artificial. I see that kind of content better suited for a blog or project wiki. In the scenario I picture, you hit the "answer your own question button" because you prepared a question, didn't hit "Post" immediately, and found the solution in the meantime. At that point might as well post the answer too.

Comment: [The tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) says "the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites" - I guess that the tour needs be re-written.

Comment: @blackgreen Sharing knowledge without need is not artificial, it's what every book and every tutorial and every teacher does every day. Even if you know all the answers you can still ask questions. I don't understand what people have against them. If you really only judge the content, it doesn't matter at all if a question is self answered or not self answered.

Answer (score 17):

With articles and self-answered Q&A I see two very similar, but not completely identical features. Let's go through the different aspects one by one:

**Scope** (is different)

- Self answered Q&A is limited in scope like every other Q&A, i.e. must be focused on a single answerable programming problem
- Articles have a [broader focus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408764/1536976). The company envisions articles "to be the content piece that is in between Q&A (specific problem, specific solution) and documentation (full description on how something works)." Specifically, articles do not need to have a question as a topic. See also [Are articles allowed to be off-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408912/are-articles-allowed-to-be-off-topic).

In practice I expect a lot of overlap. Articles (judging by the existing ones) aren't that long either (more like average blog entries) and some existing Q&A answers can easily be longer (probably going deeper into a topic instead of going wider).

**Question/Title** (is different)

Articles have a single line as title and it can be anything. Self answered Q&A have a title and a question body detailing the scope of the question showing the problem and the research.

In practice again it might be quite similar, for example how-to questions could be Q&A, but also how-to guides as articles.

**Competing answers** (is different)

Articles do not allow competing answers. Self-answered Q&A can also be answered by others, allowing for competing, alternative solutions that can be voted on.

**Duplicate targets** (is different)

Articles currently cannot be used as duplicate target of Q&A, self-answered Q&A can but cannot be used as duplicate target of articles (which cannot be closed anyway). See also [Allow voting to close questions as duplicate of Articles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408667/allow-voting-to-close-questions-as-duplicate-of-articles).

**Closing** (is different)

As far as I know, it's currently impossible to close articles; one can only downvote them. Self answered Q&A can of course be closed as every Q&A.

**Who can create it** (is different)

Every user can create self-answered Q&A about anything that's on-topic, but only collective members can create articles (presumably about their collective's topics only).

**Expected expertise** (may vary more for self-answered Q&A)

Articles can currently only written by selected members of a collective and maybe later from everyone of a collective. The expectation is that the article creators are experts in their field, if however everyone in a collective does write articles, the amount of expertise may vary.

Self-answered Q&A can be written by experts but also by everyone who happens to find a solution to their own question after asking. The amount of expertise contained in a self-answered Q&A will therefore vary. It even may vary more than for articles.

**Editing capabilities** (is different)

Every user can edit every self-answered Q&A, but only collective members seem to be able to edit collective's articles.

**Quality control** (unclear if different)

Self answered Q&A follows the usual quality control of Q&A (vote, close/reopen, comments, edits, alternative answers, and duplicate targets). Articles only are affected by a few of these things (votes and comments), but they may have a few extra points (review by collective admins maybe). It may be that because of this quality will differ. It's currently too early to tell.

**Voting** (mostly the same, but with subtle differences)

Voting seems largely the same on articles and self answered Q&A, but downvotes on articles prompt some sort of feedback dialog (see [Collective Article downvote pushes for explanation. Bug or new feature?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408656/collective-article-downvote-pushes-for-explanation-bug-or-new-feature). [Articles don't have vote breakdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408663/articles-dont-have-vote-breakdown) yet and there is a request that [Downvoting Articles should not cost reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408723/downvoting-articles-should-not-cost-reputation).

On self-answered Q&A there is a vote on the question and votes on answers. For an article there is only one vote. That means that for self-answered Q&A the question has to stand on its own. For an article it doesn't have to; in fact an article would not need to have a question as a topic.

**Content license and knowledge sharing** (the same)

Articles and self-answered Q&A have the same content license and the purpose of both is knowledge sharing.

**Backup** (currently different)

Articles are currently [not included in the data explorer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408734/town-hall-collectives-on-stack-overflow/408779?noredirect=1#comment852659_408779) and may or may not be part of the data dumps. Self answered Q&A is.

**Search availability** (same)

Both Q&A and articles can be found through the search.

**Tags** (same)

Both Q&A and articles have tags and they seem to work the same way.

**Summary**

Self-answered Q&A is a time proven solution to convey knowledge, is well integrated into the whole ecosystem and can be created by anyone about every possible programming topic. However, according to the company, people reported problems with self-answered Q&A which might have been badly received sometimes.

Articles are thought to be more broad in topic, but they are currently restricted to collectives in topic, creation and editing capabilities. They lack certain quality control features (closing and editing).

There will be quite some overlap, but they aren't well integrated with each other. That could lead to duplication of content and waste of effort (even development effort; we could have simply relaxed the scope for self-answered Q&A and called them articles instead, but left everything else the same).

In the best case, articles could be a valuable addition going beyond self-answered focused Q&A, but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Also there is an aspect of authority. Articles are supposed to be written by people who are experts on the subject and thus have a higher reliability, while a self-answer is written by the question author and can thus be of any quality including "I tried some random things and I don't know what did it but it works now rofl".

Comment: @Gimby Many self-answered questions are written by experts and articles can in the future potentially get written by everyone in a collective, so maybe also from everyone. The quality control and also generally the quality of articles is currently unclear. In principle you should only answer a question if you can but if you can it makes you kind of an expert, obviously expertise can vary. I have to think about how to formulate it.

Comment: @Gimby Added paragraph about expected expertise.