# Don't show the "your articles" tab if I don't have any articles (or if I can't write them)

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives, articles

In Google cloud collective I have an option called **Your articles**, but when I go there there is no option to create a new article.

[image: Screenshot of articles page with three tabs, "Newest", "Active", "Your articles"]

Since it doesn't seem like I can write articles without being an admin or a recognized member, it seems like this tab is unnecessary, since it only leads to questions about whether it is possible to write articles as a developer or is it only allowed for the organization. Would it be possible to hide the Your articles section if a user can't create articles anyway (or if they don't have any)?

Comment: You can write an article and then it would be voted on to see if it's a good article or not. It's explained in much more detail in the official question.

Comment: Thanks, @10 Rep but there is no option to create a new article there?

Comment: @10Rep No, only "Admins and Recognized Members" can post articles (at this time)

Comment: Are you a Recognized Member for the Collective?

Comment: Oh, I see. So is it a bug? I do not need a button called Your articles I guess. Otherwise people get confuced

Comment: @VLAZ No just another indi developer

Comment: Yes, @JanakaEkanayake I meant that if you are recognized you can write an article. Or if you are an admin. So this page is redundant and means nothing for you (as of right now).

Comment: Understood. Still, I'm not sure this Your articles button is a bug or not, anyway I will keep the question posted I guess it would help for someone to understand

Comment: @JanakaEkanayake It's not, it's _generally_ considered [bad UX to hide features that users don't have access to yet](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/120848/should-i-have-a-disabled-button-or-no-button-at-all-if-the-user-doesnt-have-su). They could have disabled it without hiding it, but ultimately it's just the search results for `is:article user:me collective:"Collective Name"`, I can't see any reason to disable it

Comment: We regularly hide UX features that people don't have access to - such as review queues - particularly if having them there causes confusion, @Nick - since this seems to be causing confusion, I've converted it to a bug report. I'm not sure which way we'll go but it seems reasonable to hide something that the bulk of people using SO are unlikely to ever have access to.

Comment: @Catija /shrug, I'm just a user :p, if SE prefer to hide it they can

Comment: Already reported here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408710/11573842

Comment: I imagine the reason it's there is in case a recognized user with articles is demoted to a regular member (or possibly the same for admins), but still letting them see what articles they've made. It's a pointless argument right now, with only one article posted (last I checked) on the entirety of the collectives, but it's a future-oriented argument. Might be better to make it clear that the user can't create new articles than hiding the button or even the tab. Or of course hiding the tab if the user hasn't ever made articles and can't post new ones, though it does lose

Comment: a "free space" for a reminder on who can make articles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated it to [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned). We’re planning to release a feature (in the near term) that would allow any member of a collective to submit an Article for review, however, for the time being, hiding it would be a good solution.

**Update Feb 10th**

Apologies, this post got buried a bit. Last month we've released a feature that allows any member of a Collective to [propose an Article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/propose-article).

Comment: It's happy to hear that