# How can I post an article on Stack Overflow Collectives?

Tags: support, collectives, articles

There is a new feature Collectives, and I saw a few people posted their articles. I also saw section My Articles, but I cannot find an option how to create one. How can I create an article?

Comment: Related: [Don't show the “your articles” tab if I don't have any articles (or if I can't write them)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408754/2821954)

Comment: The collectives help identifies that you need to be a [Recognized Member](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collectives-user-types) for that collective

Comment: Tnx. How can I become the `Recognized User`?

Comment: It is explained in that help link.

Comment: did you try bribery?

Comment: @rene Legal insists it is not called "bribery", but rather "payment".

Comment: It's not a "kickback" it's a "revenue sharing arrangement".

Answer (score 8):

As is announced:

> Members can now contribute articles
>
> We’ve added a new feature that allows Members of a collective to write Articles. Simply submit a proposal, get it approved by a Recognized Member, and publish it.

Just follow the propose article button or go directly to (substitute your collective, you have to have joined the collective before):

https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go/articles/create

Comment: It looks like there is a **Propose Article** button but it is greyed out for me, presumably because I'm neither a member of or recommended user of a collective.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Just tried it out. The propose article button is enabled if you join the collective. I tried it. Leaving a collective again could be easier. Who would have thought that the joined button changes on hover (wonder how they do that on mobile).

Comment: You dare assume SE makes logical UI elements? :p They're notoriously bad at making sensible UIs