# What actually is "Notice added/removed Endorsed Edit by Collective"?

Tags: support, status-completed, collectives

[image]

I just encountered these in a lot of questions/answers and out of curiosity - what are those?

My assumption is any interaction by collective admins adds the edit but sometimes it gets removed instantly as well. Also how is it different from a normal edit?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408686 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408688

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at a few posts edited by a collective employee I assume that the following scenario is what is happening here:

1. A collective employee edits a post. This adds the notice to the post (which is perhaps used to show the "<Collective Employee>" text under the user card).
2. Next the collective employee edits again within the grace period and for some reason (likely this is a bug) the notice is added again and the system removes the *previously* added notice (likely assuming edit might be from different users), effectively replacing the old notice with a new one.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Correct, the 'Endorsed Edit by' is tied to user card collective badges (Employees and Recognized Members). The frequent repeating is not intended, I've reported it as a bug. The developers will look into this further.

Comment: Update: The frequent repeating is fixed and the copy is updated to be more clear.