# How can I view the list of all existing collectives?

Tags: support, collectives

When I go to the [Collectives page](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives), I only see two collectives, go and google cloud. I would imagine there are many more, as the video introducing collectives uses a different one. I can't find anywhere on the collectives page to show existing collectives.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On June, 14<sup>th</sup> 2022, WSO2 [added](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/14/wso2-joins-collectives-on-stack-overflow/) their biological and technological distinctiveness, so now we have **6** public Collectives.

---

Twilio was [assimilated](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/03/02/twilio-launches-collective-on-stack-overflow/) on March 2<sup>nd</sup> 2022, so now there are **5** public Collectives.

---

Since the posting of the answer, the GitLab Collective stopped being hidden, and as of November 3<sup>rd</sup> 2021, Intel [joined](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/11/03/intel-joins-collectives-on-stack-overflow/) the Borg too, so the below should read: there are **4** public ones.

The API also seems to have stopped returning the Audio Bubble bogus Collective, but the [primary.css](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css) stylesheet assures us it is still there:

```css
.themed.subcommunity-audiobubble { /* rules here */ }
```

---

While the other answers are correct that there are only 2 *public* Collectives, there are more, but *hidden*. Two of the latter can be easily retrieved via the Stack Exchange API (SE added collectives in version 2.3): GitLab and Audio Bubble (the latter is a bogus Collective used in promotional materials. On an off-note, [audiobubble.co.uk](https://audiobubble.bandcamp.com/) may have some reservations about using a music label like this). It is as easy as following the API link to make a GET request to the endpoint:

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/collectives#order=desc&sort=name&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

You cannot find the hidden ones by going to the respective `https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/<collective name>` pages, though.

In any case, here is an interactive experience for getting an always up-to-date list of Collectives on Stack Overflow (comes with a built-in API key):

```js
(async(w, d) => {

  const addStyle = (d) => {
    const style = d.createElement("style");
    d.head.append(style);
    const { sheet } = style;
    if(!sheet) return;
    
    sheet.insertRule(`td:first-child { min-width: 15vw; }`);
  };

  const makeCell = (text, isHead = false) => {
    const td = d.createElement(isHead ? "th" : "td");
    td.textContent = text;
    return td;
  };

  const makeRow = (columns, isHead = false) => {
    const tr = d.createElement("tr");
    const cells = columns.map((text) => makeCell(text, isHead));
    tr.append(...cells);
    return tr;
  };
  
    const report = d.getElementById("report");
  if (!report) return;
  
  addStyle(d);

  const API_BASE = "https://api.stackexchange.com";
  const API_VER = "2.3";

  const url = new URL(`${API_BASE}/${API_VER}/collectives`);
  url.search = new URLSearchParams({
    site: "stackoverflow",
    sort: "name",
    filter: "sAR)YG", //default + unsafe
    key: "JP)CTkVqyn7WrWesFFaL8g(("
  }).toString();

  const res = await fetch(url.toString());
  if (!res.ok) return console.log("something went very wrong. Sorry :(");

  const {
    items = [], 
    has_more = false, 
    quota_remaining
  } = await res.json();
  
  if(!quota_remaining) {
    const quota = d.getElementById("quota");
    if(quota) {
      quota.style.display = "unset";
      report.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  const rows = items.map(({
    name,
    description
  }) => makeRow([name, description]));
  
  report.querySelector("tbody")?.append(...rows);

})(window, document);
```

```css
#quota {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="quota">Your API quota for the day is exhausted! Can't do anything about it</p>

<table id="report">
  <caption>Stack Overflow Collectives</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can find a list of all the collectives (all 2 of them) on the [Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives) page. When, or if, more are added (depends on how well the beta goes) they will be added to said page.

The related [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow) post, that's also linked on the page, also confirms that the initial launch customers are Go & Google Cloud.

Answer (score 2):

Found a list by probing the urls: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives-all

Only 4 right now though