# Collectives should be removed or be free

Tags: feature-request, collectives

Right now, those who want to use the collectives feature (e.g., Google with the Google Cloud) have to pay to use the Collectives feature.

I think it should either be made free or be removed entirely.

Right now, the incentive would be for the owner of Stack Overflow to start giving moderation powers to these companies. I can see this resulting in undesirable outcomes such as inconsistent and transparent moderation done by people who are unfamiliar with the site. I am not overly concerned by the current "recommended answer" and "recognized user" features, but just that it is a slippery slope.

I think we have to ask ourselves why this feature even exists. Does it really provide any value to the community these articles and "recommended answer" and "recognized user" badges.

The idea that was implied in the [blog post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow) (*"Give technical employees of these organizations the tools to contribute their knowledge effectively to the Stack Overflow community."*) was that companies would only contribute to Stack Overflow if they felt that they were more important than an average user.

More importantly, it seems like the Collectives feature is going to detract from the feature set of the free site.

> Each organization that participates in Collectives on Stack Overflow will get its own page, which will act as its “home” on Stack Overflow. Questions and Answers will be posted to Stack Overflow, as usual, and the collective page will aggregate all the relevant content from selected tags.

It seems like a great idea to have pages that aggregate relevant tags for a particular technology, but what concerns me is that now is this is a "paid" feature and not a free one and the owners will refrain from implementing this for free as it would detract from their profits.

Comment: How would making it free resolve any of the issues you mentioned? How would that be any different than many of the product-specific sites we have on our network through the Area 51 process, that have existed for many years and still have not been taken over by those companies?

Comment: @animuson, see my edits. I tried to improve my post.

Comment: As much as I'd love collectives not to exist... I don't think you've put forward any good or useful arguments.

Comment: You'd probably have better reception if you just proposed to remove them entirely :) On a more serious note, really why would they make it free? This product was clearly designed with profit in mind (and I do not believe, even for a second, that community benefit was a concern when the idea had first been conceived), so what would be the reason to keep it around if not for at least getting a good buck out of it?

Comment: "I think we have to ask ourselves why this feature even exists."--Are you discounting "to get the money" as a reason?

Comment: Thinking that complaining on meta about collectives is going to do anything at all is you lying to yourself. What this feature develops into or if it stays at all is between the company and their partners. And their pocket books. I would instead spend your energy on trying to co-exist with it, because this is for sure not going to be the only way that the company is going to try and extract more revenue from the brand.

Comment: Is the last sentence a question or not? Re *"inconsistent and* ***transparent*** *moderation"*: Don't you mean *"inconsistent and* ***nontransparent*** *moderation"* (my emphasis)?

Answer (score 6):

Making this product free doesn't solve the problem of why the product exists in the first place, nor does it address any of the other sticking points that software can only smooth over (e.g. how do people moderate it, what voting looks like, how searchable it is, etc).