# How do I create my own Collective?

Tags: support, collectives, product-support

As the title says, SO now has a feature called [Collectives](https://venturebeat.com/2021/06/23/stack-overflow-launches-sub-communities-for-developer-engagement-and-data/):

> Collectives are a little like subreddits, Reddit’s community-focused boards dedicated to a single topic. For Google and other Stack Overflow customers, Collectives enable control of the conversation around their tools, technologies, and products.

How do I create my own collective around my project? If there is no UI for creating your own collective, then what should I write in an email to SO for them to create a collective for my project?

Some commentators appear to be arguing a semantic issue that is not relevant to my question. As an analogy: Question: "How do I publish my first book?" Answer: "You don't! You send your manuscript to a publisher and maybe they will publish it." If the answer to "How do I create my own Collective?" is "You don't! You petition the Community Team with a well-written request showing how your proposed Collective will improve Stack Overflow and maybe they will make you a Collective, or maybe they'll tell you to pound sand! Ha ha!", then that's an answer!

If there is no public UI or API to create Collectives and each collective must be created manually by special request, that's fine. An answer could cover the process for manually requesting Collective creation by email or letter, and the general requirements expected and common acceptance/denial criteria applied by the Collectives creation staff. For example,

- Do I need to show that I am able to commit a minimum level of resources (e.g. money or staff time) to operating the Collective?
- Do I need to represent an organization with a specified minimum level of revenue?
- Is the program by invitation only, and so any and all requests to create a Collective will be ignored?

Comment: You don't. If you want to collaborate with [so] in the Collectives (beta), you need to [contact](https://stackoverflow.co/collectives/contact) them directly, as directed at the bottom of the [Collectives](https://stackoverflow.co/collectives/contact) page.

Comment: That is my question. What is required of me, my project, or my company to participate in Collectives (beta)?

Comment: *"How do I create my own collective around my project?"* and *"What is required to participate in Collectives?"* are *completely* different questions.

Comment: No, they aren't. An enumeration of the requirements partially answers my question.

Comment: A list of requirements doesn't state "how you do something". If you asked "How do I bake a cake" and you were simply given a list of ingredients, that doesn't answer *how* you bake it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please explain what you mean by "participate in Collectives".

Comment: I guess for the current state of Collectives, some hints might be gathered from [the announcement post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408585/2821954) like "*we looked at the number of tags that their technologies have and the total number of pageviews these questions get per month*". Other than that, it's between [you(r money) and Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411792/2821954).

Comment: @Larnu Fortunately, my question isn't about baking. It's obvious that the *how* is *full-filling* the list of requirements.

Comment: Then [edit] your question to ask what you are *really* asking, @BjörnLindqvist , which appear to actually be "What are the requirements that my product needs to fulfill to be able to successfully be a suitable candidate for participation in Collectives?" (which, again, is not what you are currently asking).

Comment: *"then what should I write in an email to SO for them to create a collective for my project?"* You don't send them an email, you fill in the form on the contact page I linked.

Comment: You are arguing a semantic issue. Question: "How do I publish my first book?" Answer: "You don't! You send your manuscript to a publisher and maybe they will publish it."

Comment: One interesting follow up question is probably why one cannot simply create a collective. I guess part of the answer is money. Collective were never really thought as a way to improve organization of content, mostly as a way to add another revenue channel.

Answer (score 9):

> How do I create my own collective around my project?

You cannot create your own collective; it isn't a feature that you can create like [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/create/free). Stack Overflow creates all of the Collectives on the site, and they get final decision on whether a Collective will be created or not.

> what should I write in an email to SO for them to create a collective for my project?

Collectives has a specific [contact](https://stackoverflow.co/collectives/contact) page, you don't need to compose an email to them.

On the page you need to provide some base information:

- First name
- Last name
- Work Email
- Company
- Company Size
- Country

All data is mandatory.

This will then be sent to the Collectives Team, and they will contact you to enter discussions on creating a Collective for your technology or open source organisation, or perhaps may review details of your technology or open source organisation (via their own fact finding) prior to reaching out and decide it isn't the right fit for what they want (at this time).

Comment: This is not a bad start to an answer. What I want to know in addition is what SO's selection criteria is. How many users must my project have? How many SO questions? What kind of projects/products can get collectives (games f.e)? Can only organizations propose collectives?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist if you have a new/follow-up question, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Why does a company have to be involved? Why can't we start a collective for, say, a users' group, or the general community of enthusiasts for a technology? Why should we have to have an existing offsite "open source organization" to make a collective about an open source project? I don't think I understand the purpose of this feature, unless it's "convince Google, Intel, Twilio and GitLab to give us money".

Comment: I realize this is a new thing, but there's a part of the messaging that was confusing for me. Here's my situation, I do some iOS development. There isn't a collective of any kind in this area (iOS, Apple Dev, Swift, etc.).

But the we site doesn't clearly explain who creates/owns it. (From reading this page, I get the impression this is Apple's job). But I think you need to spell it out, right now, it's a little to marketing communications and not enough "this is what you do".