# The question is in the wrong collective. How can I edit it?

Tags: support, edits, collectives

This question [How can I find kedro_cli.py in my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76721494/554319) was included in [the PHP Collective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425532/launching-2-new-collectives-php-and-nlp), possibly because it has a PHP tag, but it has nothing to do with it. If anything, it should belong to Python, but not sure if there's a collective for it.

I flagged it for moderation, but I didn't get any response, and I don't seem to have enough reputation to edit it. What can be done about it?

Comment: "and I don't seem to have enough reputation to edit it" - you unlocked the edit privilege 4700 rep ago, and you could suggest an edit before that anyway

Comment: "I don't seem to have enough reputation to edit it." Why do you believe this to be the case? What concrete steps did you take in order to attempt an edit, and what happened as a result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives) which a question belongs to are automatically determined based on **the tags**<sup>1</sup>. Example:

- [AWS Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/aws?tab=tags)
- [Google Cloud Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud?tab=tags)
- [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php?tab=tags)

Thus, to remove<sup>2</sup> a question from a Collective, just edit the question and remove the tags that are relevant to that Collective.

As an aside, [Collectives can only be created by the company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416871/2821954). Thus, not every tag has its own Collective.

---

<sup>1</sup> Example of [a question in multiple Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49262915/2821954).

<sup>2</sup> This also applies to adding a question to a Collective, by adding the tags that are relevant to that Collective.