# Rename "User groups" to "Collectives" on the SO profile page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, collectives

On the Stack Overflow profile page, there's a new label showing how many user groups that user participates in:

[image]

Except those user groups are actually [Collectives](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow).  For the sake of consistency, and also because we should call them what they are, can that be relabeled "Collectives"?  According to [this](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4387790-manage-user-groups), "user groups" might have multiple SO meanings.

Comment: This change has also been suggested on MSE: [We’ve shipped some changes to the user profile navigation](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/369281/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon That linked question only reports a pluralization bug, so chances are that the devs only fix that instead of the actual incorrect naming there.

Comment: @SebastianSimon that's asking for correct pluralization.  Anyway, a post here might get more attention since this is SO-specific.

Comment: @Tom I’m mostly referring to the comments under that answer.

Comment: Given that there's an MSE post announcing this round of changes to the profile page, "[We’ve shipped some changes to the user profile navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369276/271271)", it would be more effective to add this as an answer on that post, if there's no answer which already explicitly covers this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. This issue has been fixed — the fix actually went out around the same time this was posted (not fast enough obviously). We won't be showing Collectives in that part of the profile, this label should now only be for user groups on Teams.

Comment: Is there any reason why there's an "v-visible-sr" with a 1px height with text for some of those items on the profile?

Comment: @Scratte That's an accessibility feature that makes that text only available to screen readers.

Comment: @AaronShekey I see. Thanks. It's being used on icons making the textContent not empty, despite that fact there is no text to see. That makes it tricky to work around. I.. have opted to just remove them. I hope to see some actual text there instead of having to put it there myself when they're "empty".