# Intel Collective not visible in the sidebar

Tags: bug, status-planned, collectives, sidebar

I don't know if there is a logic with which the collectives are displayed in the sidebar, or if this simply happens because it is the last added, but I wanted to point out that in the sidebar I see the collectives of GitLab, Google Cloud and Go, but not Intel.
Same behavior without logging in.

[image]

Comment: Surely there is logic, because otherwise it's going to be a little messy once there are say a dozen of them. That logic may well be a manual toggle so there is full control over when a collective is "ready" to appear there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! this is not a great experience. We'll improve the logic to make sure that all Collectives will be discoverable in the widget.

Comment: [I said it before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408634/8967612) and I'll say it again: all collectives are already accessible via the left sidebar; the ones the user joins also get listed there. So, I'm not really sure about the purpose of that widget other than pushing more interesting stuff further down ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯