# Can we talk about the color of Collectives banners on dark mode

Tags: feature-request, design, dark-mode, collectives

I'm an avid dark mode user, and for the most part I'm pleased with it. But take a look at this page I encountered earlier today.

[image: GitLab Collectives Example]

Tell me where your eyes immediately wander on this page. I see a bunch of mostly coherent, relatively easy-on-the-eyes dark colors, and then a massive bright orange box on the far right of the screen. Regardless of how important we regard the Collectives banner as being, I think we can all agree it should be less important than the question itself, and yet it's much brighter on dark mode. I went through the existing Collectives I could find, and they *all* look terrible on dark mode. Go, Twilio, and Intel are all super bright blues, and Google Cloud is just straight-up white against an otherwise dark page.

Can we get those colors changed to something a bit more muted and less retina-burning, for the users on dark mode?

Comment: so, the sponsored ad, is attracting your attention? it's just as distracting on light mode.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-by-design]. To second Kevin B, it seems to function as intended then if your eye wanders to those banners. Which is quite unfortunate, but once again shows that Collectives were designed purely with profit in mind and with little to no consideration towards the community.

Comment: When you don't like "something" on the Site, simply kill it: => Easy Sol: `stackoverflow.com##.sidebar-subcommunity` using some Ad-Blocker, 'uBlock Origine' for example... :idea: (Tested on FF98.)

Comment: @KevinB It's also possible I still don't fully understand the point of Collectives then. I did not realize it was intended as an advert.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo [they tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408585/11407695) to pass it as a service to the community, but it is not much more than an advertisement system disguised as a Q&A feature, yeah.